# Appropriate Response for 'Do My Job' Questions

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I came across a question recently (that I now can't find, so maybe it was moderated to hell) that basically displayed a few error messages (in C# perhaps), along with a block of code and the accompanying text was something along the line of "Need this for job, its not working, please give me teh codez to make this work". I may be paraphrasing, but that was the general gist of the question.

OP displayed a tenuous grasp of the language, there wasn't anything hideously wrong about his code that I could see from a cursory inspection and they posted a (reasonably) clear problem description as well as a description of what they wanted to achieve.

What grated against my professional sensibilities was that here was someone working in a similar position as mine, has resorted to SO to try and do his job for him. Now fair play to him, perhaps the question was poorly worded, but the impression I got was that he had no interest in actually figuring out why the problem was occurring, he just wanted a fix.

I did downvote the question, but they had roughly 300 rep so they weren't a 'brand new' user. My question is this: Is downvote really all we can do in this case? This person is literally saying "do my job for free, kthx". Would a more appropriate response be to comment and tell this person, that asking SO to do their job is inappropriate.

I know that similar questions have been posted about student assignment 'gimme teh codez' questions, but I feel that this kind of thing is a little more serious as this is a supposed professional (like we all are supposed to be) who is doing pretty much exactly the same thing except they are being paid to do so.

Personally I have no interest in directly fixing a person's code, rather I try to answer the questions with simple code and an explanation of what they were doing wrong, but in this case its clear that the OP wasn't interested in anything other than getting his code fixed.

<sub>Before you pounce on my profile and point out that my own question history has not been stellar, yes, I admit that I was guilty of similar behaviour, but I don't want to delete them because they've been answered.</sub>

Comment: Aren't (almost) all questions on SO in a way "do my job" questions? I hardly can put good questions on SO because they solve themselves usually after some time of thinking and searching.

Comment: With varying levels of blatentness, I suppose. I'm just posses at the I'm too lazy so fix my code so I don't have to bother learning.

Comment: @Trilarion That's a good thing. [so] only needs to have questions that cannot be searched for easily.  Then once the question has an answer online, it can be searched for easily and the next person does not have to ask. A good question is a sign that something needed better documentation.

Comment: see also [Should we add a “Do my work for me” close reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A down vote is the absolutely correct thing to do. When you have 3000+ rep you will also have the [cast close votes privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), so you can cast one of those too. There are a couple of close reasons that cover this:

[image]

and

[image]

Leaving a comment is also a good option, although you shouldn't expect anything to be done in response to it. Many people simply don't care to put any effort in, normally these questions will pretty quickly get voted into oblivion.

Comment: Ahh, you've neatly encapsulated my issue. The question did actually have a relatively clear description of what the problem was, had error messages, and had a clear problem statement. What made me react negatively was that OP was asking a 'gimme teh codez' question in a professional context.

Comment: @JamesMassey You get used to it after a while and it won't aggravate you so much. There's just no helping some people, professional or amateur.

Comment: Not so much personally aggravating, more that it sets a poor example to John/Jane T. Student who finds the question coming in from Google and thinks that he can just get SO to do everything for him.

Comment: Note: a downvoted, unanswered question will be automatically deleted (see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/ ).  Therefore not answering and downvoting is the best response to a question that you'd rather not see hang around.

Comment: MUST... NOT... PROVIDE....SNARKY.... LMGTFY... LINK....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301716/pdf-document-editors-on-client-side?noredirect=1#comment37556810_24301716

Comment: @JamesMassey I'm a weaker person than you, snarky comment has been left.

Comment: You can *flag* for closure before you get to 3000 as well :)

Comment: In addition, there are cases for the "Too Broad" close reason.  "How do I make a website in PHP?"  --> Too Broad

Comment: I've started voting close on SO more often recently due to the sheer amount of obviously low effort, first hit on google type questions. Unfortunately, the tag(s) I'm the predominant answerer doesn't seem to have enough people to actually get 5 close votes. Also there could be several comments asking the OP to narrow or clarify the question, which is not happening, therefore, it may [still linger there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) due to those 1+ extra comments. Is there any other option?

Comment: @akarnokd The  top tag you have is Java, there are a lot of Java users here :) BTW, there is also [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had trouble with another, way more specific tag.