# Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments - Revised

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, comments, staging-ground

In October, [we published a post about canned comments in the Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420897/staging-ground-workflow-canned-comments). We asked for input about what type of canned comments are frequently used, and whether we are using the right wording for each reason.

To recap, Reviewers are able to select from pre-written canned comments as part of a review in the Staging Ground. The canned responses will shorten the time it takes to review a question, while also providing helpful and actionable feedback to the Author. All canned comments can still be edited by the Reviewer once selected. Of course, Reviewers are also able to write their own custom comment, and are not required to use a canned response.

The previous post can be found here: [Staging Ground Workflow: Canned Comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420897/staging-ground-workflow-canned-comments)

### Types of Canned Comments – Revised

Thank you for your input on the previous post. We’ve gathered all the responses, sorted them, and updated the comment types based on your feedback. Please keep in mind that we are still open to updating the canned comments once Staging Ground launches and we have a better understanding of how they are being used. Here are the updated comment types.

| Revised Comment Type | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **Elaborate on what you expected** | Please edit your question to provide more details on what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. This gives readers a better chance to figure out what didn’t work and to answer your question accordingly. |
| **Be specific about your problem** | Please edit your post to state specifically what your problem is. Add additional details to help readers understand the problem and what you are asking. You can find more information on how to write good questions [in the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) |
| **Provide background research** | Please provide more background details on your problem. Tell readers what you found through your research, what you have already tried, and why it didn't meet your needs. This will help readers better understand your problem and avoid giving answers that you have already tried. |
| **Include an MRE** | Please edit your question to include more code for a [minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Then readers can run the code and have a better chance of answering your question. |
| **Convert images to text or code** | Please edit your question to convert the image into text in the post, and use a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for any code you have. This will make it easier to answer your question because readers can search the text or copy the code to reproduce the issue. |
| **Proofread for minor edits** | Your question is almost ready to post! Please proofread and edit it to improve the formatting and correct any spelling or grammar mistakes. |
| **Custom** | If none of these are the feedback you’d like to give, you can write your own. |

---

The Staging Ground is still under development, and these canned comments can change based on future feedback. Please let us know if we are missing anything, or if anything needs to be updated. If you have any questions or comments you’d like to share, please do so in an answer below.

Comment: **Please leave all feedback in Answers below**. It is very hard to respond to different threads of feedback in the comments.

Comment: Should this be [[meta-tag:featured]]? I completely missed it in the hot meta questions

Answer (score 28):

What about a comment asking the user to post in English. It's a very common close reason and many users do not realize they have to post in English or that they didn't post in English. A canned comment asking them to post in English would be useful.

Comment: Ideally, for questions written in Spanish, Portuguese, Russian or Japanese, one of the suggestions would be to consider posting on those language-specific sites.  However, not everyone can identify the languages accurately (I use Google Translate to identify when I'm not sure).  An alternative is to suggest using Google Translate to convert the question into English.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also, not always the question is suitable. So unless you understand the language and you can tell whether it's a really good question, I don't think you should recommend to post it on any other site.

Comment: That's always an issue with any question transfer — is the question suitable for the suggested site?  The verbiage should cover that.  And many questions can be assessed without knowing the language — in my experience, it is usually clear when there is so much information missing that it won't be suitable for the other site.

Comment: Let's please not suggest that people use machine translation. If they can't communicate the problem in English under their own power, then they'll face the same obstacle in understanding answers. It risks misunderstandings that OP won't be able to know have occurred. But more importantly, in the cases where the question actually has long-term value, it will need to be copy-edited anyway.

Answer (score 14):

Would "Exceptionally useless title" fall under "Proofread for minor edits"? or would that be left to a custom comment.

I kind of feel like "Proofread for minor edits" is a bit soft for such a foundational part of how people will find the question, and it happens far too often for it to not be covered by a canned option.

Comment: Fixing the title when it is "exceptionally useless" isn't a minor edit — but it might be good to have a canned comment for "Please rewrite the question title so that it more accurately and succinctly describes the problem you are having" — or "are seeking a solution to" or some such verbiage.  That may need some simpler English so it can be more easily understood by people for whom English is not their native tongue.

Comment: I often leave comments suggesting people to got read "How to Ask" to find tips on how to write descriptive, non-ambiguous titles.

Comment: "Please use a title that makes it clear what you need to know, or what went wrong. Do not use it to describe the overall task you are trying to complete."

Answer (score 9):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Is "edit" in those comments the magic link `[edit]`? That helps users to find where they can actually edit their post, otherwise they have to figure out that they can press the button below the tags on their question.

Comment: No, though that would be a nice thing to add (I'll add it to our list). Users will have a prominent notice at the top of the page giving visible links to edit though.

Comment: @YaakovEllis, "*No, though that would be a nice thing to add (I'll add it to our list).*", hum, sounds like you didn't really pay attention, this had already been mentioned/proposed 17(!) times in the previous SG-CC Thread... And I supported it then, but now I'm coming back on that Opinion, I don't think it's a good Idea actually... // Most CC's contain the Word "edit" as the 2nd Word in the CC (=> + Link at the beginning also), while most CC's also contain a Link to some "external" Page (MRE / 'How-to-Ask' / Code Formatting) that those Users *should* really follow and check... [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] Users will feel "tricked" by this (Magic) Link, thinking "*Oh...!?, what's happening...?, same Tab, where have I landed...?, oh...!?, it's actually my own Question, ... in 'Edit' Mode, thus... Yeah Okay, "stupid Reviewer/Commenter", I know how to find the 'Edit' Button, ah-ah...! And I can't find that Comment anymore, and I've forgotten what it said... Oh yeah, + another Link..., boah...!, probably as useless as the first one...!*"

Comment: We have considered this, but are not going to be implementing it in any of the early stages. We have been going through some research related to canned comments which shows that having lots of links ends up giving a more negative experience for the author receiving feedback. And we already give edit links in the notice at the top of the page and in emails sent to the author.

Answer (score 6):

About the first 2 'Canned Comments' ("*Elaborate on what you expected*" and "*Be specific about your problem*"):

- Why using the past tense for #1...? Present tense would make more sense to me...
- Why using "*your post*" in #2, while "*your question*" is used in all other 'Canned Comments'...?
- They are both very similar, what's the difference between "*provide more details*" (#1) and "*Add additional details*" (#2)...?

About 'Canned Comment' #6 ("*Proofread for minor edits*"), I (personally) find a non-descriptive Title not a "*minor edit*"...!

=> Suggestion for a (better) Formulation:
*Your question is almost ready to post! Please proofread and edit it to improve the formatting and correct any spelling or grammar mistakes. And make sure to give a descriptive title to your question.*

Comment: Title can be considered *"minor"* in length because it's one or two sentences at most, although it's importance is major.

Answer (score 4):

Please remove comment "Provide background research".

I feel like this comment will often be misused and will be used to ask users "what have you tried". We do not need this kind of comments. They have been plaguing Stack Overflow since inception.

This comment might also cause many askers to include too much information in their questions. We only need enough details to be able to provide clear and direct answers. We do not need to see everything the asker has already tried. Most of the time their attempts are extremely wrong and only decrease the quality of the answers.

Question askers also shouldn't include their research in their questions unless it is somehow relevant to the question. We don't want to see proof of them doing research. We require them to do the research so that they don't have to ask the same question again. If they did research and they still ask a question then it works as designed. We only need to see their debugging attempts for debugging style questions because this information is needed to answer the question properly.

If a question is missing some crucial information then the commenter should be specific about what that information is.

Comment: I can t agree that it should be removed; a reword would be better. Give me the code type questions aren't good questions, so why should they get through the Staging Ground? They often aren't useful or helpful to future readers either. Lacking evidence of research, which can be as simple as "I read this documentation, but didn't understand the sentence 'x'" is still good information, as it explains where the OPs understand is lacking and allows for a much more specific and helpful answer to future readers.

Comment: gime the code questions are *far* more useful for the purpose SO is here for than debugging questions are. Can they not co-exist?

Comment: @Larnu Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean by "give me the codes". I would say that these are one of the most useful questions on the site.

Comment: I don't follow that comment, @KevinB . It reads like you're saying that [so] is a debugging website, but I wouldn't say that's true, no. Debugging questions are just one part of it, and debugging questions aren't "give me the codes" either, as they will certainly contain an attempt.

Comment: @Larnu Here, I am talking about questions like [Add a column with a default value to an existing table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/92082/1839439) or [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/194852/1839439) or [Find all tables containing column with specified name - MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4849652/1839439)

Comment: That's what I am saying. Debugging-style questions need an attempt. You can't just give an error message and no code that caused the error message. But other questions don't usually require any attempt.

Comment: Those don't read like "give me the codes" so much to me, @Dharman . I'll try to find an example, but I'm on my phone and it's getting late, so it may be several hours. More likely I'll add a counter answer when I get the chance tomorrow.

Comment: I think it's more a case of, we generally agree, but there's a difference in opinion of where the line should be drawn. There's absolutely cases of "gime teh codez" questions that need no code to be solved, most of them i'd argue. There's also questions that fall into that category that need more focus or are unclear... which *can* be achieved by providing code, or by better describing the problem/needs.

Comment: @Larnu - Posts on the topic of questions asking for code: [269247](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269247/11107541), [372179](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/372179/11107541), [260909](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/11107541), [420875](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420875/11107541) (Karl's post in particular shows that people interpret the meaning of "code-writing service" in different broadnesses, so don't cherry-pick the part where he says "not a code-writing service").

Comment: Your assertion _"Question askers also shouldn't include their research in their questions..."_ conflicts with the tooltip for downvoting a question: _"This question does not show any research effort..."_. I'm not disagreeing with your answer, but if including research in a question is generally unhelpful the wording on that tooltip should probably be changed.

Comment: ...Of course _"show"_ is ambiguous in that tooltip. It could narrowly be interpreted as _"You haven't explicitly described your research effort in your question"_, or more broadly as _"The overall quality of your question strongly suggests you didn't bother to do any research at all before posting on SO"_. Regardless, the wording of that tooltip should probably be improved, especially since it relates to downvoting.

Comment: @skomisa A question that doesn't show research effort is one that is an obvious duplicate. Feel free to downvote questions that have been asked again despite having easy to find duplicates. But it doesn't mean that one should put proof of research in the question. I don't need to know what Google search keywords they used to be able to answer the question.

Comment: @Dharman Not sure of your grounds for claiming _"A question that doesn't show research effort is one that is an obvious duplicate"_. The tooltip for downvoting questions that don't show research effort certainly doesn't suggest that.

Comment: @skomisa Third point in this post [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman Googling and duplicates are not the same thing at all. For me, a duplicate is when you ask a question that has already been asked on SO. Am I completely misunderstanding your point?

Comment: @skomisa Right, but if it has already been asked on SO then wouldn't you be able to find it by searching on Google?

Comment: Sure you will find SO duplicates though Google, and it is true that any new question which is an obvious duplicate doesn't show research effort. But you are claiming the converse of that: _"A question that doesn't show research effort is one that is an obvious duplicate"_. That's surely not the case; there are plenty of questions here that showed no research effort, and are also not duplicates.

Comment: @skomisa the ease of finding something on google isn't necessarily the best metric for whether or not research happened either, but it's up to the user casting the vote to make that judgement.

Comment: @KevinB Right. Excluding the specific case of failing to check for duplicates, lack (or not) of research effort in a question usually manifests itself regardless of any claims of research being made (or not). And I suspect many voting to downvote due to lack of research simply do so on the basis ["I know it when I see it"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it).

Answer (score -5):

The most desired "canned" comment I have I would be best described as "better suited elsewhere".

## Better Suited Elsewhere

1. UX to pick better site with omnibar, set `$SITE`.
2. Canned comment, *"This question is technically on topic here but it's better suited on another site on the network, I would suggest you take this question to `$SITE` instead."*

Example,

> This question is technically on topic here but it's better suited on another site on the network, I would suggest you take this question to `[dba.se]` instead.

This would be *VERY* useful for redirecting questions on PostgreSQL on Stack Overflow to `dba.stackexchange.com`, or questions on Ansible and Kubernetes to `devops.stackexchange.com`. I type these up anyway, so this would just make my job *way* easier.

This is desirable to me because it doesn't involve moderators on either site agreeing to anything, or in the cases when they do agree the network not doing it for whatever obscure reason. This would *just* be a friendly suggestion from one user to another.

Comment: This violates even our migration convention.  If a question is on-topic here, then answering it here is *just fine*, even if there's a more specialized site to answer it on.

Comment: It's not a migration, so it's not subject to your convention. The standing convention here is for me to be able to **inform** other users when I believe other sites on the network are better suited as homes for their question. I like that convention. I want to make it easier to participate in that convention. This proposal doesn't have any coercion/force that a migration entails. You never _have_ to use a canned comment, or write a custom one. I choose to do it though. This would make it easier.

Comment: You misunderstand me.  The convention you're promoting is *incorrect*.  It's logical resolution - migrating the question to a "more suitable" site - is seldom never done, since if the question is on-topic, there's not a lot of incentive to try to migrate it elsewhere to begin with.  This is why I likened it to migration, since the impact of the message you're sending - "this goes somewhere else" - isn't supported in this convention. We discourage cross-posting, and we don't migrate on-topic questions.

Comment: What good would this canned message do besides make a few people think they've helped someone by telling them to shoo?  That doesn't seem like a very good message to send, especially in the Staging Ground.

Comment: @Makoto That's incorrect. There is a lot of reason to migrate the content elsewhere to begin with. 100% of the questions on vim are on topic on StackOverflow because it's been determined vim is a programming tool regardless of how it's used. That doesn't mean questions on vim are better here. It doesn't make for a better environment for vim users looking for help, or stackoverflow users. Regardless of the 27,000 questions here on vim, I would always suggest people take their vim questions to [vim.se]

Comment: @Makoto the help is (a) pointing those asking questions to a community _more_ likely to have the skills sought after or which has established itself as an SME on the material, and (b) not having selfless SMEs of other communities have to spit their efforts to address the same subject matter on both sites: there is clearly overlap on subject matter, and as a PostgreSQL SME I want to be able to help people on _both_ sites who need help. Though I'd rather the questions land on the best home for them.

Comment: It shouldn't be a [run-on sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences).