# Why has staging ground been empty for a few weeks?

Tags: discussion, staging-ground

A few months ago, the second beta version of Staging Ground was [announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423469/10952503). I joined it a few days after the post.

For the past few weeks, there are no proposed questions on it. We can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/review-history) that it's not only me, there are simply no more reviews.

The last few ones we can see are people that fixed their posts according to previous reviews.

Is this a bug, or the end of testing? As we don't have feedback, there is no end date in post and there is no new question on meta SO; there is no news about it. Also, Stack Overflow Team seems to work on another feature so will it be down? There is already work on it?

Comment: See: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56435059#56435059

Comment: Also https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/questions/527

Comment: The links in the comments above are not visible to everyone. The official announcement is still "The second beta round will extend indefinitely, ending when we get to the MVP release. "

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution the linked message, in chat, states *"We are going to be pausing beta II as reviewer activity is mostly gone, and the dev team is temporarily pulled off to work on a different initiative. We are still committed to a public launch, but it is going to have to wait for the Fall. More details soon to come on the SOT* [Stack Overflow Team] *."*  So the second round is, no longer, indefinite.

Comment: @ThomA Thanks. Reviewer activity being mostly gone isn't a good sign for any possible launch.

Comment: "We are going to be pausing beta II as reviewer activity is mostly gone" - I was in beta 1 and was more active since I had more availability.... but I've had much less time during beta 2. Is this statement saying beta 2 isn't going so well *because* reviewers are just generally not involving themselves this round? This doesn't appear to bode well for the feature. I guess Yaakov isn't getting more detailed as to why.

Comment: @DrewReese i mean, there's certainly other reasons (*waives arms around widly*) that reviewer activity would have dropped, but also there was a bug (since fixed) that was getting in the way of it working well, and due to devs being pulled off of the project for "other initiatives", it was quite inconvenient to use for nearly a month

Comment: See: "[Moderation Strike: Stack Overflow, Inc. cannot consistently ignore, mistreat, and malign its volunteers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425000/3773011)" and "[What is the impact of the moderation strike?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425115/3773011)"

Comment: @KevinB Yes, there are now some obvious "distractions". 

Comment: Also noteworthy - SG Beta badges have been awarded a second time after questions have been removed from the SG.

Comment: Re *"pulled off to work on a different initiative"*: Yes, that wasn't unexpected. The Staging Ground is now more than one year late. It is important that they [get it right the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) as there will not be a second chance, but still.

Comment: [The team were moved onto the AI project](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-i-would-do-ran-stack-overflow-product-yaakov-ellis-y7fnf/). That project is currently still failing miserably, sucking up resources like a black-hole, and costing the jobs of much-valued staff, particularly CMs i.e., our last, it feels at times, meaningful way of engaging with an increasingly distant company.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As Thom A mentioned [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425461/why-has-staging-ground-been-empty-for-a-few-weeks?cb=1#comment964564_425461), developer Yaakov Ellis  said:

> We are going to be pausing beta II as reviewer activity is mostly gone, and the dev team is temporarily pulled off to work on a different initiative. We are still committed to a public launch, but it is going to have to wait for the Fall. More details soon to come on the SOT (link to SO Team).

The Staging Ground is still paused as of that message (Jun 14th, 12:27 PM UTC). The ~90 or so posts that were in the Staging Ground at the time were reviewed (mostly by Yaakov himself) and there have been no more since.

Speaking from experience, reviewer interest *was* at an all-time low. Whether that's because of a lack of rewards for reviewers' time (more on that from a more official source later...), the ongoing curation strike, or reviewer burnout is unclear. I was personally feeling quite burnt out, and I know a few others were, too.

I'm sure Yaakov Ellis will post an update here on Meta SO when things continue moving forward. As mentioned, the dev team has been pulled in a bunch of different directions lately. The layoffs, which seems to have disproportionately affected Engineering, probably haven't helped with their availability.

While the decision to pause the Staging Ground may seem like this second round of Beta testing had a severe lack of reviewer activity, I can say that from the [review history page](https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/review-history), there were about **5500 review actions** taken during Beta 2. This is a large increase from Beta 1's **1550 review actions**. Notably, multiple review actions can be taken on a post (e.g. it takes two "Close" reviews to close an SG post, a post can have multiple "Requires Major Changes" reviews if the author resubmits it multiple times for re-review, etc.) but this is still a sharp increase in reviewer activity.

On the topic of the Staging Ground, I'm committed to singing the praises of all of the developers, CMs, and other staff members who are involved with the project. As a Beta reviewer and someone who was actively giving feedback throughout this most recent Beta round, I have **never** felt more heard than with this initiative. Yaakov Ellis has expressed elsewhere that he's going to try and push for this sort of workflow (close discussion with the community with rapid-release Beta testing) to be the standard moving forward, and if that becomes the case, I hope you all take advantage of participating in those initiatives, because it's *very* satisfying seeing your feedback addressed and in many cases immediately acted upon by the development team.

Comment: Yes, quite the change in company culture from last winter during SG Beta 1 and... now. I agree that it did feel our feedback was not only heard, but quickly acted on.

Comment: I'd prefer the process to be a little less private. Not necessarily realtime access to teams, but routine rundowns of what's discussed/done/changed so the broader community can discuss it.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah I agree. It's quite invisible what's going on for large durations of time for those who aren't participating in the Beta. I'd honestly at least partially attribute the lack of consistent update posts to be a lack of staff availability given the... other initiatives going on at the moment (cough cough genAI)

Comment: For transparency, my personal reason for not reviewing in the SG towards the any more was a holiday, being busy when I got back (and forgetting it existed) and a lack of posts related to the tags I follow (volume was limited intentionally while in beta). I am sure other users had similar reasons; the tool as a whole was received very well from the posts in the SOT.

Comment: Honestly this is a real bummer. SG looked like it could address *a lot* of problems of using SO, realising this was *silently* binned is a "why bother if they don’t" moment.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi To be fair, the wording seems to imply "We're not done yet, just taking some time to address other projects" and not "We're done with this, thanks for playing."

Comment: Yaakov's statement still stands as far as I am aware. Development of it is just currently on pause. As far as I know,  it will be picked up later this year.

Comment: @Spevacus Look, I am past the point of betting on such promises. If they can't invest the manpower to continue it, why would they be able to invest the manpower to also neatly wrap it up, get back up to speed later, and then continue it? Pausing projects increases the workload, and there are always new projects coming along.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understand where you're coming from, but I *really* do think that this is just a case of developers being pulled away to work on priority projects (take that as you will) and not abandoning this project.

Comment: @Spevacus "pulled away to work on priority projects (take that as you will)" I do. That's the problem.

Comment: @Spevacus Thank you for the kind words. We really appreciated the beta reviewer involvement thus far and I can say personally that it was a joy to collaborate so closely.

Comment: "different initiative" i.e. shoe-horning Chat-GPT into SO to hype shareholders. That's what is taking precedence over actually making the site more newbie friendly

Comment: \*Puts on tinfoil hat\* Maybe they are all busy handling the red flags across the network.