# Is the Staging Ground (un)officially abandoned?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, staging-ground

It's been *some* time since the 2nd Beta Test ended and we've had little to no news in the months since (including on the Teams site for the SG). Since then, we've had Communities (and its discussions "feature") and AI Search thrown at us; features that honestly the community hasn't received well, whereas the SG was a well-received and well-implemented Beta.

Is there any news on when this is coming to the community, or should we consider the project (un)officially abandoned?

The link is still in the menu for those of us that were beta testers, which gives me hope. It would be nice to hear *something*.

Comment: _We apologise for the fault in the staging ground feature. Those responsible have been sacked._  They are probably still reeling from October's layoffs.

Comment: Might be the fact that it is the end of the year of course, I can imagine that putting this into production is kind of an undertaking. You don't want to do that in a time period where you're likely to be understaffed.

Comment: I honestly expect that to be the "official" answer, @yivi . I got a response of "staff-shortages" is a reason a support issue I have dating back to July is still open; something I can only find irony in, as if they are short-staffed then they only have themselves to blame...

Comment: Hehe, maybe we should start a GoFundMe campaign for Staging Ground.

Comment: Probably relevant (but known to the OP): [Why has staging ground been empty for a few weeks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425461/why-has-staging-ground-been-empty-for-a-few-weeks)

Comment: Yeah I was, @MisterMiyagi, and the response I quote over there says we should expect a release in Autumn (which today is the last day of) and we should have expected a post in the [Teams](https://stackoverflowteams.com/c/staging-ground-testing/questions) (which is yet to appear). I (probably) should have mentioned that in the post, in truth.

Comment: There was a recent message in the SG chat regarding it (for those who can access it): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56886653

Comment: And for those that can't; the message says there is no new information on the SG; it was passed to Project Leadership in early October and there is no news (that can be made public).

Comment: @ThomA It is *internet Autumn* which normally have two extra month to finish the work *after* [eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) ends :)

Comment: And now [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395234/farewell-yaakov-and-thanks-for-the-haiku) happened. *"Alpha Staging Ground (please please!)"*

Comment: I am crying but there are still [things giving me hope for it](https://canary.discord.com/channels/628507458452586497/628507458910027777/1182311110012063828) (for people in it, it's in the Discord which was also used for organizing the strike - I don't like posting things 1:1 without people saying it somewhere that doesn't require _any_ authentication).

Comment: Also https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56917329

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just to (finally) close the loop here - please see [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2024/03/27/community-products-reflections-and-looking-ahead/) that Des released last week. In that, you will see that we announced that we will be reviving Staging Ground this year. Bella_blue gave us more information at [a post of her own](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429606/staging-ground-is-coming-back-and-moving-out-of-beta?cb=1). More to come soon.

Answer (score 21):

We are still very interested in moving Staging Ground forward as the initial beta was well received by all users. We plan to revisit it as soon as we can but for now, it can be considered "on hold" (officially).

Comment: Why has it taken over seven months (counting from when incoming new questions to the SG was halted on June 14th, 2023) to be able to give any response to legitimate community queries about the future of Staging Ground?

Comment: In my opinion, Staging Ground should be prioritized higher than discussions.

Comment: I'll take the bait, @YaakovEllis :) We are operating in a world of drastically reduced resources and that means hard prioritization decisions need to be made. The fact that this was undetermined for so long is a sign that there are people internally who are fighting to keep investing in it.  By far the easiest thing to do (once it was shuttered) would have been to abandon it.

Comment: As a former Stacker, I know you understand this and hope you are coming from a place of compassion and empathy for your former colleagues. While we still don't have specific answers, I agree that it's been too long since there was any update. When it's picked up again, Meta will be the first to know.

Comment: @Des that doesn't answer the question. the question was _**why**_ it took so long to give a status/plans update. all you said is that the project isn't being prioritized (which is already clear to everyone here), and that you agree that it took too long to give an update. you totally evaded the question. (aside: you have all my sympathy for the tough spot non-executive staff are in due to the executive decisions that have and are being made)

Comment: @starball The "why" is all right there. We are operating in a world of drastically reduced resources, hard prioritization decisions need to be made, this was undetermined for a long while. There was not an update to provide.

Comment: I guess the question is why something that's got a  direct, measurable benefit to the community lose out to collectives (which I notice had sponsorship dropped by a few former sponsors) and discussions, as well as the GenAI initiatives which have delivered nothing of any real use.

Comment: @berthold so you are saying that this whole time when SG was on hold (which we all know was the case) there was really an internal debate going on about whether to completely abandon the project, or just to put it on indefinite hold, and thus it was inappropriate to respond to repeated community inquiries about this for over seven months?

Comment: @des if you had led with an apology (as a representative of the company, even if it wasn't your call) for ignoring very reasonable inquiries (both internal and external) about the future of this project for so long, then I wouldn't be pursuing this line. But I find the neglect of consideration for the length of time that has elapsed, and responding as if this was asked last week, to be at the very least worthy of comment.

Comment: I'm happy to see some thread of hope that SG could see the light of day after being so close to release. I'm still tremendously upset that the decision to pause it last year has had no meaningful impact on those in charge, while the community and staff that worked incredibly hard on it are left with nothing but hope.

Comment: And I am showing empathy and compassion here by restricting my comments to only this one small point, and not this like how SG was apparently on the chopping block to begin with, or...so many other things (keeping my thoughts about that [off the site](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-i-would-do-ran-stack-overflow-product-yaakov-ellis-y7fnf)).

Comment: I'll jump in here.  I'm very sorry that there was a long period of time without a response on Staging Ground.  Honestly, in my case,I simply didn't know what to say. We hadn't (still haven't) made decisions about the best way to move forward on it - and (although it's not in my direct control) we should have been better at explaining what the status was.  At this point, our new Chief Product Officer is busy evaluating the landscape and figuring out exactly where we are on a number of different fronts.

Comment: As soon as that's all settled, my team will be communicating our priorities as a company for the next fiscal year (ours starts in April). Although I understand why people are hurt and upset that something they put such an effort into is in limbo (and you know, Yaakov, that I was a strong suppporter of staging ground from literally the beginning, so I care too...) I would hope that everyone involved could remember that the situation is complex and that people of good will can disagree on how to proceed.

Comment: Personally, I still have high hopes for a strategy for the future that includes Staging Ground, or another similar tool that we build learning lessons from Staging Ground. I believe in the concept, but I also know the practical and financial realities on the ground are that some things will be shelved, others may be pushed out in waves, and still others prioritized immediately. But I have a high degree of trust in our new CPO and in the executive team here, and I know they're all making the hard decisions based on what they genuinely believe is the right thing to do.

Comment: Personally, I could go the rest of my life without hearing another variation on "they're doing what they genuinely believe is right with the information they have" and not miss it. Everyone does that. And everyone makes mistakes. Sometimes very costly mistakes that hurt other people. I'm not looking for folks who aren't *literal, cartoonishly-evil villains,* I'm looking for folks who are willing to recognize their mistakes, learn from them, and take steps to avoid making the exact same mistakes again.

Comment: @Philippe In a situation like this in future, a simple "Discussions are still happening internally, and nothing has been decided, and we don't know when that will change" might be useful.