# Remove Staging Ground section from Help Center

Tags: feature-request, help-center, staging-ground

Now that Staging Ground is [officially on hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427877/242), remove all references to it from the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-staging-ground).

> We plan to revisit it as soon as we can but for now, it can be considered "on hold" (officially).

Or at least clearly indicate in the Help Center that it's on hold.

Comment: Well, Philippe from Staff mentioned in a Comment to the Thread/Answer you are referring to, that [they will post an Update around/before the beginning of April (2024)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427363/is-the-staging-ground-unofficially-abandoned/427877#comment985235_427877), that's about another 2 weeks... Give them maybe until this time..., or ask for this Update...

Comment: I feel like it's not too much of an issue to still have a page in the Help Center that describes what it is... It's on hold. Not binned.

Comment: I would support removal if the help center actually had a clear goal. But right now it's just a thrown together amalgamation of rules, documentation and beta features. It needs a complete overhaul and untangling.

Comment: Presenting Staging Ground in the Help Center as a first-class citizen is misleading. It's advertising a limited release beta feature that is not currently available. I would love to see Staging Ground come back but there aren't many instances of SO re-engaging with features/products once they've fallen off the back of the excitement wagon. I do agree though that it's not the end of the world to leave it there until Philippe communicates the latest company priorities in April.

Comment: And like I said, ... only had to wait for 11 days, and tagada...!: "[Staging Ground is coming back and moving out of beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429606/3799241)". // I reckon Staff will now soon update the Help Center...

Comment: @chivracq Touché. Well called.