# How to deal with users that seem to use SO instead of thinking?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Without finger pointing, I have the feeling that some users ask questions, whenever they hit a problem no matter how simple the problem is. I agree, that there are problems which seem simple to more experienced programmers. However, I think the purpose of SO is not to teach programming.

As an example: I noticed that a user asked several questions regarding Swift. Some questions are well-formed, others are not. However, most questions were solvable with a little thinking, e.g. in one question the user used an array of types of which he tried to assign one item to another variable later on. He was confused by the error message but could have noticed, that the types stored in the array did not match the one of the variable which he tried to initialize.

Just out of curiosity, I was looking around and found similar questions from the exact same user. This makes me think, that he is not even trying to find an answer by himself but quickly posts a question.

TL;DR In the case, that a user "mis-uses" SO to prevent thinking, how to deal with them?

If I am aware of this situation, I think more careful whether to answer or to flag. But is this a good strategy? Because, the user will not learn that his behavior lead to flagging.

Comment: Down-vote! For god's sake down-vote!

Comment: Related: [Please stop being a care bear, and proceed to be harsher at once.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/1842065).

Comment: @gnat IMO this is a little different. Because the user shows at least some effort. It is just, that he stops at some point.

Comment: @SebastianDressler per my reading the [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/839601) given there covers this

Comment: @gnat yes, I'd agree on that.

Comment: There simply is no requirement to think.  There used to be one, a notion of "minimal effort" occasionally encouraged by a "what have you tried" comment.  But no more.  SO users like it that way.

Comment: I suspect that, often, there is cetainly thinking going on.  Usually, I suspect it's along the lines of 'why should I do any hard work if I can con some other moronic drone to do it for me?'

Answer (score 9):

> Downvote, downvote, downvote and give them the boot, the boot.
>
> Downvote, downvote, downvote and give them the boot.

If enough of their questions are downvoted, they will be banned.

Comment: a.k.a. the downvote Song.