# Is it a good practice to provide solutions for non-debugging questions without attempts, which feel hardly reusable?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've recently come across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649027/aggregating-data-in-javascript-with-two-criteria) seeking **how to** achieve a task about aggregating data in JavaScript. I've noticed that the question got downvoted with people calling out that the OP has not provided an attempt at a solution to their problem.

From [the top answer of "Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/9107694), I've been led to believe that a question is required to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example only when it's a debugging question, otherwise **Definition effort**, **Problem solving effort**, and **Research effort** should be shown.

In this case, I do see a solid explanation for the question (Definition effort) and some links to some solutions that the OP doesn't know how to make use of (Problem solving effort).
However, I know that such a question is hard to be reusable for solving others' problems, and won't have any solution online as well. Hence, I'm not sure about **Research effort**.

Another example is [a how-to question I've asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77573895/how-to-update-a-label-multiple-times-asynchronously-after-a-button-click), where I am afraid that without any example attempts the question will be downvoted or closed. Hence I've provided a workaround code, but really it isn't what I want. And eventually someone provided a genius solution that had nothing to do with the workaround code that I provided.

Is it good practice to provide solutions from scratch to such questions?

Should I even attempt to provide solutions from scratch for such questions?

---

- Might be Related: [Answering questions when no attempt has been made](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364755/) I did not find an answer inside and it seems like the OP thinks these questions should be closed.
- Related: [Do questions have to have an attempted solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284599/) Explained that such questions are valid, but from what I've observed, such questions will be downvoted a lot and potentially get closed, and answers provided will be downvoted simultaneously as well, which discourages people from answering.

Comment: Note I've deleted my answer on that question because of a misunderstanding of what OP want, and I'm not sure if I should even attempt to fix it since the answer I've provided will not be useful for anyone else other than the OP.

Comment: That's your own decision to make. Ideally we want useful questions and answers, not questions and answers that only serve to help the asker. A question doesn't need an attempt at solving the problem for an answer to be a long-term useful answer for many people.

Comment: Yes I saw this post, it is based on if we can **ask** such question, where the answer is yes we can. Since the question has already been ask, and I know at least one solution, I'm not sure if it is encouraged to answer such question. From what I've observed, such question will downvoted a lot and potentially being closed, and answers to those question will be downvoted as well.

Comment: A how to question doesn't need an attempt, what could be discussed about it is whether it is focused enough. Personally to me it looks like the problem would be best solved by breaking it down into multiple pieces (e.g. create separate arrays for each date, aggregate away things that don't meet threshold, aggregate away till number of fruits are more than threshold)

Comment: @SyndRain I'm not certain you should be so sure that your answer "will not be useful for anyone else other than OP"; speaking for myself, I learn things from parts of solutions to problems that are different than my own all the time... even answers to very specific problems can be extrapolated to other problems by readers.

Comment: Yes I agree to this, one reason I've ask this question is because I think it is not to me to judge a answer and question is not useful to anyone else solely. That's also why I said "hard to" in the question.

Comment: @abdul-aziz-barkat I see, and I agree that it might require multiple steps, which is also what the original answer I've provided did. Also, I believe requiring multiple steps will have nothing to do with a question being focus enough or not, correct?

Comment: The "These solutions solve part of the problem but I wasn't able to combine them to generate the desired output:" part very much sounds like they do have an attempt and failed only at part of it. Either showing that one (to clarify what their actual problem is) or removing any mention of it (to show it's a general question) would be helpful to clarify the question.

Comment: FWIW, the first question has issues regardless of showing an attempt. It's outright *massive* example with three huge data blocks (one even being just large enough to get a scroll bar...). I don't even get how the results match to the rules described - no idea where those `blueberries` above the `minSalePct` went...

Comment: @mistermiyagi Maybe the example can be cut down, I think it's pretty clear that blueberries are moved to `others` because the `maxFruit` is 3, and it is not top 3 in overall `salePct`, which has nothing to do with `minSalePct`. I do think there should be at least 3~4 fruits and 2~ 3 dates to demonstrate all criteria

Comment: @SyndRain`blueberries` is already removed from the `aggregatedByThreshold` before `maxFruit` enters the picture.

Comment: @mistermiyagi Ah you are right, the OP did mentioned in the comment in the answer that I've deleted that A fruit would be added to others if its salePct is lower than the minSalePct for **any** of the available dates, but nevertheless this should be included in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: However, I am pretty certain that the downvotes are from no attempts being showed, because the downvotes happens simultaneously when the "no attempt" comment received helpful votes.

Comment: @SyndRain This is (was...) included in the question, specifically mentioning it has to apply for *all* the available dates. No matter how we spin it, the question *wasn't* (and likely still isn't if one has to hunt for individual words in all that volume) useful. While an attempt isn't needed, it would at least have cleared up the logic - which *is* needed.

Comment: True! I agree that a question should at least have cleared up the logic, or it won't be useful and deserved downvote!

Comment: "_Definition effort, Problem solving effort, and Research effort should be shown._" sounds like you've severely misunderstood the post that you read. please read it again. particularly the part about problem-solving effort.

Comment: IMO I think that question can be useful to others as an answer will demonstrate some valuable data juggling skills. It's just that nobody is going to find it, which kind of deflates the whole thing. But at that point in my opinion it starts to get a little ambiguous if it should then be treated as "not useful for others" because Google tends to point me directly to answers, I hardly ever see the question itself so without an actual answer to judge by it is in limbo for me. But I think because the question in practice contains multiple questions, it is going to be closed as needs more focus.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> I've believe that question is required to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example only when they are debugging questions, otherwise Definition effort, Problem solving effort, and Research effort should be shown.

How-to questions do not require an attempt, and in fact **code showing an attempt is often counterproductive** (it makes the question worse by splitting attention between the intended "how do I do this?" versus "what's wrong with this code?" - and the problem with the code can often be completely unrelated to the task being attempted).

They do, however, require a) **a precise specification** (How is input provided, and how is it structured? What logic does the code need to implement? How will the output be provided and formatted? How can we *objectively verify* whether a given solution attempt is correct?) and b) **adequate focus** (i.e., it needs to be about one specific problem that is clearly understood).

"How do I integrate these two libraries to solve the overall task?" will generally not qualify for that, because it lacks *clarity*; we can't clearly understand what the actual point of difficulty is. Also, *the fact that two libraries are proposed for use* implies that the overall task needs more focus; it clearly breaks down into a series of steps.

**We don't do problem-solving or analysis here for the most part** (aside perhaps from some generic computer-science algorithm sorts of things). A problem with integrating libraries generally either boils down to a nondescript lack of understanding of how to put together pieces of a program (which will *usually* not be something that can form a coherent question, unless the problem is with some *clear technical* matter e.g. [how to call a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785933/) or [use its results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793/)); or else it comes from a failure to consider *what the output will be* from the "first" library, *what input is needed* for the "second", and therefore what adaption (if any) is necessary.

Your own question seems fine. Showing your workaround improves the question because it demonstrates *why you consider it a workaround*, and therefore clarifies what you want the program (really, the combined client-server system) to be able to do that it doesn't already.

> My question is: Is it a good practice to provide solutions from scratch to such questions? Should I even attempt to provide solutions from scratch for such questions?

If it's clear that the task breaks down into a series of straightforward logical steps, in one particular way, and there isn't a good reason to expect a "built-in" solution for the whole task, then please flag or vote to close as "Needs More Focus", and do not answer.

Otherwise, use your judgment; the closure reasons are fairly straightforward IMO aside from that one interpretation. **Questions that don't merit closure, merit answers**, because the primary purpose of closure is to prevent answers.

If the question shows a workaround, sometimes it will make more sense to modify that workaround and other times it will make more sense to start from scratch. OP can't always reasonably know which of those will be the case; that's why there is a question.

---

The point isn't so much to "show" effort in those categories (and certainly not to simply *claim* to have made that effort!), but rather to **ask a question that reflects the result** of that effort.

The question doesn't need to look like the OP spent a lot of time thinking about the problem specification; it needs to *have* a specification that meets standards, and arriving at that specification generally takes effort.

The question doesn't need to look like the OP spent a lot of time trying to solve a larger problem; it just needs to be about a specific thing that has been clearly identified, and typically that is the result of doing problem solving and determining a missing piece of the puzzle, then clearly defining it.

The question doesn't need to look like the OP spent a lot of time with a search engine; it just needs to not be a duplicate, and needs to be phrased in a way such that it's clear *why there could possibly be a question* about the matter.

Comment: *Questions that don't merit closure, merit answers* - I feel like there's a middle ground here. There are questions I downvote and think don't "deserve" an answer (and certainly don't want to spend time writing one myself), but which I don't VTC since they're not truly off-topic and/or I couldn't find a close-enough duplicate. And I'm not *sure* that nobody should answer; preventing others from answering by closing it is a higher threshold for me than just personally thinking it probably doesn't have much future value and/or quality, where reasonable people may disagree.

Comment: @PeterCordes In principle, I don't think there is middle ground. However, no individual is solely responsible for deciding which bin the question falls into; and everyone is therefore welcome to abstain from that decision. And then, there doesn't seem to be any strong consensus about downvoting. Personally it is very rare that I downvote a question without also casting a close vote (unless it's an already closed question that I'm treating as a deletion candidate), and fairly rare that I downvote a question that's already at or below -3 (because I don't find it a useful signal beyond that).

Answer (score 4):

Whether an attempt was made is a simple [sniff test](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sniff_test) that *in my experience* generally, **but not always** can be used to determine whether a question is on-topic for Stack Overflow and thus worth answering. If an asker demonstrates an honest attempt to solve the problem (note: code spat out by ChatGPT does not constitute "honest attempt"), that generally indicates they've thought it out to some degree, and in my experience this almost always results in a good question. In contrast, and again in my experience, questions that lack attempts are generally flawed in one or more ways.

I applied this basic test to the question you first linked, and came away with a tinge of help vampire in my nostrils, which put me on alert. Then I read the comments, both on the question and your since-deleted answer, by the asker - that are changing the question after the fact because it hasn't been properly thought through, and trying to convince you to tailor your since-deleted answer to further requirements - and the vampire was confirmed. The question has now been staked via close votes and the vampire banished.

In short, whether an attempt was made can be used as *a way* to get a "feel" for whether a question is good or bad. But like most criteria that curators use, and like most things to do with human beings, it's not a black/white absolute - just a guide, that should always be used together with multiple other criteria to most adequately evaluate a question.

As for your question, I believe it's poor because it feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You say you want to fire thousands of web requests, but you don't say **why**, and in my experience that's the hallmark of such a question: you have a problem, and instead of thinking it all the way through to an optimal solution, you've instead jumped on the first solution that you've come up with. Plot twist, most first solutions are simple, obvious - and completely, utterly wrong, which makes questions about them a waste of time.

In your question, therefore, the lack of "why" is its own sniff test - just like a lack of an attempt would be - that the question is likely a bad fit for SO. In your case you did get an answer, but said answer did start by pointing out that you appear to be asking the wrong question, as webforms is really not an appropriate tech for what you want to do. Personally, I've found that including "why" when writing my own questions has helped me avoid posting many that don't make sense; it's amazing how reading what your brain is thinking, can allow you to see how off-course you are!

In short, the simple, obvious *and wrong* answer to the question

> Is it a good practice to provide solutions for non-debugging questions without attempts, which feel hardly reusable?

is "no". The far more correct, but arguably far less useful, answer is

> It depends on a variety of factors, of which attempts are only one.

Ultimately it comes down to you, as a smart human being, *engaging your brain* and evaluating a question on as many criteria as possible. A lot of this is simply experience, i.e. using the site to get a feel for which questions are good and bad. This will allow you to make, and continually improve, your own judgement when it comes time for you to ask yourself the question you've posed to us.