# Disputed audit - How to make a Transparent Layer over the CardIView Item?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11557287 on [How to make a Transparent Layer over the CardIView Item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309261/how-to-make-a-transparent-layer-over-the-cardiview-item)

The question basically

- asks for a complete solution to some general problem
- is crappily put together, essentially being

  - a spammy image (one or two sections at most would suffice)

    - I even got a warning that it "was detected as possible spam" (though it might be fake)
  - "current code" that is loosely relevant (as the asker says they don't yet have a solution at all).

I.e. it's "too broad/opinion-based/work request" for me, and the only reason it wasn't closed is because it had bounty on it.

Comment: How is the image spammy? Looks like generic descriptions to me.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Maybe, here in Russia we're not so saturated with full-page images advertizing something (especally something not affiliated with the place where it's posted) to see them as nothing special. I would crop the image to an absolute minimum or turn off the pictures.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev The image is useful, relevant to the question, and seems entirely reasonably sized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> asks for a complete solution to some general problem

As opposed to what? Asking for half a solution?

I see a question that's:

- about programming;
- understandable;
- specific and answerable.

Furthermore, the author did seem to make some effort and included code ([which is not even a requirement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/660921)).

Questions asking "how do I do foo?" are not inherently off-topic. Sometimes you *just don't know* how to "do foo". As long as "foo" is a specific and answerable problem this is usually fine.

The problem is when "foo" is a very broad topic. Asking "how do I make an Android app" is basically the topic for an entire book. Asking "How do I play sound in an Android app" is the topic for a book chapter, but asking "How do I make this transparent" is specific enough for a Stack Overflow answer.

I don't understand why you think this is opinion-based. Sure, there are perhaps more ways to skin this cat, but that doesn't make it **primarily** opinion-based.

> a spammy image (one or two sections at most would suffice)
>
> I even got a warning that it "was detected as possible spam" (though it might be fake)

It's not spammy. It help describe the problem. I wish more questions came with images like this. That the spam filter erroneously detected it as possible spam is irrelevant. It's not spam.

> is crappily put together

It's not stellar, but this is why the "edit" button exists. It's clear what the author is asking, and that's enough.

Comment: I had a very hard time figuring out what the asker needs and what they have (for a moment, it's a strict requirement for question validity). Only comments shed some light on this, and even they are barely comprehensible. Is this really a perfectly valid question worthy of checking ppl against?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev It's not a stellar question, no; probably due to lack of English skills and different sizing in the screenshots which makes it look a bit "messy". But it seems obvious enough what the problem is? He adds a new layer and it's not in the right position. IMHO it's not "barely comprehensible" ... "Is this really a valid question" -> I think so, because this is a question that looks shitty if you just cast a casual glance, but makes sense once you spend 15 seconds of effort in reading and comprehending the question. [Not every question needs to be perfect](http://tinyurl.com/gl89rsw).

Comment: To be fair, although it looks superficially like an acceptable question to me, I have no idea what the person actually means by "transparent layer over the grid." I wouldn't feel comfortable making any moderation decisions on that basis, though, since I don't know anything about Android programming. If you are in that same boat, @ivan, as your profile suggests that you might be, you should click "Skip."

Comment: @CodyGray The phrasing is indeed slightly confusing, but he just means that it doesn't align with his product boxes, in which case it should be "Unclear what you're asking", not "too broad/opinion-based/work request" as Ivan mentioned in his question above ;-)