# Which flag to use on a question that doesn't show minimal research if "low quality" is unavailable?

Tags: discussion, bug, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

Some time ago I flagged a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42333763/how-to-use-windbg-to-debug-a-driver) that in my opinion showed no research and was a complete waste of time. The question was more or less "I'm following this and that guide to do something and it doesn't work. What to do?"

Fifteen minutes after asking the question OP answered himself: He needed to turn the firewall off - something that was clearly noted in the link he supposedly followed.

The "very low quality" flag was unavailable to me at the time, and none of the other flags seemed appropriate to me. It wasn't spam in the usual sense, wasn't rude or abusive, wasn't an exact duplicate of another question, and didn't fit any of the "should be closed..." options: IT certainly wasn't opinion-based, it was *not* unclear what was being asked, and it didn't fit any of the available off-topic options.

The closest available options was "too broad". But while the question was rather broad, there *were* clues pointing at a network problem.

The question was simple bad because the answer was "actually do *all* the steps in the guide."

With "low quality" unavailable I picked

> **in need of moderator intervention**
>
> A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed!*

because the problem *wasn't* listed.

In the test box I entered:

> Very low quality. Does not show *minimal* amount of research. Answer is basically "actually do *all the steps* in the link provided in the question."

The flag was declined with the message:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

I looked at the link. Didn't help me. Which flag am I not familiar with and I should have used? Or should I have not flagged this question at all?

Perhaps it's a bug that the "low quality" flag is unavailable to question with positive number of votes? Perhaps the assumption that low quality posts will have negative score is too strong, and it makes flagging more difficult than it should be?

--

*Edit:*

The question [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) and its answer do not sufficiently address my issue.

The distinction the accepted answer makes is useful, but the two reasons is gives for not having a close reason for #3 are false and do not apply in the case I'm asking about:

1. Judging problem-solving is not subjective when OP himself answers his own question with an answer that amounts to "I actually *did* what the documentation page I already had in my hands, and that solved by problem." OP admits that he did not do what the documentation told him to do.
2. I am not requiring *maximizing* effort. On the contrary, I'm requesting the bare minimum - try to do what you were already told to do by the official documentation you are fully aware of and claim you read.

   The answer is maybe right in that "if we disallow all questions that don't require investment *beyond* research, we give up the ability for folks to research their problems *using* Stack Overflow", but that is not what I'm suggesting. I'm suggesting to disallow question that don't require investment *including* research. This is the point where the distinction the answer makes kind of breaks down.

   The answer defines:

   - **Research effort**: has the asker searched for a solution before asking?
   - **Problem-solving effort**: has the asker done anything to solve the problem himself before asking?

   but considers actually *doing* what the research effort produced at part of the problem-solving effort. That makes the research effort part meaningless. If we allow for questions about things the poster knows but didn't do, it doesn't matter if he knows them from the official documentation or from another SO question. In both cases he finds the answer, doesn't do what it says, and asks another one. But if the answer was found in another SO question it is considered duplicate and no "research effort" while if the answer was found in the documentation (he was aware of and read!) it's considered lack of "problem solving" research and the duplicate reason doesn't apply. That's an odd distinction at the very least.

Comment: The downvote flag is appropriate in these situations.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: That's true for all the possible reason to flag a question or an answer, isn't it? Are you saying that it is not only *appropriate* but also *enough* and there was no need to flag it?

Comment: Yes. If a question lacks research, downvote. If it can't be useful to others, maybe flag as typo, but that's debatable, and we don't want to repeat the errors of Too Localized.

Comment: Questions that lack reseach effort but are not otherwise off-topic should not be flagged. Use voting instead.

Comment: Sounds like "typographical error or no longer happening" is perfect for this case. Also note that being self-answered question does not mean that question need to be treated to any different standards - it still needs to show research and provide enough information to answer (which makes creating such Q&A pairs appropriately hard).