# Are preemptive questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a Python problem which I am sure has been already addressed (how to manage an exception list where some items are specific and others are a wildcard - this leads to entries like `10.10.10.10,*` or `*,222` and an orthogonality is sought after. I am just highlighting the nature of the problem to show that it is common).

I am sure that a library or typical approach exists and before reinventing my own version of the wheel I would like to just ask "is there a standard approach to tackle this". Of course, I tried to search for a cookbook recipe first but nothing popped out.

This means that I have not made any effort to code anything **yet**, so the question is likely to be angrily downvoted because (among others, probably) "you did not show any code" (correct), "this is a recommendation" (also correct).

Is such a question blatantly off topic?

If so - is there a SE area where it would be more appropriate?

Comment: So I'm confused as to why you can't try to do this yourself before asking. Then, if someone knows of a library, they can add an answer say, "Use <library>; here's how."

Comment: *"this is a recommendation" (also correct)* Well if you're asking for people to recommend an off site resource, then yes it's blatantly off topic. Not showing code is only blatantly off topic for debugging questions but you're right that asking how to do this without showing an attempt would be down voted for not being well researched. It could also be considered too broad if writing an answer from scratch would be too long.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: sure I can try and write something subpar and overly complicated, to learn afterwards that it is actually a red-blue balanced tree (I am making this up) and if i only used numpy.redbluetree I would have had it in a second. What I am missing here is the ability to quickly decide between "there is a ready-made solution for that" vs. "you have to code it yourself". As an example, I once knew someone who almost started to rewrite a firewall, just to be told to use one instead (he was so into his problem that he missed that obvious solution).

Comment: Sounds like that person didn't do enough research... Basically, you're asking the volunteers on Stack Overflow to do your research for you, and we want Stack Overflow to be the last place people come, not the first.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: no, I am asking the volunteers on SO to glance at the problem and if they recognize something which is not obvious to someone who is not a good coder - to just direct him on the right track. I have done quite a bit of research in my life (PhD in physics) to understand how useful it is to have someone helping to bootstrap some knowledge, if only to say 'looks like a red-blue balanced tree problem', something I would never imagine no matter the amount of research. Anyway, thanks for the answer, it clarifies (and confirms) that SO is not the right place for such questions.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: ('cont'd) this is said without any vitriol or sarcasm, I just need to look somewhere else (or code it myself, to discover one day that it is 3 lines of code when one knows the nature of the problem and how to ask the question)

Comment: Research effort is different than coding effort. Research effort means you looked for similar questions, and detailed why those didn't work for you. Coding effort actually makes the site less usable. No one is going to be searching for the exact code that you wrote, which means your question will be useless to anyone other than yourself. Best to show research effort, formulate a clear on-topic question. Check out [this answer on the topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281) for more information.

Comment: I can relate to that very much. For example, I am a beginner with using some specific library and want to solve a specific problem (which is not that exotic - so, it might be useful to the community, too). I have done research but did not find any recipe for doing it. I'd like to avoid reinventing a wheel and writing some ugly code, when there is a high chance someone experienced could show how to do it properly in a few lines of code. However, if I ask a question about "how to do it properly" without posting my ugly code, the question, very likely, will be closed.