# Option to close question as "Request to code"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

I often come across questions like "How can I do this" without even an attempt to solve the problem.

IMO such problems should have an option to be closed as **"Request to code, without an attempt"**, as the OP wouldn't even have attempted to solve the coding problem and wants the community to solve(or code) it for him.

Example [Hadoop - Processing Single line JSON using JAVA Mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47019788/2142994)

Comment: I very much agree with this. There are many questions posted daily just like the one in the example.

Comment: The backstop for such questions is 'Too broad'.

Comment: It's called "duplicate". Allow me to demonstrate...

Comment: I want want extra options too, eg: 'OP has less debugging skill than an paramecium in a coma'.  Not gonna happen so, [sigh], 'Too broad'.

Comment: I like this title more than "zero-effort questions" because it makes it explicit that some people come here asking for others to do their work for them

Comment: @Shog9 [That question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) was neither a feature request nor is it a specific one. It is about zero-effort questions in general. I am specifically asking why not add a feature to close questions with **zero research effort** .

Comment: @MartinJames its not `Too broad`! The question is very specific like `write a python function to add number 'a' with number 'b' ` but there is just no research effort from the OP's side (he/she hasn't tried solving it). 
There is currently no option to tag these kinds of questions.

Comment: If the question doesn't qualify for the "too broad" close reason, and it isn't asking for *debugging help*, then you should not close it. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for practical programming problems, not a tutoring service. We aren't here to teach people how to program or enforce pedagogy, and we only care about seeing prior effort if it's necessary to limit the scope of the question to make it answerable. If it's answerable as asked, then *answer it*. Lack of research effort is a subjective downvote reason, not a closure reason.

Comment: Allow me to refer you to my question about [help-me] tag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358681/adding-help-me-and-teach-me-tags

Comment: See, they look an awful lot like duplicates to me, seeing as how they ask about adding a close reason for the same problem @Ani. And you didn't give any indication in your question here that you'd already read the (numerous) previous discussions on this topic and found them lacking in some way, so... Would you have preferred that I'd closed your question as "Asks for feature without even an attempt to find work-around" rather than linking you to the previous discussion? Because that's what you're asking for the ability to do here.

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins Would you answer a SO question like `Write a C++ function to multiply two numbers`? I think such questions should have a separate tag to be closed like "Request to code, without an attempt".

Comment: @Shog9  I don't see any of those answering my question. Why are we entertaining SO users to ask questions like "Code for me" or "Help me answer this assignment"?

Comment: Because they're useful to others? Or at least, they can be; there are certainly plenty that aren't, but as a class HOWTO questions are some of the most generally-useful questions on the site. Have a look at your own questions, or those you've found while searching: do you think anyone reading cares about failed attempts at solving the problem, or do you think they go straight to the answers that solve it successfully? Effort is only useful insofar as it either leads to a duplicate or aids someone else in answering; after that [it's just noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/).

Comment: ok @Shog9 go on answer every silly question. I wouldn't answer questions which are "Code for me".

Comment: So, don't. No one is making you. Downvote and move on...

Comment: @Ani No, I wouldn't answer "Write a C++ function to multiply two numbers", because that's *way* too broad. I would have like 100 questions before I could even *start* writing that code. If the question were clarified, like I have data in the following form, I'm looking for a fast vectorized solution using SSE2 intrinsics to multiply the numbers as quickly as possible, blah blah blah, then heck yes I'd answer it. It's still a "write code for me" request, but it's totally unproblematic because it's adequately specified. These are way more interesting questions than "debug my code for me", IMHO.

Comment: @CodyGray True that, in a circumstance where it involves some kind of optimization or improvement over the usual way its done then its a question worth answering. But I was suggesting this close tag for questions which are straight forward.