# Google one liner questions with no SO answer

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I was wondering what is the common policy for questions such as:

[I want to move alternate rows to another sheet in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920657/i-want-to-move-alternate-rows-to-another-sheet-in-excel#49920657)

It lacks research as googling the title or something close yields plenty of easy to follow results, and only one relevant SO question:

[Copying every nth Rows in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681002/copying-every-nth-rows-in-excel)

which may be close enough to be marked as a duplicate. In any case the question is in general is:

On easy short (3-4 line) answer questions available on Google but not SO, is it worth answering them on SO so they exist here as well, at least once, even if the question itself does not follow guidelines, or do we treat them as normal (say downvote for my above example)?

Just to be clear, I'm interested in the side of SO as an information accumulating community, regardless of the OP's behavior (and questions that can be improved if we choose to). The question above is an example, please try to not address it specifically in the comments.

Comment: if a question is trivial and obvious and we can easily find it within 2s search, honestly we should not answer [I tihnk]... I don't think such ressource will be good to the website. SO is related to programming issue that we cannot *easily* find, not a tutorial website.

Comment: Is that a common agreed to thing, that only issues that aren't easy to find should be answered? There are plenty of examples against, but they may have "slipped" through.

Comment: @kabanus The first reason on the downvote button is "this question does not show research effort". That first question linked indeed does not. You _could_ add a link to "idownvotedbecau.se", but given that OP's attitude, I doubt it'll help. (Also, compliments on staying friendly towards that OP, despite their attitude).

Comment: `should be answered?` --> Here it will depend on user, personnaly i downvote such question and vote to close them but some user run to answer *easy to find* question, they get upvoted, they upvote the question, we get more answers, they get accepted, etc .. We can do nothing about this though.

Comment: What's your problem with closing it as duplicate? This won't delete the new question and we won't need to duplicate the answer of the old question.

Comment: @S.L.Barth agreed, I'm more interested on the side of SOs prerogative. Does the **community** want to have these if it doesn't already, regardless of OP?

Comment: I would have voted to close this question for not being about programming. From the question itself it is unclear whether op is looking for a VBA solution or just wants to know how this can be done without programming. Also the sentence "Or will I have to use other software" makes me think that it is not programming related.

Comment: If it has already been answered here, it should be closed as a duplicate. If not, please don't try to get rid of it just because it's simple. If I ever need to search for the answer to a simple question, I want to find it a) in the official documentation of the language/library b) **here**. Preferably both.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The *premise* of this question is, "It lacks research as googling the title or something close yields plenty of easy to follow results", so clearly you *can* find the answer by searching for it if you have the problem.  The question is not asking about "easy" problems that do not have readily available solutions already out there.

Comment: @Servy I want to find an easy to follow result here, though. I like it here. I don't want to go to some _forum_ if I don't have to. If googling the title yields an easy to follow result _here_, then obviously it should be closed as a duplicate, but if not I'd rather have a version of the answer here, where it can be evaluated, improved, and maintained.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Why is duplicating readily accessible quality content here useful to the programming community?

Comment: @Servy I personally find it useful because of what I mentioned in the last part of my previous comment. Here we can interact with the content if we want to, vote on things, edit them, update them if they're out of date, show different ways to solve a problem, etc., you know. Elsewhere it's just take it or leave it, which is often okay, but just not as good as here. It's just my opinion though, I get that not everyone feels the same way.

Comment: @Servy why don't you post an answer so everyone can vote on them? I was looking for a few opinions, and am wondering what is the more common mindset.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I would also request you post your addition as an answer, as it is not addressed in the current only answer.

Comment: To everyone touting the "research effort" part of the downvote explanation: research only counts if the answer already exists ***on Stack Overflow***. If the answer does not exist on Stack Overflow and the question is on-topic, ***answer the damn question***. This insistence on shutting people down because their question is just to stupid for you is detrimental to everyone involved at best.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why on earth should people be expected to only ever do their research within the site?  No one said anything about shutting people down because "the question is stupid", but rather because "the answer is already readily accessible and the question is poorly researched".  Why is going around duplicating content helpful to anyone?  How is preventing the duplicating of *readily accessible quality content* detrimental to anyone?

Comment: @Servy research has only ever counted if the answer can be found on Stack Overflow. Otherwise 90% of this site should then be deleted because it can be found elsewhere on the internet. We don't  close questions as duplicates of the documentation for the given programming language. Come on, this insistence on shutting down reasonable question helps no one, and hurts stack overflow.

Comment: @TinyGiant Do you have a citation for the claim that the research expected of question authors *actually* means "research on the site" and not "research", as it actually says?  There are certainly lots of questions that don't have readily accessible quality answers *anywhere*.  Those are the good questions that are actually beneficial to both ask an answer.  You're correct that lots of quesitons asked on the site (probably not 90%, but still a lot) have readily accessible quality answers, either on SO or elsewhere.

Comment: Questions that don't demonstrate even the most minimal of research *aren't reasonable questions*.  Shutting them down helps the *useful* questions actually be found, and answered, and encourages people to do their research going forward.  It's harmful if your goal is to just spend all of your time duplicating content, instead of adding information of value.  SO even tried to create an explicit place that had the goal of just duplicating all of the content in documentation (since it didn't belong on the main site).  That...didn't turn out well.

Comment: @Servy Sure, [here's the reference you requested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions/260909#260909). I disagree with everything you said after that (other than the idea that purposefully recreating content may or may not be a bad thing, depending on the quality and accessibility of the original content, but that's not what we're talking about here)

Comment: @TinyGiant That just says that there's not a close reason for poorly researched questions without a duplicate on the site, not that a well researched question isn't expected to search more than just the site.  That fact is unfortunate, but indeed true.  As for whether this question is about re-creating content, of course it is.  The whole *premise* of the question is that quality answers are readily accessible elsewhere, meaning that asking it again here is just recreating content.

Comment: @Servy I disagree with your interpretation of that answer. As for the premise of this question. I see nothing in the question about **purposeful** re-creation of content.  As far as I can tell this question is about honest-to-goodness real questions whose answers can be found with a google search though not on Stack Overflow. Tim post posted some stats a while back on the fact that the vast majority of askers _do_ research before asking, one of the more common problems being that the asker just doesn't know the right search terms.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why does it matter if it's purposeful or not?  Re-creating readily available content doesn't suddenly become useful just because you did it by accident.  That people don't do a good job of doing their research doesn't make it useful to repeat the content *again*.  The people that wouldn't have found it before still won't find it even with that question there.

Comment: @Servy someome asking questions for the sake of duplicating content is an entirely different situation than someone who searched for an answer but didn't know the right terms to use and ends up asking a question which then causes the duplication of existing content. I at no point said that either was bad, I stated that they are two different situations and this question is about the latter, not the former, and that I fail to see how answering an answerable, on-topic, non-duplicate question can be a bad thing, or how not answering it could possibly be a good thing.

Comment: As for your insistence that someone not knowing the right search terms to use qualifies them as being an incompetent researcher and that no one would possibly find the question that contains the search terms the author _did_ use (the whole idea of sign posts)... that's just nonsense.

Comment: @TinyGiant The question is the same either way.  Whether they asked a question that isn't useful intentionally or by accident doesn't affect how useful the question is.  Answering poorly researched questions encourages people to continue not doing their research, adds nothing of value to the site or the programming community at large, lowers the quality of the content on the site, makes finding useful content harder, and discourages experts from wanting to participate.  All answering does is prevent one person from needing to do their own search before asking a question.

Comment: @TinyGiant The premise of the question is about questions that have readily available answers, not about questions were you couldn't reasonably expect anyone to have found the answer.  Yes, some questions are useful signposts because they're asking about an issue with existing resources, but in a way that prevents them from finding it.  Such questions are very rare.  Most questions asking about common problems aren't using entirely original terms for said issue.  It is *those* questions which are the ones that are poorly researched.

Comment: You again obviously have no interest in listening to reason so I'm done with this pointless argument. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think the discussion is taking a detour. I think the discussion should not focus on the people asking questions, but rather on whether we want the content on SO. Do we want SO to be a standalone manual of everything, or do we shrug off the easy stuff for the sake of a more high level sharpened tool?

Comment: @kabanus if the question is on-topic, answerable, and not a duplicate then it should be answered. Plain and simple, no ifs, ands or buts. This is a question and answer site and what we do here is answer questions that are on-topic, answerable and not duplicates. The point of this site is not to quibble over whether a question is good enough for our delicate sensibilities or not.

Comment: @TinyGiant I tend to agree with you, and like the answers below, but I think Servy's point is valid and want to wait a bit before accepting an answer. Look what happened to my example question for instance - I'm not sure if it's a canonical example, but at least shows there is some debate (there was an answer given, though it was deleted now).

Comment: But there are many answers, just googling the title with 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: @TinyGiant "research only counts if the answer already exists on Stack Overflow" [citation needed]. I've always seen research as actual research, not bound to SO content, otherwise we wouldn't downvote questions by that reason at all, since all the knowledge SO has is on the internet in one way or another.

Comment: @Braiam that's nonsense. If the answer already exists on Stack Overflow then your point is moot. We're building a repository of information, it makes no sense to exclude information from that repository solely because that information currently exists outside of the repository.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the question is on-topic, answerable, and not a duplicate, then there is absolutely no reason to prevent the OP or future readers for gaining access to the knowledge requested in the question.

Answer (score 9):

In general, not taking this specific example, as per request of OP:

As Stack Overflow wants to be a repository of questions and answers it might be useful to have even a simple question answered. That way:

- The answer to that simple question might be more likely to be found when using a search engine.
- The question might be less likely to be asked again on Stack Overflow, as the ask a question page then gives hints that this question might already be around.
- The question can be used as a dupe target. This makes gold badge holders able to dupe hammer a question, ensuring quicker closure compared to a question going through review.

The best course of action would be to self-answer such a "simple" question and mark it as community wiki if you ask me.

Comment: Errm... why would you ask and self answer a question that had already been asked instead of answering the existing question?

Comment: Well not if the question is present already. But in other cases the questions present might be unsalvagable, so it would be nice to have a well-written question, with clear use-case and an answer of similar quality. As these "simple" questions tend to come from new users question quality might not always be fit for an answer.

Comment: I like your answer, and think it's concise. I would say that @TinyGiant is right though - if the question is not salvageable but you understand what the OP meant, you can re-write it in it's entirety in place (they are usually short anyway).