# What if they COULD google their question in 5 seconds?

Tags: discussion, comments, welcoming, rude-or-abusive

One example from the revised Code of Conduct of a comment that will now be considered "rude" is "You could google this in 5 seconds."

Indeed, my usual comment for cases like this is the relatively neutral `[I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)`

This raises an interesting question, though: what if they *could* have found the answer in 5 seconds on Google Search? In cases like this, is it wrong to point out the obvious? I've seen plenty of questions where literally copying and pasting their question title into Google Search gives dozens - or even hundreds - of high-quality results. Granted, this comment kind of implies that the OP is being lazy, but really, aren't they?

Put differently: couldn't you argue that *implying* that someone is being lazy isn't as bad as actually *being* lazy?

Comment: But if you imply that they're being lazy, they might be upset that you pointed it out and stop asking lazy questions that could have been easily googled in 5 seconds.

Comment: It's not laziness, just time management. If there is an army of naive drones who can be conned into doing your searching/collating for you, why do it yourself?  There is plenty of other stuff, real stuff that nobody else can be persuaded to do for free, that beeds to  be done instead, (and, if not, the bars are open).

Comment: @MartinJames That's true in some number of cases, but when typing your question into google and looking at the first result gives you a great answer, typing up your question on SO, posting it, and then waiting just 3 minutes for someone to answer is still *way* more work and takes much longer.  Those are even more infuriating then when someone is posting their homework question that would take them 15 minutes and that someone answers in 5, in which it's at least in their own best interest, even if it's bad for the site.

Comment: Related:  [LMGTFY link can't be added](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255397/lmgtfy-link-cant-be-added)

Comment: This question seems to miss the point of what the CoC says by virtue of not seeing the forest for the trees. The important thing is not what you are saying but *how* you say it. There are ways to indicate that you can search for and find the answer to a simple question on Google without being unfriendly or rude.

Comment: That comment is now "rude"? Jesus.

Comment: One nit-picky comment regarding “laziness”. When I was new to programming I didn’t know HOW to communicate about programming and I often barely knew WHY my code wasn’t working. It wasn’t laziness, it was ignorance.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I saw a question today asking what .net reflection is. If they knew the term, why couldn't they look it up themself? Honestly, I suspect that they usually just want someone to spoon feed them the information.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I’m 100% not talking about that one single post. Rather, I’m speaking in regards to the broad generalization that folks who come here with seemingly trivial questions are lazy. I certainly wasn’t, I just didn’t know what I was after. I’m not trying to be difficult, it just resonates with me. Made me want to quit trying to be a part StackOverflow, when I started.

Comment: _"What if they COULD google their question in 5 seconds?"_ - Then google it yourself, and if there is a Stack Overflow answer, close it as a duplicate. Personally, I get more satisfaction from dupe hammering than I do from trying to teach people (to google) who don't want to be taught.

Comment: @TylerH *"There are ways to indicate that you can search for and find the answer to a simple question on Google without being unfriendly or rude."* - but are there? (Without *actually providing an answer*, at least, which people who post these comments seem to want to avoid doing.) I don't see what those ways would look like.

Comment: Maybe has been mentioned but many questions where "google in 5 secs" would have sorted for many SO users, in fact hasn't worked for the OP as they simply lack the required knowledge to implement the solution (however basic it may seem to others). They come to SO looking for someone to write the solution for them and then there is a long draw out set of "explain this" to me questions. P.s. I am feeling moany today.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Then you should buy a beginners programming book (or several) before coming here to wastes people's time.

Comment: @Andy thats ridiculous. What about folks in counties where programming books are forbiddingly expensive? They shouldn’t have the “privilege” of pestering you because they couldn’t afford a book? Also, I had many books and no peers to ask. Books don’t cover everything.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Libraries.  And yes, pestering me is in fact a privilege; its not like annoying me is going to make me help someone.  "Books don’t cover anything"  I started by reading programming books, but you're right, it wasn't until SO appeared that I learned anything at all about programming (even though I was years into my career at that point).

Comment: Also ridiculous not every country has libraries and many libraries don’t have programming books. Look Andy, My only statement was that not everyone new here who crafts a bad question is lazy. You can feel free to argue it all you want. Let’s not waste any more of your utterly valuable time by continuing this discussion Andy.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu: If you have internet access (which we assume is true for people getting questions onto SO), then you have access to a wide variety of free tutorials, which are the electronic equivalent of books.

Comment: Yup, that’s true. But again, tutorials don’t cover even a fraction of the problems a new programmer can run into. Having said that, I’m 100% tapping out of this conversation. I can’t believe how much flack I’m receiving for just stating that we shouldn’t label people as lazy so easily.

Comment: @MarkAmery Yes, there are. There are lots of ways to say most things without being rude, believe it or not.

Comment: Why should any user ever need to go to ANY third-party site outside of SO? Should we start flagging "this question already has an answer at quora.com"? If not, why is a random set of google results any different.

Comment: @TylerH Well, would you like to propose such a way? Nobody has done so here so far, and - as you note yourself in your comment that I first replied to - the entire premise of the question, unchallenged by anyone other than you, is that it is the message and not the tone of the comment that could lead to it being seen as objectionable. If you think it's in fact the tone that the staff are objecting to, then what's wrong with the tone and how would you fix it?

Comment: It's funny how many times I google a problem and the first result is a stackoverflow question where the first comment is something like "google it".

Comment: @ChrisDChris that is annoying but it is not localised to stack overflow or even programming. It happens all the time when I'm looking up automotive stuff I end up on a forum where the only response is "You're not smart enough to understand the answer so we aren't going to answer"... Ok but _I_ am smart enough to understand the answer... or "you should learn how to use google"... this was the first result on google...

Comment: @MarkAmery The CoC draft provides several examples already.

Comment: @TylerH I only see one (*"This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here."*) which doesn't strike me as being equivalent in meaning, since it's actually providing useful extra information about terminology that perhaps the asker otherwise couldn't've trivially Googled - not just rebuking them for posting. Indeed, I wouldn't necessarily read the latter as being critical of the asker at all.

Comment: I have this bookmarked in Chrome for this exact purpose [`site:stackoverflow.com <query here>`](https://www.google.com/search?ei=5nRVW6SRGYj5sAeY04eIAg&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+What+if+they+COULD+google+their+question+in+5+seconds%3F&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+What+if+they+COULD+google+their+question+in+5+seconds).

Comment: What if they could not? The typical "google is your friend" implies that it actually is. Often without the poster actually trying to google it. And possibly assuming the asker knew the additional search terms he is needed to find an useful answer.

Comment: @allo the OP's often do have the search terms - copypasta of their exact title into Google pops up 'About 5,000,000 results', with several SO Q&A on the first page that explain the OP's problem/s and how to fix them:(

Comment: Often they have, sometimes not. My question was "What if they could not?". There are several scenarios where good research seems easy for you, but not to everybody.

Comment: Not everyone gets the same results from a Google search due to bubbling ([discussion](http://guides.library.illinois.edu/c.php?g=348478&p=2347794)).  I suspect (without having done the experiment, admittedly) that long-time SO users with lots of coding questions in their search histories are likely to get more productive results from a Google search than new programmers without that history.  Even if there's not a bubble, my personal experience is that I can tell from the Google-result snippets whether a result is likely to be helpful, and I doubt newbies can do so as quickly.

Comment: @TinyGiant I agree, another example is forum posts that say "Did you google this? [Here's the first result to googling it](https://xkcd.com/979/) (dead link) and it solves your problem."

Comment: @ChrisD I usually flag the "did you google this" comments, they're almost completely useless if the question has been on there for years, especially if the question has high views, a good score, and is the top result on Google. IMO comments like that are not super rude, if anything they're kind of comic relief as I chuckle a bit at how bad people can be at predicting SO's future search rankings. I would probably recommend against leaving those kind of comments, to me it seems like SO's crystal ball isn't working all that well.

Comment: There may be some people who don't have access to Google, but do have access to SO. Specifically, people who are physically in China.

Comment: It takes more than 5 seconds to post a Q on SO. People come looking for help. Tell them it's easy, share the link, don't mock, move on

Comment: @khaverim No one is suggesting mocking anyone. With that said, [don't feed help vampires](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) - it's not helpful to the site in the long run to even share links for questions where the OP could've found the information on their own easily. We're not here to spoon-feed people information that they could've easily found on their own.

Comment: *"Put differently: couldn't you argue that implying that someone is being lazy isn't as bad as actually being lazy?"* - yeah but its the difference between dropping a live landmine and a training one filled with paint. The training one won't kill you when you make a misstep, but your face will still be covered in paint and you look like a clown.

Comment: Also another somewhat related topic on the accuracy of SO's crystal ball, I see a good bit of "what are you trying to accomplish" comments on the more nerdy conceptual questions. When I see this stuff I will reply to you, but let me ask these commenters the same question: "What are **you** (as a commenter) trying to accomplish?" Are you taking a survey? I mean okay sure... I'll provide you a data point if you want... sometimes it really isn't an XY problem, also sometimes the answer is just "people expect the code to be like this because the API we're using is like that".

Comment: @user16320675 not quite sure what you're getting at here. It's most certainly not the opposite, most traffic comes from external search, and external search is better than site search even when looking for something you know is on site.

Comment: Yes, that's fact. When you want someone to do the bare minimum research, google is typically the place you send people to. That's not new.

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that in polite company the phrasing of a comment like "you could google this in 5 seconds" has _always_ been considered varying levels of rude. To suggest it was only now being considered as such is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

### We need to *stop* pontificating.

Without full buy-in to what the scope of the site is, the obvious answer (yeah we don't really want to support those questions) **isn't** going to be the obvious answer.

### We need to be *clear* on the scope of the site.

Are we catering to the Googleable answered questions?  Are we catering to the hard and/or unanswered questions?  Are we catering to the questions which somehow fit in the middle?

No one's officially clarified this yet, so...for now, if you point out the obvious, we're going to get called out for being "impolite".

Then again, there is a way to tell someone that they could just Google this without coming across as a jerk, which may be the finer point being missed.

Comment: That's a good idea.  :-|

Comment: When you say "Googable answered questions" do you mean ones with answers already on SO? If they aren't answered here, they are [definitely in scope](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/262509).

Comment: Re scope and how to word this: My technique has been "Can you please show us the code you have so far?" because 1) these questions almost *never* have an MVCE, 2) adding an MVCE tends to make them look a lot more like real questions, and 3) if they don't show their code, then this is a nice unambiguous close reason that doesn't involve arguments over how much research is "enough research."

Comment: How dare we ask people to not put us to search their questions for them!?

Comment: "Then again, there is a way to tell someone that they could just Google this without coming across as a jerk, which may be the finer point being missed." Please provide a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example of this ;)

Comment: @Hack-R:  I lack the prerequisite credentials on public speaking and interpersonal communications to illustrate this succinctly in a simple Meta post, but what I like to do is pretend I'm talking with a respected family member or a colleague at work.  If I wouldn't say to them what I'm saying to you online, it's not worth typing.  That barometer varies since there are people who routinely hurl abuse between colleagues and family members, so I can't say it applies for everyone.

Comment: @Makoto even with family members and colleagues you adopt a level of security where you can say things more to the point, sometimes going as far as to provide a stern reality check. You don't ever need to go there on Stack Overflow. I've made the comparison in the recent past to just act as if you're doing the introduction round on your first day of work. No matter who you are, you know to be painfully neutral, put up a smile and stay far away from overbearing language and controversial topics as to make the first impression at the very least not a bad one, but hopefully a good one.

Comment: Sorrry to say this but hard questions are nearly all subjective or too broad and will get closed or downvoted. Stack overflow is just not a good fit to ask those kind of questions.

Comment: @Gudradain:  I use a definition of "hard" that is the opposite of "easy".  How to manipulate arrays in Java?  Easy.  The difference between bean and XML injection in Spring?  Hard.  Performing a self-join on a table?  Easy.  Configuring and instrumenting an industry-based application with scant documentation?  Hard.

Comment: @Gudradain:  If you're saying then that Stack Overflow's scope should be to cater to the easier questions - or the questions that are within reach of anyone to actually answer - then you have tragically missed the point of the site.

Comment: I'm saying that Stack Overflow's is not the place for hard questions because you can't ask many of the hard questions in programming. Technical problems are generally easy. The hard parts of programming in how to structure your code, how to structure your data, how to to structure the different system interacting with one another but as far as I have seen those questions are not welcomed here.

Comment: @Gudradain:  Hard problems are not *subjective*.  Subjective questions include things in which there is at least one ambiguous position or opinion on the subject, which includes how one should structure or slice their code.  Hard questions are simply that - they're hard.  The amount of information on the Internet about them is virtually nonexistent or the situation is unlike one you've ever encountered before for any environment.  I've asked [two hard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42635091/1079354) [questions before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599053/1079354) and both were welcomed here.

Comment: @Gudradain:  Maybe it's easier to think of a "hard" question as, "It's a concrete and unambiguous problem for which you don't know the answer, and Google doesn't reveal it either, but there might be a true guru out there that *can* reveal it."

Comment: "concrete and unambiguous" : That's the problem right there. You are attracting only "fix my code" easy technical question as that's the only thing that fit the criteria. Things are not all black and white in programming.

Comment: @Gudradain:  Prove that the two questions I linked to in above comments were "fix my code" questions.

Comment: @Gudradain  'The hard parts of programming in how to structure your code, how to structure your data, how to to structure the different system interacting with one another' yes indeed but 99.9% of all such questions are too broad for an SO Q&A, or are grossly underspecified, or both.  It's not possible to help with most system-level issues on SO.

Comment: @Gudradain [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is the site for whiteboard style design questions, rather than programming questions.  Note that I'm not a regular, so check out their tour and FAQ to see what types of design level questions are and aren't appropriate.

Comment: I would like to add that I have also asked on the topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366247/google-one-liner-questions-with-no-so-answer - the upvoted answer at least seems to imply we should answer if the content does not exist on SO.

Comment: @TinyGiant I hear you are in the cahoots with the poster. BTW, it gained more votes since I accepted the other one, but it does seem you two agree that these should be answered (and the people who voted).

Comment: "what I like to do is pretend I'm talking with a respected family member or a colleague at work" funny that you say that, because usually such response comes from frustration that our expectations aren't fulfilled. For example, there's a direct family member that complained that I dedicate more time to explain tech to them than to itself. Thing is that I know they are capable of figuring out this stuff by themselves, unlike strangers where I have no knowledge of. This site "dedicated" to professionals or enthusiast, such expectation should be taken for granted.

Comment: "Then again, there is a way to tell someone that they could just Google this without coming across as a jerk, which may be the finer point being missed." My current formula is: "Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). I found the linked duplicate by putting `search terms` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=search+terms) | by copying and pasting your question title into a search engine." Of course, this works a lot better when it's true and I actually have dupe-hammered it ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Why...did you necro-comment on this...?  My sentiment was more metaphorical and more to the person aspect of telling someone that their question was simple and not *necessarily* tied to the fact that we had found a dupe and thus had closed it.  [I tend to avoid commenting on questions I close](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413546/1079354) because I ain't moonlighting as a pin cushion.  This was also a much longer time ago in a much more optimistic era.  I don't know what you aimed to achieve by commenting here.

Comment: ...I aimed to share information on the Meta site, in the usual way?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  Not on a Meta answer that is attached to a question with a max of 9k views that doesn't get all that much traffic, surely?  Did you want a new conversation about it or something?

Comment: I followed some links. Don't remember exactly, I don't really keep track of that sort of thing. It seemed like an appropriate response to the answer content. I don't particularly care about the dates on content on Meta, for the same reason that I wouldn't on the main site (except insofar as technical content can become obsolete).

Answer (score 95):

The problem you are putting your attention on is one of the reasons why I almost stopped answering questions on Stack Overflow.

I would love to have an online community of professional programmers. Where professional programmers ask questions and where professional programmers give answers. Stack Overflow is not such a place. For example, I just looked at the first 10 questions under the "PHP" tag, and I found no answerable questions at all. Other tags are not that much better. It was clear to me, that most of the question askers there are certainly not "professional programmers".

So, by catering to the needs of non-programmers who just want to ask questions, you (SO) are losing at least one professional programmer (me), and I am certainly not the only one. I'm waiting for the moment when someone creates a site for software developers that is just like Stack Overflow, but without all the noobs. As soon as that site becomes available, I will leave Stack Overflow and never look back. The only reason I'm still here, is because there is no alternative.

IMHO, we shouldn't be rude to newbies. We should just not allow them on the site and eject them from the site. This could be done in a polite way. But this is not my decision, because I have no authority here. But when I see a comment like "how are we even supposed to help you?" under a question that is totally unanswerable, I will continue to upvote it.

End of rant.

Comment: But... just close those questions. Done.

Comment: Plus, there are no way to know if a question is "unanswerable" without looking at them.

Comment: @user202729: i could. the problem is.. I would like to answer questions. I cannot answer questions because there are almost no good, answerable questions. And this is frustrating, so I leave.

Comment: @user202729: What do you mean by "there are no way to know if a question is "unanswerable" without looking at them" - that's obvious. Do you think I decided that a question is unanswerable, just by looking at it's question ID??

Comment: if just 60% of the questions are bad, I wouldn't care much. But if 99,99% of the questions are bad, that's another story.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If you're saying that "there is no answerable question", that will probably not change if the unanswerable questions are cleared. If you're saying that "the answerable ones are hidden under the unanswerable mess", then... ... yes it's a problem, and the solution is to close/delete the questions faster.

Comment: @Michael - The proportion of good questions seems to be heavily weighted towards certain tags. For example, I spend my SO time almost exclusively on the `f#` tag right now, where there are rather few questions (1-2 per day) but 75-80% of them are good, answerable questions. On the `php` or `javascript` tags, OTOH... it seems like 2% of the questions are good.

Comment: @rmunn: i think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51458371/754705) is very interesting. The title is "Meaning of \ in Haskell identifier", and it has been marked as a duplicate of "Getting started with Haskell". We should close more questions this way ;) Can we have `foreach` programmingLanguage a "Getting started with $programmingLanguage" question? ;)

Comment: Well, when you are asking a question it shows you what it things are similar questions already in SO.   So maybe it could just google your title and put that result up there too?

Comment: I will note that "makes money" and "not a noob" are distinct -- though your point is understood

Comment: @Max: I like to use "duck typing" here. if it looks, acts and talks like a professional programmer, it is a professional programmer ;) . One could argue that this is a superficial way of looking at things, but I think it is reasonable to see it this way. But I agree with your point: there are definitively excellent coders who didn't work professionally yet. and there are definitively professional coders who don't know how to program. including the first group but excluding the second group would be a good second approximation. (the first approx. was "only allow professional coders")

Comment: @Max: but practically speaking, the "second approximation" is easier to test anyways

Comment: I would be happy if they at least were hobbyist, where they at least have a real drive to read manuals, read answers and read their code.

Comment: I (140k rep) have essentially stopped answering because there are no answerable C# questions anymore. Many questions are possible but frustrating to answer. Too many noobs is a good point. They don't cooperate in being helped.

Comment: A professional programmer can still be brand new to a particular language, and ask questions for that language that sound pretty "noob".

Comment: So folks who have never been to college and are trying to better themselves by learning how to program are not allowed here? Harsh. (the efforts around making sure new users learn how to ask good questions are the right direction IMHO)

Comment: @AndrewGrothe: no. I said I would appreciate a site for professional programmers. do you know that there are forums for medical doctors? these forums would be totally useless if everyone were allowed and you got 10000 questions about migraine every day. do you think it is harsh that these forums exclude non-MDs like us?

Comment: I appreciate that analogy, but there are medical institutions and government agencies that concern themselves with licensing doctors. Are you thinking of a SO-like site that has an entrance exam? Accreditation validation? A site like that would likely require a subscription. That would certainly keep the user count low!

Comment: Personally I'm alright with attempting to answer non-professional level questions, but I respect that you aren't and I hope that you can find the site you're looking for (if this doesn't end up being it). I sympathize because SO hasn't exactly been consistent about what it really wanted to make here and the friction and waste that causes is... unfortunate.

Comment: If you want to keep the noobs out, what kind of barriers would you like to have in place? E.g., initial tests involving complex Perl one-liners with regular expressions?

Comment: If this kind of elitest attitude takes over SO, this site will die quickly. And any site that is actually like what you describe would be very lucky to survive very long. There are so many examples of this on the internet, it's absurd.

Comment: @ouflak It is exactly that "elitist" attitude that led to SO becoming popular, so yeah... good luck with your strawman.

Comment: @IanKemp: exactly. I had become tired of arguing. Furthermore, this kind of "elitist" attitude is exactly how offline communities work by default. Universities are not overrun by people who failed at high school. When I meet former co-workers, they don't bring noob programmers to the meeting who repeatedly ask questions about NullPointerExceptions. - An online community on the other hand is non-elitist by default. And letting everyone in is much easier than doing some kind of filtering. Most online communities are non-elitist. Still noobs prefer stack overflow over quora.

Comment: @IanKemp, then tell the staff at StackExchange to stop posting all of the strawmen 'welcome' topics and 'be-nice' topics and trying to update their Code of Conduct. There isn't a problem here and these postings are just distractions. Since the site is only meant for seasoned programmers who ask clear concise questions, we should be chasing off anybody who doesn't make the cut. That way the site will grow, prosper, and be very profitable.

Comment: "be nice" is good. being unfriendly doesn't help, because the noobs have no better place to come to, no matter how unfriendly, racist, sexist and whatever we may be. if we are unfriendly to noobs it will not make them disappear anyways. It's like free beer: people take it, no matter how unfriendly you are. @ouflak: you seem to miss the point that there are plenty of online communities which have failed exactly because they were not elitist enough. SO somehow solved this problem, at least partially.

Comment: @ouflak Sadly the staff of Stack Exchange have been tasked with making money from the site, which is orthogonal to keeping it high quality. The people like me who care about quality have a problem with that, and we're fighting against it because it's the right thing to do, not necessarily because we believe we'll win.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe as a man who learned in my 25 years at work more than in my 5 years in college, I resent your question. This is a false dichotomy in its purest form. Yes, we ask for certain level of background knowledge in the technology the question is posted about. No, we do not require that the knowledge comes from college.

Comment: @AndrewGrothe Moreover, there really is no college course that will teach what exactly is a meaning of "variable" in Java vs. how it's different from the meaning of "variable" in C++. There may be a course **during** which the student needs to have this epiphany, but it's never explicitly explained. In fact, the relationship is opposite.The people who grasp technology end up studying it in college, not the people who study in college end up grasping the technology.And until you've got that basic grasp of what is e.g. pointer,reference,variable,array-there is very little that SO can do for you.

Comment: @Michael - My take is that SO doesn't seek to be a professional space oriented around **programmers** but strives to be a public space oriented around **programming**.

Comment: @IanKemp SO became popular because of its stringent _format_ (community moderated, accepted answer is controlled by the asker only, up/down votes, comments are for clarification and not 'thank you' or '+1', etc.), not the quality or "depth" of its questions. There are countless (often now-deleted) examples of questions from 2008 and 2009 that serve as reminders of the low quality of questions asked back in those days. Oh, and it helped quite a bit that the two founders were rather famous programmer advocates who already had followings to import into the environment, so to speak, at launch.

Comment: @Michael FWIW you can always find some like-minded individuals and propose a new site on Area 51 for _professional_ programmers only. Given how SO staff has said that Stack Overflow is exceptional in that it doesn't get to determine its own fate like every other SE site does, a separate site may be the best bet.

Answer (score 78):

Great question... (and thanks to @Makoto for clarifying [which clarification we need](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371350/8112776)!)

---

*...`is it wrong to point out the obvious?`*
*...`if they could have found the answer in 5 seconds on Google?`*

IMO it's not wrong as long as it's done politely, and in fact is an important part of the learning process.

What if your high school teachers were never allowed to tell you to put some effort into finding a solution on your own.  I'm not suggesting that anyone be as rude as *my* high school teachers were, but a key part of learning is *learning how to learn*... (Think *"[Give a man a fish...](https://quoteinvestigator.com/fish/)")*

### What's obvious to you is not obvious to everyone.

I think that in most cases, the OP did not post a Google-able question on SO simply because they wanted to create extra work for others.  I think that most would much prefer to have the 5-second answer that Google (or SO Search) often can provide... if they knew how to ask for it.

### 'Effective Searching' is a learned skill.

I'd like to see a wiki like a *"Programmers Guide to Google Searches"* to which we could (politely) direct users, not unlike how we currently use `[ask]` or `[help/on-topic]`.  The fact is, Google *does* have answers to almost anything, but some [tips](https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/insidesearch/tipstricks/all.html) and [tricks](https://libguides.lmu.edu/GoogleSearching) aren't obvious. There's even an [**Advanced Googling Course**](http://www.powersearchingwithgoogle.com/) straight from the source!

---

### Bigger fish.

I don't consider it any more "rude" to provide an example Google search than the "Duplicate Question" notice:

> **This question already has an answer here:** *(duh!)*
>    . . .
>   **This has been marked as duplicate by these 5 people.** *(what's wrong with you?!)*

---

## *Edit:*

This question got me reflecting on times I've recommended Google.

Written communication doesn't always carry the intended sentiment, and when combined with our states of 'HALT' (Hungry/Angry/Lonely/Tired), we can make mistakes.

So I'll <del>give</del> *point* the finger at myself and share three varying times, I've recommended a Google - at least one of which is pretty ugly in retrospect.  (Query yours [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/877181/google-mentions-in-a-users-comments).)

---

## <sub><sub><sub>[image: good]</sub></sub></sub> GOOD

> ### <sup>Q: Scan attached files in a new e-mail</sup>
>
> > *I am currently trying to learn VBA for Outlook ... Could you please show me the path to do the following ...*
> >
> > [image: good example]

Several relevant links shared by multiple users in a polite manner, with an OP inviting different solutions - even without an answer, this to me, is the "gold" that can make SO such a valuable resource...  I learned something even while in the process of helping another.  *"Win-win!"*

---

## <sub><sub><sub>[image: bad]</sub></sub></sub> BAD

> ### <sup>Q: RDLC Indian Currency to Words Conversion</sup>
>
> > *I used above code to get the result, the one that I'm looking for is like ... Is there any way to get the required result, help me out of this?*
> >
> > [image: bad example]

...ouch - looking back, not only was I an absolutely condescending ass, but while lecturing about grammar and Google, I didn't both to check *my own* spelling or grammar.  Terrible.

---

## <sub><sub><sub>[image: ugly]</sub></sub></sub> UGLY

> ### <sup>Q: How to hide connection string in app config from user</sup>
>
> > *All my grids and combo boxes bound to dataset/adapter which the connection string ... I tried ... but my app returned an exception.*
> >
> > [image: ugly example]

..."ugly" in that it was a back-and-forth involving multiple users, although thankfully it turned out well everyone involved managed to see each other's points of view by the end, the post eventually resulted in thanks-all-around and the OP self-answering.

Comment: You allude to this at the beginning, and I think it is key: finding what you don't know  you don't know is harder than just finding the thing that you don't know. There's no debate that the volume of lazy and bad questions is too high, but this is also a global site with people of all tounges trying to solve problems, and trying to translate their native 'technicalese' into English 'technicalese.' I recall having to work through German Active Directory manuals ~20 years ago, when I was just learning German; ugh. The short is that "just Google it" is not a magic pill that weeds out the lazy.

Comment: Plus one for The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly reference. I love Tuco.

Comment: Every day I'm on the site I come across questions where I can (and do) copy paste the title of the question into google, and the first result is the answer to their question.  Yes, there are cases where someone clearly couldn't have found the answer to their question on their own, even when it's out there.  Those questions are manageable.  It's all the ones that very demonstrably didn't even try that aren't.

Comment: @Servy - agreed.  Wouldn't it be handy if the new SO [Question Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369682/ask-a-question-wizard-prototype) included *exactly that feature* for the OP -- especially *new* OP's: **a list of the first 2 or 3 Google Search results** (easily obtained with the [Google Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview)), in the same way that the interface *already* shows similar existing SO questions?  That would make a big dent in this issue, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @ashleedawg I find it unlikely.  People that can't be bothered to even search for their question on Google aren't even going to look at the results in a situation like that.  Often enough *the top recommended question* answers their question well.  Clearly people don't let that stop them.

Comment: “as long as its done politely” — politeness is a relative concept that I don’t think should be a focus of the user community. Sure, our interactions may be more affective when applying some manners and respect, but shouldn’t that be up to the end user on how they choose to communicate? Before you know it some admin is going to start banning people for being impolite and I don’t think we should argue that an abuse of power does occur from time to time.  Let’s permit humanity to endure and allow people to address others how they feel is fitting.

Comment: Why is someone who's self-proclaimed to never even have used vb.net allowed to attempt answering a vb.net question? I'm annoyed when users unfamiliar with a topic claim the question "is too vague" or "trivial to answer by Googling". These commenters lack the context that comes from having attempted to use that particular technology.

Comment: @vol7ron - "as long as its done politely" - meaning: every user should self-moderate, being aware that it's civility/politeness ***matters***... I didn't imply that it's up to any one person to judge others. If a particular post or set of posts is cause for concern and potentially requires deletion, only a majority-vote *of an appropriate sample size* can be fairly used to make a final decision.

Comment: I think the "sample size" needs to be considered carefully because, for example, IMO, the number of **votes required to close a post** should vary depending on how many users there are overall, and how many are active in that tag/topic/area. In the early days of SO, any one person with 3000 rep could close a question. When SO reached 25k users, Atwood hesitantly implemented 3-vote close/re-open vote minimum.  When SO hit 65k rep it was deemed necessary to increase to 5 votes.  Now, SO has about 145 times that many users - maybe time to increase number of req'd votes to close...

Comment: Perhaps. I’m just worried that the sensitivities to speech and word choice has been causing harm when it comes to freedom of expression. The message sent is people don’t have the freedom to be who they want to be. To my knowledge it’s much easier for a select few admins to revoke something than the other way around. It’s easier to close a question than re-open it, even after corrections are made. So I’m sensitive when people start arguing for social order in a community run forum. As I understand it, you’re advocating for standard social rules, which I don’t disagree with.

Comment: @AlexR - That's likely a common POV from any user who gets a "Too Vague" VTC.  Obviously, nobody *intentionally* posts "too little information."  All we can hope is that those users are at least willing to take suggestions where offered. Coding knowledge is not a linear object, contrary to some attitudes (like *"if you don't know X, you definitely don't know Y"*, lol) Not everyone in a community of 10 million will have the knowledge/behaviour that others "expect" but with the right attitude plus a willingness to learn & take suggestions, benefit can be maximized for everyone.

Comment: It's amazing what both an *"asker and answerer"* can learn from a properly structured Google Search - even if one or both has little existing knowledge of the platform. (Everyone starts somewhere.)  For example, my experience has been in varying forms of VB since long before the "V" was attached to it, but have hardly even ***seen*** C#, yet some of my highest-scoring answers are in C#. Yet another way that one can benefit from answering, as much or more than by asking.  Pretty amazing how that works, and how like-minded, generally *good people* the vast majority of this site's members are..

Comment: 'Obviously, nobody intentionally posts "too little information' - they do, every Sunday, to try and obscure their low/no effort homework questions.

Comment: @MartinJames - You've got me there....  Interesting that you mention Sundays... it was only a theory of mine until you just confirmed.

Comment: AND is correct in numbers like that outside the US, and it is also used in the US.

Answer (score 27):

> I certainly defer to the others here who are active participants -- but our general philosophy is to heavily favor answerers.
>
> We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. *Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers.*
>
> If this means aggressively closing unworthy or uninteresting questions, so be it. **Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?**

https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/595/41104

Comment: OP should have googled better their question :P

Comment: This has been proven a lie again and again. At best, this is obsolete. The current management at SO heavily favors askers (because askers make the most noise), then searchers (because they make the most traffic), **then** answerers. When they talk about "unwelcoming" comments, they do not mean "unwelcoming to answerers", do they?

Comment: @Arkadiy funny that you say that, because askers is the thing I less see on meta. Now twitter...

Comment: Yep - this just confirms my "most noise" hypothesis. Twitter is a more public forum, is it not?

Comment: @Arkadiy Just to be clear, you're asserting that it's no longer the case that SO as a company believes this quote to be true, not that the statement itself isn't actually true, right?  Or are you asserting both things?

Comment: @Servy, You are correct. I am asserting that at some point the company acted according to the statement in question, but it has not been the case for a very long time. I also personally think that the statement is correct, whether SO currently supports it or not. But I am an answerer myself, so I am biased. All I ask is that people should stop bringing this quote up. It's no longer relevant to how SO does things.

Comment: @Arkadiy well, if the company doesn't favor answerers... what are we doing here?

Comment: @Braiam Trying to do a good deed in an increasingly unwelcoming environment.

Comment: @Arkadiy ha! I see what you did there.

Answer (score 25):

> Put differently: couldn't you argue that implying that someone is being lazy isn't as bad as actually being lazy?

Debatable, but not relevant.  It is not up to us to point out other people's personal flaws.

My advice:

- If you think a Question is lazy, skip it.  Move on.  Spend your time on Questions that you think are worth your time.
- If you think a Question is egregiously lazy, downvote it.  No comment.  Then move on.

A comment on another answer:

> In that case, there's an obvious solution: CV as dupe. Why even bother to comment?

Or ... don't even bother.  Frankly if a question is egregiously lazy, then the OP doesn't even deserve the help of a dup closure ... which entails me making an effort to find an appropriate dup question for them.  (IMO)

---

> What if they could have found the answer in 5 seconds on Google Search?

Maybe *they* couldn't ... due to poor language skills, or not knowing the correct (IT) terms, or not understanding how to get Google to give relevant search results.

And maybe they did find it, but they did not *understand* it.

We cannot tell.  Best approach is to leave the topic of laziness out of any comms with the OP.

---

We can't solve the problem of the flood of poor quality questions.  Leave it to SE management to come up with something that is practical.

Comment: Sorry but as someone who cares about the quality of content on Stack Overflow, I just cannot agree with the *“move on and spend your time on better questions”* mentality. If I don’t do something about the question the moment I find it, chances are pretty high that someone will come around and just answer it, feeding the lazy behavior of the asker. – So yes, I am kind of required to spend a bit of time to find a duplicate and get the question closed quickly…

Comment: Being lazy is a personal flaw, but I don't agree that is shouldn't be pointed out when it becomes a problem for other people. When you see someone leaving garbage on a street, do you skip it and move on, do you pick it up, or do you tell them to pick it up?

Comment: `Maybe they couldn't ... due to (...)` - or maybe they're in China?

Comment: "If you think a Question is lazy, skip it. Move on. Spend your time on Questions that you think are worth your time"  And then stop answering questions on SO at all, because its just not worth the effort to find decent questions.  I'm sure that will really help with the quality here.

Comment: High-probability homework questions from low-rep users (Fibonacci sequence, Sieve of Eratosthenes, any SQL query against tables name Employee, Customer, or Student, etc) should IMO be CV'd with "Off Topic > Questions seeking debugging help...". Or you can just refer them to geeksprogramming who apparently are selling programming-for-cheaters services over the Web. Free enterprise at work. I wonder how much they charge..? (Of course, at a company-wide level it's not "cheating" - it's "out-sourcing"! Big difference! **BIG** difference!!!)

Comment: If "we cannot tell", then we cannot help them.  Requiring questions to state what has already been tried, what resources they found, what errors they got, is not just rules for the sake of rules.  Those things actually are the bare minimum to get answers which the OP can understand, otherwise they're right back in the situation of "they found the answer but do not understand", meaning they are no better off for asking and the time of everyone involved has been wasted.

Comment: Of course we can help them.  Given enough time and patience you could help them understand with a new answer to a new question.  Whether you will actually help them cannot be predicted.  Whether >>you<< should try is up to you.

Comment: But really the point about not being able to tell if people are genuine ... or lazy ... is not about whether we should help them.  This is about whether or not we should tell them they are lazy!

Comment: *"And then stop answering questions on SO at all, because its just not worth the effort to find decent questions. I'm sure that will really help with the quality here."* -  1) I am starting to come to that conclusion myself. 2) I some back to the point that I made on another answer: it is not our responsibility to fix the quality issue ... and we can't.

Comment: @BobJarvis *sigh*... that reason only applies to questions asking for debugging help. How-to style questions are not inherently off-topic, and do not explicitly require code. They just need to be on-topic, reasonably scoped, and well defined. They may or may not be made clearer or more reasonably scoped by the presence of code or prior research, but such is not explicitly required of such questions. The important message to get across to users asking overly broad how-to questions is that they need to break their problem up into it's component parts, then attempt to solve each individually. ...

Comment: A question asking how to implement one of the component parts of a task may be reasonably scoped whereas a solution to the entire problem may not. Or, the solution to the entire problem may be reasonably scoped if the problem itself is not too complex. It's really subjective and not nearly as clear cut as these blanket statement comments with such content as _'High-probability homework questions from low-rep users ... should IMO be CV'd with "Off Topic > Questions seeking debugging help..."_ make it out to be.

Comment: @BenVoigt Stating what was tried or what research has been done has never been a requirement. It's a nice thing to see, but it is not and has never been a requirement. Some users falsely tout it as such and help confuse matters further, but there is no such requirement. In fact, there is a ban on comments whose only content is "What have you tried?" as well as comments that start with that are immediately destroyed on the first flag.

Comment: @hanshenrik re: "maybe they're in China?" You can use [Let Me Baidu That For You](https://lmbtfy.cn/)

Comment: _[...] It is not up to us to point out other people's personal flaws_ **Yes, yes is!** That's the only way to make help those people become less terrible! How people cannot see that it beyond me. If someone tells me _"Man, You are too fat. You have to do something about that"_ I receive this as an wake-up signal to try harder and get better. **It's never offensive if it's true and You can fix that**

Comment: @TinyGiant: "Lacks research" is the mouseover text for the downvote button.  Thus neglecting to perform and describe research doesn't lead to question closure, but to deletion and revocation of asking privileges from the account. 
 "What have you tried?" is not banned because it misinterprets the site rules, but because it doesn't provide the OP with understanding of what sort of previous effort they are supposed to describe and how it helps them get a better answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt questions must be closed to be deleted. The rest of your argument completely falls apart after that. "What have you tried?" Is banned because it is irrelevant and useless, just as most often the irrelevant or useless "attempt" that the OP might include after relentless pestering from users who don't understand the scope of Stack Overflow

Comment: @TinyGiant: Questions count toward bans based on votes, not based on closure or being deleted.  And it isn't true that questions have to be closed before deletion -- you can't cast a delete vote on an open question but the roomba doesn't care.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I don't know about you, but I find the best questions come from people who have already tried helping themselves, and are asking about how the bigger picture that the reference documentation doesn't cover -- how to combine functions, interactions between function preconditions and language rules, and so forth.  For these things, good answers go beyond stating a simple fact and explain why, alternate designs, tradeoffs, and so forth.  These are useful and interesting.  Regurgitating official documentation is no more fun than pointing out typos.

Comment: "Leave it to SE management to come up with something that is practical." AHAHAHAHAHA. Oh, my sides!

Comment: **Please** don't use "the question is lazy" as an excuse *not to close a duplicate*. Leaving duplicates unmarked makes **the entire site** worse.

Answer (score 24):

There is a simple course of action to take when a question can easily be googled.

## Does googling bring up a good response *On Stack Overflow*?

### Yes:

Close as duplicate. If it was really easy to find the dup, *and you are in a teaching mood*, you can politely show them how they could have found their answer faster by using a search engine.

### No:

Upvote<sup>1</sup>. As per [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/262509), these questions are allowed and are helpful. We don't have a "duplicate of offical documentation" close option for a reason.

---

What isn't needed is rudeness designed at highlighting their inability to use search as a tool effectively. That is a waste of your time, hurts their feelings, and slanders the reputation of everyone on SO.

Just because you resent incompetent users does not give you the right to ruin our good name by bullying them.

<sup>1. Except when other factors fail (i.e. clarity of writing).</sup>

Comment: "*What isn't needed is rudeness*" but isn't it arguably rude to ask a lazy question that wastes everyone's time as it was easy to search for the answer? "*and slanders the reputation of everyone on SO*" and poor questions that help no-one else that *are* googleable and duped many times *also* slanders the reputation of the site by filling it with low quality content.

Comment: @James Two wrongs don't make a right. And I think half the problem is you mistake a lack of knowledge and ability for laziness, hence the resentment. Everyone on this post thinks they are mocking people who are lazy and want others to do the work, when they are actually often mocking users who are confused and unable. It really is saddening. And I'm not saying bad content shouldn't be closed and downvoted. All I'm saying is that everyone would do better if people did so while controlling their attitudes.

Comment: Hmm, I know the difference between lack of knowledge and someone who has no care to even try to search. This is confirmed when I suggest things like viewing their error log file (teach a man to fish etc) and they either reply with nothing at all for hours until someone answers and suddenly they burst into life, or they respond with a less harsh "STFU if you don't want to answer". I'm not talking about those who are not lazy, I'm talking about those who are, so I think you're defending a ghost here.

Comment: @James You are now talking about people who are rude, abusive, and unwilling to be helped. That is a different discussion. Even then, being rude back achieves nothing. Downvote, flag, why waste time writing a response back that will only inflame them even further.

Comment: No I'm talking about "lazy" as per my first comment. They are lazy because they don't want to engage in comments to figure it out themselves, they are lazy because they don't go look at their error logs. Lack of knowledge would be they did not know about the existence of PHP error logs so say "hey thanks for the advice, where do I find those amazing-sounding error logs".

Comment: Assuming you can identify this kind of user before even commenting, why bother commenting? I still don't see how this justifies rudeness. If you know they are bad, you aren't going to teach them anything by leaving a rude remark. Just leave a downvote for the bad question and move on.

Comment: There are two paths here:
*One:* They lack knowladge/ability to find an effective solution in an existing post. In this case politely teaching them how to help themselves will work.
*Two:* They are a lazy rude unteachable user like you talk about. Pretty much nothing can be gained by commenting. Why bother? --- Bottom line is that anyone who deserves rudeness doesn't deserve a response at all. Responding will only help to make you (and the rest of the power users) look more like them.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here. you keep changing what you are discussing and putting words in my mouth. I merely commented on something you said in your answer and your first response was "two wrongs don't make a right". That's like not sending people to prison for the same logic

Comment: @James I made the erroneous assumption your original comment had purpose beyond stating the obvious. Obviously users who are genuinely low effort posters are rude and destructive to this site. So what? We have lots of ways to get rid of them. Auto bans, downvotes, close votes. Nobody is asking to take those away. Nobody every doubted that. The point of my comments and my posts was that responding to these users rudely is not a good idea. The point of the "be welcoming" initiative is to attack the kind of rudeness we don't have a mechanism for fighting. The rudeness that comes from curators.

Comment: In your answer you put "*What isn't needed is rudeness*" then your last comment to me was "*I made the erroneous assumption your original comment had purpose beyond stating the obvious*". Irony? Kinda breaks down any legibility in your answer when you state people shouldn't be rude then are rude to them when they discuss your answer. Also, I don't post cryptic messages that I expect other people to figure out to know what I meant, so sure if you want to label "to the point and understandable" as "obvious".

Comment: @James Sorry - no rudeness intended - that came out a lot blunter than I would have liked. What I meant by my remark is that you pointed out something that my answer did not call into question, and is generally not doubted (or put shortly: obvious).

Comment: No worries man, I think we're all on edge at the moment with some of the changes, and what they mean etc

Comment: You appear to have the upvote tooltips reversed if you think that poorly researched questions are supposed to be *upvoted*.  The description is *very explicit* about it being the exact opposite.

Comment: The incorrect premise of the question, and many of the answers here, is that easy to Google answers are off topic on SE. This is wrong; I beleive it has never been the case. As you say, in the case of a duplicate, vote to close as a duplicate. And, I would add, downvote if the duplicate us not a useful duplicate. If there is an answer elsewhere, that does not preclude an answer *here*.

Comment: @Raedwald I did a bunch of research regarding this yesterday and it seems like that FAQ post does not line up with any of the existing policy. Seems to me like its generally understood (but never explicitly said anywhere) that simply googled posts aren't covered. Of course this is not consistently enforced. It would probably help if the policy on this was *clearly* stated somewhere.

Comment: @James "but isn't it arguably rude to ask a lazy question that wastes everyone's time as it was easy to search for the answer?" If the question meets the site mandate and is not a duplicate, then adding it to the site is **inherently not a waste of time**. Many of the site's most important and valuable questions concern topics that an experiences programmer would find trivial. Neophytes will always outnumber experts, in every field, by huge margins.

Answer (score 14):

What if they *did* google their question in 5 seconds? Or, more to the point, **what if Stack Overflow googled it for them** and presented the top n (n in (2..5)) Google results along with the SO results? Maybe something like

```
Stack Overflow result 1              +-----------------+
SO result 2                          | Google result 1 |
SO result 3                          | Google result 2 |
etc                                  | Google result 3 |
                                     +-----------------+
```

or

```
SO result 1
          2
          3
          4
          5

Google result 1
              2
              3
```

Comment: As noted, this already happens with the automatic search that happens when asking a question - it doesn't seem to deter this sort of user. Those capable of looking at search results aren't the ones that are causing this problem. Generally, these sort of questions aren't really googleable to start with, because the title is "i dont know why this doesn't work" and the body is an unformatted dump of their code.

Comment: @Knetic: **WELL! CLEARLY** Google has some work to do in the critical areas of homework identification and garbage code detection! **HUMPH!!** :-) On a more serious note - I read a post lately which pointed out that SO has become The Place on the internet to crowdsource debugging. And I must admit that I'm at least partly to blame for this. *<sigh>* What to do, what to do..?

Comment: SO cannot automatically use google without paying huge fees. Automatic research is limited to 400 per day as I heard.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - to paraphrase Dickens: Is there no Dogpile? Is there no Yahoo? Is there no Duck Duck Go? (I'm somewhat disappointed in myself that I can't quickly figure out how to incorporate, "...they had better do it, and decrease the surplus population" here - but I'll work on it, I'll work on it... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis +1 for DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 13):

There are a number of possible scenarios where someone is asking a question where finding a solution elsewhere is trivial, and in my opinion a suitable response depends on which scenario it is.

1. **The answer is already on SO.**

   Obviously, mark as a dupe, and link to the other question
2. **The question can be pasted as-is into Google, and return a high quality result from a reputable source.**

   How about a comment saying something along the lines of "the documentation for {whatever it is} answers this quite well see here {link}", or whatever the best source is.
3. **The question can be Googled, but needs re-phrasing.**

   Give the user polite tips on how to find what they are looking for in google, such as keywords which are not included in their question.
4. **The question can be Googled, but does not yield any sources which stand out above the rest.**

   e.g. There are some blogs and tutorials that answer it, but none by an obviously reputable source, or there is an answer in the documentation, but it is written in a way that is not accessible, or it can be answered by drawing together points from several sources.

   If this is the case, and the question is in scope and well written, I would say that it is a perfectly good question, where an answer would be helpful. Leave it be, or answer, as pleases you.

**You know it is one of these, but don't think it is worth your time to work out which, because you think it's a lazy question**

Doing nothing, or just down voting, wastes the least amount of your time.

Comment: #2 is a wordy way to say RTFM / "RTFM" is a nerdy way to say "the documentation for {whatever it is} answers this quite well see here {link}". #3 - SO is not a "how to use Google" site (or is there now, or should there be, a googletips.stackexchange.com site?).

Comment: #2 Is a perfectly valid question, [as per the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers). Upvote and answer. The fact that a high quality source exists is irrelevant. We don't have a "duplicate of official documentation" close option for a reason.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms You appear to be under the impression that upvote are for "poorly researched questions", and that downvotes are for...what, exactly?  Anyway, that's very demonstrably wrong.  Downvotes *exist* to indicate that a question is poorly researched.  Upvotes exist to indicate that a question is well researched.  The fact that a high quality, accessible answer exists for the question is not only not irrelevant, it's *extremely* relevant.  The site doesn't exist to plagiarize documentation.  It exists to *actually improve* the information available to programmers, not to duplicate it.

Comment: @Servy That post that is part of the official FAQ seems to disagree with you. Also, just because a good source answers a question, does not mean that there are not other (possibly better) ways to answer that question. SE allows all the answers from a wide ranger of people, as well as a method to rank them. Pretty much all other sources don't. I agree we don't exists to plagiarize documentation, however I have seem it helpfully summarized and quoted in many instances - which is the beauty of SO.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms The FAQ doesn't say that research isn't important, or that you're supposed to upvote poorly researched questions.  It says that you shouldn't be posting answers or comments that just link to LMGTFY.  That doesn't mean that poorly researched questions should be upvoted.  It also doesn't claim, as you are, that the purpose of the site is to duplicate, without any added value whatsoever (which, for the record, is called plagiarism, so you *are* advocating it) all official documentation.

Comment: @Servy Whilte it is specifically talking about lgmtfy - but the rest of the post goes on to indirectly encourage easily googled questions (like "What is a variable?"). The justification being that they will be best answered on SO, no matter how many excellent easily found via google sources also answer them. Stack overflow is for all questions, even if other sites already answer them.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Yes, one person advocated that in the question, and isn't even given as the answer.  That's of course contrary to the help center, stating that questions are expected to be well researched, and number of other meta questions stating the same.  SO is not for all questions.  It's for clear, reasonably scoped, objective, **well researched**, questions about specific types of programming related topics.  It's a site designed to have *quality* questions with *quality* answers.  Not a place for people to regurgitate documentation because people didn't bother to do their research.

Comment: @Servy I am still detecting contradiction here. I am going to look into what *exactly* "well researched" means as a question criteria.

Answer (score 13):

My advice: put up or shut up. If the question really is googleable "in 5 seconds", then demonstrate that fact by linking to an easily-googled page where the result can be found. Ideally, quote the answer inline in your comment. Under your own premises, it'll only take you 5 seconds to find such a quote, after all.

If you're not willing to take the extra 5 seconds to do that, then I'd suggest not commenting at all - if only because, in my experience as a question asker and a reader, commenters who complain that something is trivially googled without citing specifically where the answer can be found are wrong more often that they are right. If the complaint comes with a link and a quote, that either definitively proves that the answer *was* already easily findable, or allows the question asker to argue (by pointing out how the quote doesn't actually answer the question, if it doesn't). Vaguely indicating that Google could provide an answer without pointing to anywhere in particular does neither of these things; it's an *unsubstantiated* criticism, just as easy to state when it's true as when it's completely false. That's pretty much never constructive, and I would generally flag such comments on sight.

Comment: @Jeremy How so? It seems to me that the approach I'm advocating - in the case where the answer really is trivially Googleable - has precisely the opposite of all the effects you're claiming it has: it adds page-rank to the already-easily-Googleable source by linking to it, encourages downvoting and closure by demonstrating to other readers that the question is trivially Googleable, and demonstrates to the asker that they could've Googled, encouraging them to do that in future.

Comment: @Jeremy Hmm; I just checked some old comments of mine, and yeah, you appear to be right about that. My other two points stand, though: the incentive for bad askers to "pollute the site with their excrement" seems to be lower if people take my approach.

Comment: This. Often I see "this can be googled" or the like, only to find that it is not as easily googled as the commenter suggests. If it is so easily googleable, you should be able to link to the relevant result and the Google query you used to find the result.

Comment: It is not up to me to google stuff for people. I am not an human English parser. On top of it, I am here to teach, not to do help desk.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro If you're not going to even Google the problem before commenting, how can you possibly *know* that it's trivial to Google?

Comment: @pnuts A good point. No need to even look at other tags than mine to make the comparison, either; T.J.'s got *[11000](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157247+[javascript])* answers to my 44. I don't think it changes my conclusion - I still think unsubstantiated claims that an answer is trivially Googleable are frequently wrong and rarely serve a purpose, and that the site would be better off if such comments were just never made - but I *do* see how asking for a greater investment of effort per question is far more of a burden for someone who touches 100x more questions than I do.

Comment: @MarkAmery There are good questions, there are bad questions, and there are very trivial questions. On top of the very trivial questions anyone that hang outs frequently sees quickly that a good percentage of the bad questions appears over and over. It is a question of common sense. Actually, many bad questions are a question of a lack of common sense. If you see my top points, they are of a technical group, anyone experienced on the field knows very well what is trivial to know and find. But that is even besides the point. Many questions are not worthy an investment on time.

Answer (score 7):

> “You could Google this in 5 seconds.”

Maybe you could google it in 5 seconds, but perhaps they lack the expertise to discern the most relevant search results in that short period of time. Therefore the whole "5 seconds" part is extraneous and, while not necessarily rude, it does reveal a little frustration and (perhaps) condescension. If you want to convey the fact that it would be quick, then just say exactly that: "a quick search".

Here's the official Friendly version:

> "This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in a comment here."

The official Friendly version is not great either. Here we are still promoting a specific search engine, which may not even be accessible in that user's country. And does StackOverflow really need to be in the business of promoting one search engine over another?

Another problem is that this is far wordier than the original. If we want to help everyone use their time efficiently, then how does that make sense? Wordier does not equal friendly / better; A programmer should value some degree of precision rather than beating around the bush.

So, here's my proposed Friendly version:

> "FYI, an internet search for (Insert Keyword here) turns up a lot of good tutorials"

Here the formulation is less aggressive, but equally concise: you are just providing additional information. What they choose to do with that information-- and whether or not they feel foolish in retrospect-- is of course, up to them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question, but it does raise two points that also bugged me: advertising a specific search engine, and being overly wordy. I feel this would be useful on the [Meta Stack Exchange request for feedback on the new CoC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312850/168333).

Comment: Sure, you can try to use google in a generic sense, lots of people do, but it is still a clear reference to the Google search engine. Likewise if I say to bing something, then I am promoting through my language the use of Miscrosoft's product. @pnuts

Answer (score 6):

I think the MAIN problem with this question is the false dichotomy.

Sometimes it is appropriate to redirect to google. Sometimes it isn't. Sometimes it's both at the same time. Sometimes the user wouldn't exactly know how to search for this productively on google, hence their search isn't as good as a knowledgeable user's search. Sometimes they're not looking for 'examples', they're looking for understanding by someone who can explain it. And sometimes they're just lazy (which I find an odd conclusion, since posting a question takes more effort).

Just to be cheeky, what do people think about the [OP's question here as an example that should have been googled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50120515/4183191)? If you agree that my snarky comment below his question about "google gives [the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem) in 5 seconds" is inappropriate, then I would agree with you. However, you would also agree that they didn't demonstrate they 'googled' effectively in their question. Was such 'google evidence' necessary? Probably not.

Also, to compound the issue, I freely admit I haven't even read their question; it was just a knee-jerk have you googled it response because there didn't seem much evidence of "I googled this" in it at a glance. I think this is also something that happens, which when you re-read the question it is quite reasonable that a question was asked rather than 'googled'.

**UPDATE:** my comment on that post has now been deleted. This is either an automated script by SO, or OP felt it was unfair and unwelcoming. I well let people draw their own conclusions from this.

Comment: PS. Also, I hope someone will answer your question now given the fresh exposure, OP. It sounds interesting :p

Answer (score 5):

I want to know what research the SO/SE owners/admins are doing (or considering) on creating an AI (well maybe not a real AI, mayber only a programming Eliza bolted on to the resources of SE and the Web))  that will essentially automate the Googling operation and offer an immediate answer? Why restrict the search space for dupes to just a particular forum on SE? Why not develop a programming lexicon of potential synonyms for terms like "merge", "join" and, "append", perhaps with a dialog to get user-clarification on potentially ambiguous terms and then deploy a programming-specific search on the collective resource of SE and the Web. It's essentially an SE-Watson approach with the added feature of clarification steps.

This "AI" might scan the posting for the words "I searched" and ask for the search strategy. If there were no words there might be a Programming-Psychiatric dialog about what the "right" search strategy could be.

Comment: But this is exactly what Google does, why reinvent the wheel? And you can already add the qualifier `site:` to a search to get results from a specific site.

Comment: SO already has a mechanism to display a set of potential duplicates. I speculating that this search space could be expanded to a programming-specific, spider-gathered resource (maybe not Google?) and then questioners could be asked to interact with the results to explain in natural language why the offered answers were not satisfactory. That dialog with a automated system would be of value in the subsequent assessment by the "experts". (I did agree with the post that said "stop pontification" and ended with a call for clarity on the nature of the target user.)

Comment: I think the answer is "A code of conduct is a lot easier to change than actual code which won't make them money anyway". There is already [a bot with 99.97% recall](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354719/should-moderators-run-automated-bots-under-their-accounts/354724) for flagging useless comments, but SO hasn't tried to incorporate anything like that officially, despite it constituting ~15% of accepted flags in 2016. If they can't even do that for "me too!" comments then there's no way they'll have interest in doing anything similar for quality-checking question content.

Comment: Actually, this might be a good suggestion - as long as the AI has HAL-like personality issues, and access to SkyNet-like "resources". "HALnet - I've got a homework assignment, How do I implement the Fibonacci sequence in C?" "I'm sorry, Dave - I can't code that for you. But I *can* park a 5000 degree mushroom cloud over your home, in 5 seconds...4...3...2...1...". :-)

Comment: [Show Google results before user can post a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336128/show-google-results-before-user-can-post-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

The thing about telling people to Just Google it is that there's sometimes a *very* fine line between "teaching a man to fish", and being a jerk.

Yes, many of our visitors are obnoxious freeloaders, and this gets frustrating after a while, and they really out to lift at least one finger to help themselves before running here asking us to tie their shoelaces for them.

**But**, there are plenty other of our visitors who come here because they actually, honestly *need some help*, and they heard this was a place they could ask a question and maybe get an answer on something they needed some help with.

There's no bright line between a question that's worth asking here and a question that's so basic someone should have known the answer themselves.  There's no bright line between a question that's worth asking here and a question that's trivially Googleable, either.  If you see one of those questions and know the answer, you probably also know the search terms that would have found that answer in 5 seconds on Google -- but remember, *the answer wasn't obvious to the OP*.  That's why they've come here asking.  And if the answer to their question wasn't obvious, it's far more likely than you might think that they couldn't think of the right search terms to use, either.  Or maybe they wouldn't know how to interpret the answers they found.  Or maybe they're getting tired and frustrated, finding themselves on unfamiliar ground, five levels deep in a yak-shaving exercise, and they just want some actual, human help.

The reason that "Just Google it" is likely to come off as rude (rather than as nobly teaching someone to fish) is that in 2018, the likelihood that someone (a) does have an Internet connection and (b) has figured out how to post to Stackoverflow but (c) has not heard of or does not know how to search Google, is just about exactly zero.  So when you say "Just google it", you are *not* teaching them to fish, you're basically always scolding them for having been, in your mind, lazy.  So they're going to think you're rude, because no one likes being scolded.  They either don't think they're being lazy, or don't care.  But you're not going to teach them to be un-lazy by scolding them.  So if you think they're being rude or lazy, if you think they don't deserve your help, maybe just ignore them instead.  Answering rudeness with rudeness just raises the overall rudeness level.

(And remember, if you had absolutely no intention of rudeness when you wrote "Just google it" -- well, so what?  It doesn't matter how you intended the words; what matters -- if the question is how to make the site less rude and more welcoming -- is how those words are perceived.)

Comment: If I copy your title, paste it in Google, and get a relevant official tutorial whose sample code matches your problem exactly, hasn’t that crossed the line into clearly trivially Googleable? That happens all the time. And it means the OP did know the search terms, they just didn’t bother. And, while nobody is perfect, experienced SO users get pretty good at judging the difference between “novice who doesn’t know what to search” and “lazy vampire who doesn’t bother to search”. And advise to treat both groups the same way because we can’t distinguish between them 100% perfectly is…

Comment: … going to hurt all those novices that we’re currently treating better than the help vampires, for the small benefit of the tiny number who we’re accidentally miscategorizing. Is that really a win?

Comment: How is going around Googling questions for people that couldn't bother to helpful to the people that did their research, did their best to try to solve their problem, and wrote a good question that clearly indicated not just what they needed to do, but what they did to try to solve it and why it didn't work (in other words, asked a *good* question).  The people that ask those *good* questions are unaffected by what happens to the people that couldn't be bothered to search for their question before asking it.  This question isn't about "easy" questions, it's about *poorly researched* questions.

Answer (score 1):

> `[I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)`

Sure, asking people to show more evidence of their investment into a question in a general sense seems fine to me.

> What if they could have found the answer in 5 seconds on Google Search? In cases like this, is it wrong to point out the obvious?

...but that is both wrong and non-obvious.

*Wrong* because saying "you should have searched on Google" is advertising spam, and should be flagged as such.  Unless Stack Overflow decides in its new Code of Conduct to include a Pledge of Allegiance to Google.  But I think it better to have a tolerant attitude of those who might choose to not use certain outside services. E.g., if someone wants to, they should be able to use SO despite boycotting Google to get them to stop being involved with the military [(sidenote: I see they eventually did)](https://futurism.com/maven-google-military-tech/).

*Non-obvious* because Google is blocked in several parts of the world, [including China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Websites_blocked_in_mainland_China).

Beyond that, there's how much Google's results [vary on their whims](https://www.webpresencesolutions.net/7-reasons-google-search-results-vary-dramatically/): per location, per device, per person, per time, etc.

Maybe they searched on mobile and didn't get the result you think should have been on the top.  Maybe they searched from a different part of the world and it was influenced by their IP address.

Or maybe they can compose a question in English well enough, but have a harder time working inside an entire search surface that is in English.  The search engine they are comfortable with may not be Google, and may not index information the same way.

Comment: So "You could DuckDuckGo this in 5 seconds" is fine, right?

Comment: Fun-Fact: DDG actually includes results from stackoverflow in the result pages.

Comment: I cautiously agree with everything after the second quote, but disagree with your very first paragraph about "evidence of investment". I'm of the view that [deliberate *displays* of effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210840/200582) generally make a question worse, not better, and that they are not the yardstick by which a question's quality should be measured.

Comment: Note that the site's spam rules are not "you are not allowed to even mention any other company on this site".  It's entirely appropriate and allowed to mention the use of a company or product that is able to help someone solve their problem.  If they mention why the use of said product is not suitable for them, then alternatives can certainly be mentioned.  If Google is blocked for someone, other search tools can be mentioned *as they become necessary*.  Likewise, you're free to recommend the use of any alternative products you feel would help someone answer a question.

Comment: It only becomes spam if you fail to disclose an affiliation, are suggesting it where it's clearly not applicable for the sole purpose of advertising, it's clearly the only reason your account exists, etc.  Telling someone that a Google search will answer your question is none of those things.

Comment: This appears to be nothing more than a rant against google

Answer (score -1):

You don't tell someone to consult the documentation; that's not an answer.
You don't tell someone to Google it; that's not an answer.

In fact:

- even if they **have** consulted the documentation
- **even if they already know the answer**
- it is still a valid question to ask, and correct to ask it

Stack Overflow was [created as a sort of combination between Wikipedia and Reddit](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/). Which means if a piece of knowledge hasn't yet been asked to Stack Overflow, then it needs to be added to Stack Overflow.

- [it doesn't matter if it's documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797984/how-to-lowercase-a-string-in-python?rq=1)
- it doesn't matter if it Google search easily turns up the answer on another site

Telling someone to go consult the documentation is not an answer, it's the incorrect response.

The correct response is to either:

- answer the question, simply and directly
- link to the existing answer on the duplicate question; and vote to close

Stack Overflow is not a magical font where you ask a question get an answer. Stack Overflow is the collected knowledge of everything about everything related to programming. And if the question doesn't exist yet: it needs to be asked and answered.

But this also means that Stack Overflow is not a magical font where you ask a question and get an answer. If your question is in fact a duplicate of an existing question, then it should be closed (calmly, plainly, with a link to the existing answer)

---

- I've asked questions that I can find the answer to on the internet
- I've asked questions when I **know** the answer
- I've asked questions when I know the answer, and will give someone else the opportunity to answer it for the rep
- I've asked questions, already knowing the answer, and tell people the answer **in the question**, and tell people copy and paste the answer into an answer and I will accept it and give you reputation
- I'll answer my own question myself just to make Stack Overflow better - because it now contains more knowledge

---

From [**Stack Overflow Launches**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/) by Joel Splosky, 9/15/2008:

> Every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question. *How do I enlarge a fizzbar without overwriting the user’s snibbit?* This question should only appear once in the site. Duplicates should be cleaned up quickly and redirected to the original question.
>
> In addition to voting on answers, you can vote on questions. Vote up a question if you think it’s interesting, if you’d like to know the answer, or if you think it’s important. The hot tab on the home page will show some of the highest-ranked recent questions using an algorithm similar to digg or Reddit. If you’re generally interested in programming and want to learn something new every day, visit the hot tab frequently.

- I joined SO the day after launch: [`2008-09-16 14:53:25`.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/878423)
- ten years, and 112k reputation, later i still hold to that altruistic goal

Which is why it's so upsetting to see how mean-spirited and grumpy SO has become.

Comment: Almost upvoted because on paper you're absolutely right. But speaking socially you're absolutely wrong, and the pressure to not put pressure on people has resulted in this total mess of garbage the site now is. Speaks for itself really!

Comment: I basically agree with you. But SO should not be a learner's primary reference for well-defined subjects with their own documentation. The question or answers or both (and the tag wiki, too) should link to the primary reference. The Q&A format of SO can increase accessibility and visibility of small topics in large subjects.

Comment: Sorry, but I think it is time we stopped thinking it is our responsibility to make StackOverflow better.  That's SE management's job.

Comment: @StephenC What is the point of contributing at all, if not to make StackOverflow better? (points are, in themselves pretty meaningless after all). I think Ian is overstepping the mark far less than those people who think it is their responsibility to get rid of all poor quality questions, since it sounds like he does what he enjoys doing, while aiming to improve the site. In other words it is his pleasure rather than his responsibility to do so.

Comment: @Ben - simple.  **Helping people**.   But my point is that it is not our **responsibility** to make SO better.  Which is a good thing because the real problems are deeper than we (the community) can solve.

Comment: @StephenC I agree that helping people is the main point, more than improving the site, also that improving the site is not our responsibility. What I don't understand is how this applies to this answer. To me it sounds like Ian just enjoys contributing to the site, because it helps people. I think other users are trying to take responsibility for getting rid of poor questions from the site, and that your point is more relevant to them.

Comment: I was replying to the earlier comments rather than the Answer.

Comment: This site shouldn't attempt to be a replacement for documentation which already exists.  Copying and pasting documentation into this site doesn't help anyone.

Comment: This is what I came here to answer with. And it was written better than I could write it. I'm saddened that it got down-voted so heavily.

Comment: The valid question, the one that gets asked after consulting the documentation, is different in important ways from the lazy question.  The valid question links the documentation, quotes the part that OP thinks might be relevant but is confusing, and focuses on the portion of the problem that isn't clearly addressed in the documentation.  The lazy question "lacks research effort" and is subject to deletion for that reason.

Comment: Why should stack overflow duplicate clear documentation that already exists? I thought we shut that failed project down a while ago.

Comment: [Stackoverflow was created as a sort of combination between Wikipedia and Reddit](https://xkcd.com/285/)

Comment: `Stackoverflow was created as a sort of combination between Wikipedia and Reddit.` - co-founder of SO disagrees with you. Quote from "Stack Overflow: Where We Hate Fun": [There’s no way we’re sacrificing our core Q&A; mission to turn into a brainless LOL-fest like Reddit or Digg](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

Comment: co-founder of SO agrees with me. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/

Comment: @IanBoyd After re-reading Joel's post again I'm still not seeing the part where Joel says that questions are not expected to be well researched, and that it's perfectly fine to duplicate content that's already readily accessible elsewhere.  It doesn't look like the post addresses the issue at all really, other than saying that the main problem that they're trying to solve is that web searches for many different practical problems don't yield any useful results, which implies that the site exists to provide answers for those search that don't yield useful results.

Comment: @Alex Well, technically "SO Documentation" wasn't supposed to duplicate all official documentation, it was supposed to pick up where they left off and be a useful supplementary.  Everyone told SO that that wouldn't work because it'd just end up doing nothing but duplicating official documentation.  They went through with it anyway.  It ended up doing very little besides plagiarizing official documentation, hence it was (eventually) shut down.

Comment: *"It is not our responsibility to make Stackoverflow better."* The mentality that has ruined stackoverflow.

Comment: "*I've asked questions, already knowing the answer, **and tell people the answer in the question**, and tell people copy and paste the answer into an answer and I will accept it and give you reputation*" Sorry, I am with you except for this point. That's not allowed. Solutions belong in answers, not in the question. It's fine to ask a question you know the answer to but, questions need to _ask questions_. This sounds like reputation fraud, similar to paying bounties purely to increase someone else's rep.

Comment: @TylerH On the contrary, it is inkeeping with the very **spirit** of StackOverflow, which is a combination of Wikipedia and Reddit. I am adding knowledge to SO (wikipedia) by asking the question, and providing the answer. Votes are the mechanism to recognize useful questions or answers. It's ok if you don't agree; i'm here to may Stackoverflow better, and most users of stackoverflow are here to fight against making it better.

Comment: @IanBoyd Stack Overflow (not "StackOverflow") is not "a combination of Wikipedia and Reddit." What Joel's blog post actually said is that every question is _like_ a Wikipedia page about a very specific programming question. He also said the site _uses algorithms like digg or Reddit_ to rank questions. That's it. Site employees _have_ discussed what Stack Overflow is/isn't, though: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums

Comment: @IanBoyd And though the author isn't an employee, my favorite is [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums/92122#92122). The Venn diagram there aptly covers how Stack Overflow is at the nexus between not just Wikipedia and Reddit but also traditional discussion forums and weblogs.

Comment: @IanBoyd It's important to note that no one has issues with you asking a question and providing an answer. What is at issue here is doing it the way the site works. Blog posts that don't leave a question open are not actually questions, and thus are not acceptable on Stack Overflow. If you want to post an answer to a question, do so in an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: @IanBoyd I'm not sure what you mean by "*Votes are the mechanism to recognize useful questions or answers.*" or by implying that I don't agree with that. I never said anything to the contrary. Please avoid strawman arguments (along with sweeping, baseless statements like "most users are here fighting against making Stack Overflow better").

Comment: @TylerH Sorry. Someone above tried to imply that providing the answer to the question **in** the question is somehow not allowed, or goes against the spirit of Stackoverflow. I was pointing out that it a) it **does** follow the rules, and b) it **is** inkeeping with the spirit of Stackoverflow. That is why i do it: to honor the very purpose of Stackoverflow, and to make Stackoverflow better. It is our responsibility to make Stackoverflow better.

Comment: @IanBoyd What comment, specifically, are you replying to? **I** _said_ (I did not simply imply) that it is not allowed, and that is correct. Answers belong in answer posts, _not_ in question posts. That's not in the spirit or in the design of Stack Overflow (again, "Stackoverflow" is not a thing; there's a space between the two capitalized words). See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74413 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/ and more recently https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400494 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387792. Or just read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: By putting an answer in a question, one explicitly _dishonors_ Stack Overflow and its purpose by abusing the site's design and intended functions and processes. Self-answering is a good thing to do, and there is **one** acceptable way to do it: post the solution as an answer, not as part of the question.

Comment: Putting the answer in the question explicitely *honors* the entire ethos of StackOverflow, and is embracing the entire point of the site. It is the right thing to so, and people need to know this. I wanted to make sure that anyone reading a comment saying that it is *"wrong"* know that it is not wrong, and remind people they are free to also help make StackOverflow better.

Comment: @IanBoyd "*Putting the answer in the question explicitely honors the entire ethos of StackOverflow*" [citation needed]

Comment: @IanBoyd "Putting the answer in the question explicitely honors the entire ethos of StackOverflow, and is embracing the entire point of the site." That is quite possibly the most wrong statement I have ever read on meta.stackoverflow.com. It also suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of what the English words "question" and "answer" mean.

Comment: @TylerH while I agree that questions need to ask questions, I can't fathom how it could be considered *fraudulent*, on a reputation basis, to answer within one's own question. If anything, a properly self-answered question is offering other users twice as many upvote buttons for the same content.

Comment: it's fine to answer one's own question in the answer box.

Comment: @TylerH People being upset when Stackoverflow contains **more** helpful information rather than less. *That is quite possibly the most wrong statement I have ever read on meta.stackoverflow.com*   Right back at ya. Why anyone would think intentionally sabotaging the site is a good thing is quite beyond me. Takes a different kind of human to think intentionally suppressing is ever a reasonable idea. The rest of us are here to make Stackoverflow ***better***.

Comment: Placing the answer in your question *is* intentionally sabotaging the site.

Comment: It seems as if you're literally spreading misinformation just out of spite because a mod deleted a chatgpt answer that was *also* wrong.

Comment: @KevinB Plaing the answer in my question *is* intentionally improving the site. Anyone suggesting Stackoverflow should contain **less** information, rather than more, is, quite simply, wrong.

Comment: Noone telling you answers don't belong in the question are suggesting so should contain less information rather than more, quite the opposite actually. Providing the answer as an answer provides *more* information in that it clearly identifies the answer as an answer and allows others to upvote/downvote it to provide more confirmation that it is a good answer. Posting the answer in the question is no better than providing an answer in a comment; it can be deleted at any time by anyone.

Comment: @KevinB *"Posting the answer in the question is no better than providing an answer in a comment; it can be deleted at any time by anyone"*: False. Comments are limited in length, do not allow formatting, tables, imagines, bullet points.

Comment: however, they, just like answers posted in a question, can be easily deleted by anyone while following site policy.

Comment: @KevinB You mean impossible to delete; because we can see the edit history, and the name of the person who tried to sabotage the post.

Comment: Deleting an answer from a question won't be viewed as sabotage. the edit history is there, if the OP wants to post an answer they can.

Comment: @KevinB I agree, deleting information from Stackoverflow is bad (i.e. sabotage). Which is why it's nice to have the edit history to a) restore the damaged content, and b) call out the saboteur.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The fraudulent part is posting the answer with the intent for another user to copy it and post it as an answer, so that the other user can then have their post upvoted to receive reputation.

Comment: The desirable, good, and correct part is posting the answer with the intent for another user to copy it and post it as an answer, so that the other user can then have their post upvoted to receive reputation. That is the entire **point** of trying to make Stackoverflow better. There's no particular reason **i** should get rep for an answer i already know. That is left to the helpful Stackoverflow user who takes the time to read the question and supply the answer.

Comment: "There's no particular reason i should get rep for an answer i already know." ... What on earth? No, the point is not to reward people for knowing stuff that helps the person who asked. The point is to reward people for **doing the work to help build a library of useful stuff**. If you know something, then you **absolutely should** get rep for taking the time to both frame and explain what you know in the highly challenging (but rewarding) Q&A format.

Comment: "Plaing the answer in my question is intentionally improving the site. Anyone suggesting Stackoverflow should contain less information, rather than more, is, quite simply, wrong." Again, you couldn't possibly be more wrong. **Information is not the same as quality.** "deleting information from Stackoverflow is bad (i.e. sabotage)" Kevin didn't say that, and it's completely and utterly wrong. Putting information in the wrong place is effectively vandalism, just as it would be on Wikipedia (e.g. copying and pasting random excerpts from the article about cats into the one about dogs).

Answer (score -10):

Whether or not the answer can be found with a quick google search is irrelevant to whether or not the question is a good fit. Because it's irrelevant, there's no reason to bring it up in a comment.

So if you do a quick google search and the question already has an answer **on Stack Overflow** then do the normal thing and close as a duplicate. Most simple questions will fall into this category.

If the question fails to meet the minimum standard for some other reason (off-topic, unclear, too broad, opinion-based) then do the normal thing and downvote/vote to close for the appropriate reason. Feel free to leave a comment explaining why.

As pointed out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) (among other places), one of the goals of Stack Overflow is to be the "ultimate source for all programming related questions". So if it's a good question that hasn't already been asked (rare), it belongs on the site. There are advantages to having Stack Overflow as a canonical source such as community vetting and the ability to update/evolve over time.

Comment: Why should people willing to sacrifice their time to help improve the site do the lazy asker's Googling for them? I can tell you that is a curating activity that gets old very quickly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I fail to see how that's relevant to this question or my answer. Are you suggesting the solution to the problem of lazy questions is to comment telling people to google instead? That seems ridiculous.

Comment: @pnuts That's not a close reason and it seems to be at odds with what I've linked and what I've read elsewhere. Do you have a source for why that makes a good fit?

Comment: @pnuts Oh interesting. It seems they have a bit of mixed messaging going on... here's another example of where my answer is coming from, which is completely at odds with the up/down messaging: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299411/2124351

Comment: `Are you suggesting the solution to the problem of lazy questions is to comment telling people to google instead?` It's ultimately not a constructive solution to the problem, no. Neither is requiring every one of those questions to be closed as a duplicate, though. It's a waste of volunteer time. One thing that could help this that I'd love to see implemented is here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336128/show-google-results-before-user-can-post-a-question

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ah yes I like that idea. I don't really disagree with any of your points, but closing as a duplicate seems to be the way to handle it at the moment.

Comment: @Pekka Why should I sacrifice my time to help improve the site when the a lazy asker couldn't be bothered to do a simple search? Easy: to make Stackoverflow better. We make do these things because we are good people who want to make Stackoverflow better. And closing questions you be bothered to answer is very must **not** making Stackoverflow better. It is our responsiblity to make Stackoverflow better.

Answer (score -24):

A simple solution is charge just enough money to ask a question that it becomes less expensive to find the answers on Google.

Nothing can be given away for free which isn’t free. The spam that is impacting these free sites is an example of that aphorism. The time of those who use a Q & A seriously in their work is not free.

Those who use a site seriously will find it is much cheaper overall to pay an insignificant amount (relative to significant earnings of a professional programmer) so that spammers are disincentivized, than to wade through all the spam. And there’s no solution that is better than economics directed one.

All the downvotes are of course irrelevant. **Meta is for being frank.**

Comment: The problem is that this is *too* strong of a disincentive.  You'll push away all of the good questions along with all of the bad ones.

Comment: I really think you're making assumptions about who is downvoting and why. I myself downvoted for the same reason that Servy gave - requiring money would be too big a disincentive. Still, disencentivizing the act of asking a question, itself, is something to consider.

Comment: You are not disincentivizing anything. Anyone who is worth anything and earns anything from being a professional programmer will gain many multiples of the cost to disincentivize spammers by having their important question answered.

Comment: One of the reasons for Stack Overflow's creation was that a certain other site was charging for access to its answers, and the founders did not like that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn’t propose to charge for viewing answers. I proposed to charge for asking a question, so as to minimize spamming with questions and increase the quality and care put into formulating questions. When readers don’t even read what I write, then downvote what kind of veracity and integrity does that voting system represent? All downvotes should be required to be public information and every downvoter should provide a reason. All this obfuscation is not in the spirit of transparency and veracity. All because of politics and egos.

Answer (score -43):

This is social behaviour (reality).

For big data (like the Stack Exchange community), dealing with data quality need to be anyhow, but fixing or teaching its source (people).

Can't you consider such a problem as data? What questions are repeated? What field? When? Why? Seasonality? ... etc.

I understand that you (and many like you) desire to have nice looking community, but me not .. and maybe some others too.

Ciao!