# Why do people post questions that they could Google in 5 seconds?

Tags: discussion

Related: *[What if they COULD google their question in 5 seconds?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371347/what-if-they-could-google-their-question-in-5-seconds)*

The new Code of Conduct banned comments like "you could Google this in 5 seconds!" as excessively condescending. *LMGTFY* has been banned for a while for being condescending and rude.

I got to thinking the other day, though: Given that it (presumably) takes more than 5 seconds to post a question here, why *do* people still post stuff that they could Google in five seconds?

Comment: Because they are lazy or lacking google fu? Provide them with appropriate duplicate answers you found at google instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If they were lazy and they could Google their question in 5 seconds, wouldn't they do that instead of posting here?

Comment: @EJoshuaS no, because that would make them do the work of Googling (and reading the linked articles!). They can ask here without using their brain.

Comment: They probably tired to use the intrinsic search feature of the site, which doesn't leave you with the same results. That's a well known problem.

Comment: @HereticMonkey They'd have to read the answers here, though, too, wouldn't they? I still don't understand why they think that posting here is easier than Googling it themselves.

Comment: It's a different kind of laziness. It's the same kind of laziness that keeps me from changing my home directory to somewhere useful instead of cd-ing into the directory I always use. Sure, it would take me 5 seconds to change my .profile , and it takes me 3 seconds to type the line of where I'm going every time, but for some reason, I just always type it out instead because I'm too lazy to change my current train of thought to make my life easier. It's been a year like this since I set up this machine and I've never used the default home directory, always that of my copy of my old drive.

Comment: "_'Effective Searching' is a learned skill._", as [ashleedawg's answer on the linked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371357/4320665) explains.

Comment: But the answer here is custom-made for them; they copy-paste it and they're done. If the answer isn't directly copy-paste-able, they raise hell on a social media platform and the next thing you know, we can't mark questions on duplicates any more... Sorry, went off on a tangent there :).

Comment: @EJoshuaS Laziness is a big attractor. Letting other people do the harder work for you seems to be the easier way to go nowadays. We try to fight that misconception as good as we can though.

Comment: Because it is a personalised answer. They spare the effort of understanding and filtering the google hits which look fruitful, but they aren't.

Comment: I expect most just don't realize that they're expected to do their own research, or honestly don't realize how easy it is or how much information is out their.  They just assume that if they searched they wouldn't find their answer, or don't even consider that they *could* search first.  Most of the other explanations would cover the less egregious cases; this applies more to the could *literally* find the answer with 5 seconds of googling.

Comment: @FabianBigler That question isn't asking why people ask poorly researched questions, it's asking how we should deal with them.

Comment: @FabianBigler *This* question is asking why people post stuff they can google in five second.  The post you linked to is asking how we should deal with posts that can be googled in five seconds.  It doesn't answer this question.

Comment: There seems to me to be a high percentage of poor questions that just searching for the question title provides a reasonable result: right now Googling [select rows where parameter match columns in joint tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53200913/1270789) takes me to [SQL: Select from one table matching criteria in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5446778/1270789); Google manages to parse the vague technical-term free title into a reasonable query. (And yes, I've flagged it as a dup!)

Comment: @KenY-N Yes, I was curious about those in particular.

Comment: Somewhat related: I wonder if we could discourage the use of "google" as verb. There are many other search engines, and we're encouraging beginners into a monopoly mindset if we (accidentally) support the idea that there are no other search engine services available.

Comment: the fact that _we_ are able to identify a dupe in a few seconds justifies (again) the dupehammer feature.

Comment: Maybe you could have google that.

Comment: Don't forget that your answer will be indexed, so that every thousands of user actually googling this will just find "guy just google it" Frustrating answer isn't it?

Comment: Because the ones who DO google it in five seconds and find their answer DON'T post here.

Comment: A lot of people believe their experience in life to be unique in comparison to everyone else's. Their decisions are the correct ones, their actions are the best ones. As such, their problems are unique to them as well. How could anyone have asked this question in the past, if they (and thus, their problems) were infallible up to the point where they decided to ask their question.

Comment: @pdem yup. And if the google target goes away, you now have a red herring answer that just pollutes search results. I found a ton of those when I was researching something related to OpenGL and I wasted a lot of time. "Google X" is worse than a link only answer. Just a friendly reminder to always include relevant information (in your own words) into your answer when positing. Especially if the "google this" result you're talking about is a blog on somebody's personal site, those disappear all the time.

Comment: Why do people provide answers in the comments?

Comment: @HereticMonkey hehe *nervous chuckle* #NotMyDuplicate

Comment: People are different. Some people already know, others will google something in 5 seconds, others in 3, some in 10 and others will never find the answer. The answer below is pretty good though.

Comment: @DavyM, can I assume that you are using the command line because you trying to do the most with the fewest keystrokes?

Comment: Googling in 5 seconds is subjective. For someone with prior knowledge on the solution and a mind that is not tired (after trying to solve a problem and failing many times), Googling in 5 seconds works. If you can Google the answer in 5 seconds, either you use 5 seconds to help someone, or you just ignore the question. There is no need for a rude answer.

Comment: I think this is a rude question :o)

Comment: because they use Bing

Comment: I just came up with a theory here... what if there are actually dumb people using the Internet!? As in, what if there are actually people using the site _without even considering_ to use Google first!? Or even (*gasp*) posting a question without considering the quality at all? This would explain _everything_ that has happened on Internet forums ever since Epoch! _Mind blown_. (Next theory: what if there are actually rude people using the Internet?)

Comment: I think people often want to get points on stack overflow. They think to themselves "ah! I'll ask a question that nobody has ever thought of!" And they type it out, hoping to get tons of points from the question," without actually seeing if anybody HAS thought of the question.

Comment: If they could google it, they wouldn't ask the question. Google is much easier and much less insulting than SO.

Comment: @TerryCarmen If that's true, why are there so many questions about Null Pointer Exceptions still? It's not hard to search for.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Because the poster doesn't understand what a null pointer is or why they have one or what it means. A lot of the time first posts aren't asking the question they typed, they're showing that they don't understand the underlying concept.

Comment: @TerryCarmen That doesn't seem like an explanation, though - what's stopping them from just Googling "what is a Null Pointer Exception"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS continued . . .Especially for new or inexperienced programmers, entire toolchains and technologies are overwhelming to the point that when "something is wrong" they're not equipped to even know what the thing is.

Comment: @TerryCarmen I agree, but for common exceptions you can literally copy and paste the text into Google and get the answer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS nothing is stopping them. However there's also no reason that SO needs to be the Forum of Last Resort. Asking "what is a null pointer exception" shouldn't get verbal abuse and a close vote, it should just get a friendly pointer to the good answer that exists right here.

Comment: @TerryCarmen The new Code of Conduct discourages condescending comments, but if something has been asked and answered many times why shouldn't it be marked as a duplicate? There's little point in us rehashing the same information over and over.

Comment: @EJoshuaS In fact, I just tried it. DuckDuckGo gives me great snippet from SO. Google however gives me a really crappy explanation based on Java that doesn't really answer the question. If the poster only checked Google, I can see why SO would be the next stop.

Comment: @Terry how does that change Joshua's point though? If the question is duplicated on SO, should we not point the user to that? Verbal abuse shouldn't be given I agree, but dupe-closure is a *good* thing. Without it we run the risk of SO not being the centralized repo of knowledge it claims to be as better answers pop left right and center for the same question.

Comment: Because everyone else get reps, why not? It sounds selfish but reps are good, right?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Because they genuinely *cannot* "google that in 5 seconds". Allow me to explain.

When people are searching for a solution to a problem, they sometimes enter a kind of "search mode". They read everything with a filter over their eyes. That filter is designed to search for solutions to the problem they're currently having. Any information which is not obviously a direct, complete, and comprehensible solution to the problem as they understand it is discarded by this filter.

Basically, when people enter "search mode", they're not interested in *learning* anything; they want the solution to their problem.

See, most "google that in 5 seconds" problems can't actually be googled that quickly. Not unless you know exactly what you're looking for. Most of the time, Google Search will take you to a page that *has* the answer, but you have to read through a bunch of stuff that is *not* your answer.

If you're thinking in terms of learning how something works, this is great. Googling a topic or question can lead you to a lot of foundational information. All of that "stuff that is not your answer" is useful and will help avoid problems in the future. It will give you a better foundation of understanding the system, and allow you to become a better programmer.

But if you're in "search mode"... you *do not care*. You don't want to understand the system; you want a solution, *period*. So all of that "foundational information" is just noise to you, and your "filter" will discard it. If Google Search links you to a page that appears to be pointless noise about stuff that isn't your problem, you won't find it very useful.

Even worse, note my previous phrasing: "the problem *as they understand it*". Many people don't *really* understand the problem they're having. They often think the problem is one thing, when it is something only tangentially related to it. Their vision of the solution is based on their understanding of the problem. And since their "filter" culls out things that don't look like the solution, but their idea of what the solution will be is *wrong*... they will cull out the *actual solution*.

Google is a useful tool, but getting the most out of it requires the right mindset. You have to go into it with a willingness to *learn*, not just to apply a pattern filter to find your answer. And a lot of people don't really think that way. Even some long-time programmers, when learning a new system, will often fall victim to "filter"-based reading. I know I have.

Comment: I wish I could add more to this answer.  I weep at the truth it tells (notably the "you want a solution, period" - since I've **been** in those shoes).

Comment: I tend to disagree. For quite some newbie questions, you copy/paste the title of their question, you put that into Google, and you get the solution right there. Very often, the first link by google gives a solution, code, explanation. I came to the conclusion: people very much prefer that somebody explicitly **explains** to them what their problem is.

Comment: @GhostCat: That's an unfair assertion; for the questions which turn out to be easier than you realize at the time, being able to express what they are in terms of a search query is a fundamentally impossible task.  Only *after* you understand what the problem actually was and how to look for a solution could you consider a problem "newbie".

Comment: I don't understand that comment. I occasionally do that: I copy the exact question title that the newbie used on stack overflow into google, and I get perfect newbie consumable links back. Not always, but more often than not.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, questions do exist where the duplicates are hard to find.  They're less common than duplicates that are very easy to find, but they certainly happen.   GhostCat wasn't contenting that hard to research problems exist, just that there are also a *lot* of very *easy* to find duplicates out there, duplicates even the author of those questions are more than capable of finding.  This meta post is about *those* questions.

Comment: I would add to that language differences and some things that seem extremely simple get extremely difficult.

Comment: Adding to this to some people might know what they want to achieve or what to do but don't know the exact type of 'thing' to search for example you know the term of pop-up boxes. Meanwhile what you're supposed to search is a dialog box, but you don't know the dialog box. More often than not they would ask about pop-up boxes and not the dialog boxes.

Comment: @GhostCat Could it be that your Google is tuned to programming whereas the newbie's Google is tuned to, say, Kim Kardashian, American football, and the Midterm Elections 2018? Does it still work if you use duckduckgo? (I suspect it does, but I was trying to construct an excuse for the newbies.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Fair point. Next time I make such an experiment, I will try to use other search engines, too ;-)

Comment: Google fu is a skill many devs lack and takes a lot of learning to get right too. I wish more people would realise that.

Comment: RTFM (or search Google) is, at some level, a correct answer to the majority of tech questions ever asked.  It is however, neither clear nor helpful nor the answer that people want; if it was then this site, and many IT jobs, would not exist.

Comment: @Lunc: I rather doubt that. There are many cases where "TFM" doesn't exist or is flat-out *wrong*. SO could probably subsist on just the cases where Windows documentation is inaccurate/incomplete.

Comment: This answer is often contradicted by literally searching the question title. It's common enough that you *must* have seen it. Sure, sometimes that means they need to actually sit down and spend some minutes *reading* the result and working out their understanding, but the fact they don't is a failure on their part, not ours. And since we are not a personal tutorial service, we expect users to have done so. Thanks for undermining SO's core values and blaming users for being understandably frustrated.

Comment: "*the fact they don't is a failure on their part, not ours*" I never claimed it was a failure on our part. The question asked about the reason behind a phenomenon, and I attempted to offer an explanation for it. And my point is that "*sit down and spend some minutes reading the result and working out their understanding*" is *not* the way the user is thinking. So to them, doing the search will not lead to the answer; it will lead to a page that has a bunch of noise in it where the answer is/may be buried.

Comment: Completely agree with GhostCat, I try that often too, and if I can find answers like that (and most of the time I can), I will put that in a comment too. Not an LMGTFY link, but at least smth like *"I pasted your exact question title in Google, and the first page gave me [this] and [this] and [this]"*. If people are put off by that, it's too bad. I hope they take it as a hint that "wow, maybe I should have thought of that", in addition to being helped by getting direct links to duplicates of their question.

Comment: My initial reaction to this answer was similar to yours, @jpmc26, because I find what Nicol describes very disappointing. But I don't think that the answer is actually defending or even apologizing for it; on re-reading I believe it's meant to be a neutral observation. (And an unfortunately insightful one.)

Comment: This is pretty obvious to me, but very nicely formulated - better that I could have done it. It also points out the weakness (without mentioning the destructiveness) of the "this is a duplicate" mentality. There are very rarely duplicate questions, it is the answers that are duplicates.

Comment: @JoshCaswell The problem with this answer is that it's saying that *sometimes* the author couldn't have reasonably found the duplicate question, which is true, but the problem is that often it's *not* true.  Talking about all of the reasons that the actually reasonable duplicates get asked doesn't address the fact that a *large* portion of the duplicates being asked *aren't* reasonable.  Conflating them is very problematic.  Yes, sometimes someone had no way of knowing what to search for.  **This is not about those times**, it's about all of the times where they *did* know what to search for.

Comment: @Servy: This answer isn't talking about duplicates. Indeed, this *question* isn't asking about them either. The question is about users who ask things whose answers are easy to find via Google. My answer is that, in a lot of cases, they're not easy to find because those doing the searching are not doing so with a mindset that allows them to *see the answer*.

Comment: "search mode": I so recognise this. It's the mode you're in when you're under stress or time pressure. It's often not a good mode to be in, but not every person in "search mode" is lazy. Life can be tough, and there's sometimes not enough time or energy for deep understanding of a particular topic that's otherwise not your main concern or expertise.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you agree that your answer isn't talking about the same situations as this question.  In that case, why post it as an answer?  Yes, there are questions that can't be answered by 5 seconds of googling by the author.  But there *are* lots of questions that *can* be answered by 5 seconds of googling by the author.  Why do people ask *those* questions.  Given that lots of questions answer answered by *googling the title*, clearly the author of the question is capable of doing that.  You can't claim they're not capable of forming *the exact question they posted here*.

Comment: @Servy: "*So you agree that your answer isn't talking about the same situations as this question.*" No, I'm saying that the answer isn't talking about the same situations *you are*. I'm saying that your understanding of what the question is asking is incorrect. What is easy and what is not depends on *mindset*.

Comment: @GhostCat I'd bet that folks learn to phrase their question better by asking [a human than a search engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). They simply may not noticed that they've learned something by formulating the question. I've been lucky enough to delete over half of my SO questions before posting, because I figured out precisely what I didn't know, and could google it at that point.

Comment: @NicolBolas The question is asking, "Why do people ask questions that they could have found by searching for 5 seconds?" and you've responded with, "Some questions out there can't be found in 5 seconds."  Which is of course true, but doesn't answer the question of why people ask those questions that they *could* have found by just searching.  Unless you're arguing that there literally aren't any questions asked on the site that can be found by the author searching for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Servy: No, my answer is "what you think can be found in 5 seconds frequently cannot be found in 5 seconds if you're not of the right mindset".

Comment: @NicolBolas Which is not an answer to the question.  The question isn't asking about what causes questions to not be easily searchable for people, or why people ask questions that EJoshuaS was able to google in five seconds.  It's asking about the questions where the author of the question *could* have found them in 5 seconds.  So unless you're saying that no such questions exist, it's not an answer.

Comment: Amen. Your spot on. If it was that easy for them to find ‘their’ answer, they would not spend 5 minutes on formulating a question here.

Comment: _"Most of the time, Google Search will take you to a page that has the answer, but you have to read through a bunch of stuff that is not your answer."_ When did everybody become so allergic to _reading_? The only way to understand the answer is to _study_ and _learn_ the surrounding context. There is no excuse for not doing this other than sheer laziness, sorry. Unfortunately, getting answers to such questions merely propagates the myth that a quick wham-bam-thankyou-maam three-lines-of-code solution is in any way a substitute for proper research and learning.

Comment: tl;dr giving "search mode" a name doesn't make it a valid, good or non-lazy approach to software development, and at worst you're risking normalising this behaviour and preventing people from learning to _stop doing it_

Comment: I would also add that some people lacks the ability to search for the exact technical words needed. Been there, done that. After getting an answer and re-searching Google using the new learned technical words, I would find other solutions as well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: "*you're risking normalising this behaviour and preventing people from learning to stop doing it*" Yes, making people aware of a real phenomenon is just normalizing that behavior. Better to just call them lazy. After all, why bother trying to *understand* someone's behavior when you can just demonize it? Understanding behavior means recognizing that other people aren't just imbeciles. And if we can't think of them as being stupid, we might *empathize* with them. Or even help them avoid it. No field of human endeavor has ever been improved by *hiding* the truth.

Comment: @NicolBolas I've spent years trying to understand the behaviour and my deciding to state here my conclusion as to its cause shouldn't be taken to suggest otherwise ;) I'm certainly not suggesting that we shouldn't analyse how these people work, nor publish our findings, but I _strongly_ believe we need to discourage that behaviour when we're done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, we can and should discourage it. But to do that effectively, you must first correctly diagnose it. And I don't believe that reducing it to being "allergic to reading" or "lazy" is an accurate diagnosis. And therefore, accusing people of such maladies won't stop them from appearing. You can't treat cancer by pretending it's the flu.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree that it must be diagnosed. Apparently we disagree on what that diagnosis is, though, which is fine! You think it's flu. I think it's cancer. Absent further data we can't really go further.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to apply the solution a newbie finds to their own issue - perhaps they lack the necessary skills to change things around, otherwise an unwillingness to change things around!

Comment: Over the years I've noticed, both in and out of this site (pretty much anywhere really), that people are quick to jump to the conclusion that stating an observation implies you're supporting, endorsing, defending or apologizing for it. I guess it explains why [shooting the messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_the_messenger) is such a problem. (And I post this well aware somebody will be tempted to give me flak for my statement.)

Answer (score 105):

Some of this is guessing, some of this is what I've read askers say in comments.

- They don't know the correct terms to get at what they want.
- They don't know how to form good search queries to get what they want.
- They did find something but didn't understand it.
- They did find something, made a mistake in implementing the answer, and assumed the answer they found was incorrect.
- They did find something, made a mistake in implementing the answer, assumed *they* made a mistake but failed to mention this in their question.
- They want the opinion of someone they're sure is an expert  (or experts).
- They aren't sure what they're asking for is what they need.
- They want to be able to ask follow-up questions.

Comment: • Their variables have different names.

Comment: • They have got sick of their problem/homework and want someone to finish it (just this once).

Comment: @halfer before I get too mad at those people I try to remember the time I spent three hours trying to work with a non-zero indexed array (from a VBA library) in C# before basically begging on IRC for somebody to solve my problem. Not my finest hour, but I think we all have those days...

Comment: @mbrig: begging is to be strongly discouraged, even though we can understand what gives rise to it. It is, by definition, a form of emotional manipulation, and is beyond the pale when used against volunteers one does not know. On IRC, where one has pre-existing relationships (or with colleagues where one knows there is a greater available well of kindness) it is perhaps more forgivable. My general concern is helper burn-out, which comes from people being manipulated to assist more than they have energy for.

Comment: I have tried to explore this theme [on this question here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions).

Comment: One thing that should also be pointed out is that two people can google with the same search and get completely different results since google does customize the search results for everyone

Comment: @halfer, describing begging as "a form of emotional manipulation" is pretty cynical. There's a big difference between expressing false emotion to manipulate people and expressing true emotion resulting from genuine suffering and need. Presumably some begging falls into the former category, but all of it?

Comment: @halfer indeed, I didn't mean to imply that begging should be rewarded (especially here on SO), just that I no longer get angry at such people. DV/Flag/etc as needed and move on is my plan now.

Comment: @senderle: I hear you. The view I take is that begging can be added for two reasons: (1) as an emotional release from frustration, which is understandable, and (2) to indicate that the writer would like a fast response or priority treatment over other questions. My objections to begging stem entirely from the second category. It is not that I wish to be hard on people; indeed, the purpose of my policy is to protect valuable helpers, so they are encouraged to help over the long term.

Comment: @mbrig: I think _Meta_ is of the view that begging is not sufficiently important as to require a mod flag. When I see it, I edit out the chatty material and paste a boilerplate comment, and downvote if the begging was particularly egregious (e.g. it amounts to title vandalism). This is perhaps more educational than before, where I would just edit and downvote.

Comment: @senderle: I see your point regarding emotional manipulation. I don't mean to suggest it is fraudulent; what I am getting at here is that writers are telling readers that their suffering and woe will end if only a kind soul will help them. In other words, readers become responsible for that suffering if they do not help. I think that can reasonably be called manipulative, even if it is not necessarily an entirely conscious strategy.

Comment: (I'd be willing to use other descriptive words if you find my language too strong - I am using these words merely in their descriptive capacity, rather then something that is intended to be excessively condemnatory).

Comment: @halfer, I do see your point. I would still say that some begging is *communicative* rather than strategic or manipulative (consciously or otherwise). But telling the difference is not trivial. This is one of many instances of the more general dilemma the site faces -- identifying and redirecting bad actors without driving away good ones.

Comment: @halfer: That's a good analysis of why begging is such a bad thing: as you say *readers become responsible for that suffering if they do not help*.  I've felt that way with followup comments on my answers sometimes.  Begging right in the question itself has nearly no emotional impact on me, though.  SO is completely the wrong place for "help me now" requests, and they're usually the lowest future value questions that are just clutter to future searchers.  (Trivial variation on something common, or full of too many errors and misconceptions for one answer.  SO isn't a tutoring service.)

Comment: +1 I've programmed forever but sometimes I just can't figure out the magic phrase to get google to spit out the correct results to some software dilemma. I've asked questions where I absolutely knew there was an answer out there but 10 minutes of searching had lead to nothing at all of use! I'll post on SO, continue to search, then get an answer on SO while still not having found an answer myself, just because I was missing some magic word I hadn't considered.

Comment: @senderle: absolutely; well put.

Comment: @PeterCordes: your implication that readers are susceptible to manipulation to greatly varying degrees is worth thinking about. I wonder if I am irritated by it to a high degree because I know that, to some extent, I am affected by it. It feels coercive. (In my link above, I explored the idea that some of this phenomenon is affected by the cultural background of both writers and readers. In my Stack Overflow experience, some countries normalise pleading behaviours in which a sense of helplessness and deferentialism is encouraged, which I find embarrassing).

Comment: Also: they want the answer quickly, and asking someone who knows is always perceived as being faster than googling it. Although as pointed out by others here, googling isn't any slower than posting a stack overflow question (and then patiently waiting for an answer; I once waited 8 months!) It's just that perception that someone who knows can just quickly tell you, whether or not it's a true assumption. The attitude of, if I can find someone who knows, I don't need to know. Personally, I not only want to learn for myself, but also document it so that 1) I don't forget, and 2) others benefit.

Comment: Thier English is poor and they cant find the solution in their native not-English language.

Comment: @halfer There's nothing wrong with asking for help. I've been writing SQL queries since the 80's but sill ended up asking for help because I had been staring at the same 5 lines all day. It turns out that MySQL will happily stuff a DATETIME into a DATE and truncate the time portion and not complain. Everybody needs help sometimes.

Comment: @TerryCarmen: I don't think I have ever taken the view that it is wrong to ask for help. Can you indicate what remark I made that gave you that impression, so that I might clarify it? I believe the themes I have covered in this thread are (1) begging and (2) requests for free work (i.e. overly broad requests).

Comment: @halfer I was agreeing with you. Can't find your original comment right now.

Comment: Righto @TerryCarmen, thanks. I see what you mean now!

Answer (score 27):

Quite often, I suspect, users *do* Google their question in five seconds, and they get something that looks like this (click for full size):

[image: A man page in which all of the text is meaningless and confusing.]

Some open source documentation is really great, like PostgreSQL's docs, or Python's.  But a lot of products, both open source and closed source, have extremely dense and impenetrable documentation.  Sometimes, it's because the [feature is inherently hard to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39382501/1340389) or [profoundly different from a typical developer's mental model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/1340389).  And sometimes it's just because nobody is putting effort into documenting things in a clear and understandable fashion.  This should not be surprising, because writing good documentation is difficult, time consuming, and requires a lot of practice to do well.

On the other hand, many new developers have never learned how to read documentation.  I know reading documentation was never covered in my (absurdly expensive) computer science degree.  Documentation in general, and man pages in particular, are often written in a highly idiosyncratic style.  Reference documentation prefers to be comprehensive and unambiguous, but usually does a very poor job of answering *why* and *how* questions ("Why would I pass this flag?  How does the app choose which sprocket to frobnicate?").  It also tends to be terse and chronically short on examples, and what examples do exist tend to be small and artificial.

Some products offer tutorials, which are geared towards answering these questions, but:

- Many products do not have tutorials, or they have tutorials which are not very good.
- Third-party tutorials, while widely available, tend to be of variable and uneven quality.
- It takes a measure of self-awareness to admit you need a tutorial.
- It takes a substantially larger measure of self-awareness to admit you need a tutorial while you are actively trying to solve a specific technical problem.
- The developers of the tutorial will almost never foresee every possible use case of the product, so their "why" and "how" answers may be inapplicable or outdated.

Comment: *”admit you need a tutorial while you are actively trying to solve a specific technical problem”* — This.  It’s often very hard for many to slow down and take a step back to really understand their problem on a Friday afternoon at 4pm when you “just need to solve this one thing”…

Comment: Finally, a post that actually uses the correct alt text for an image, those posts are really becoming rare

Comment: And how is anyone going to learn how to read this if they never have to? We have a serious problem with only a relative minority of our industry actually knowing anything about it. Everybody else is just getting individual solutions by rote. What happens when all those capable of _reading_ have gone? This isn't a hateful rant, it's a genuine, practical problem.

Comment: Surely if the only way you could find an answer to your question is by diving into a tutorial, then by definition it can't be "Googled in 5 seconds"? Or are we defining "Google in 5 seconds" to mean "Enter a Google query in 5 seconds that will lead you to a website that will, in principle, help you solve your problem if you subsequently spend a couple of hours reading multiple pages of content?" Because if we mean the latter, then I don't see why that should be a reason not to ask a question, in order to create an internet where you can actually *find the answer in 5 seconds*, which is better.

Comment: *"But a lot of products... have extremely dense and impenetrable documentation"* - Maybe stackoverflow should add a dedicated area where they collect **good** documentation, that is maintained and voted upon by the community. Wait. What?

Comment: @MarkAmery: we *are* teaching the next generation to expect spoonfed answers, tailored to fit each individual case. "Reading the documentation" is quickly becoming a nerd activity. (Again.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't necessarily have answers, but I'm skeptical that our profession is going to sink into a swamp of ignorance that easily.  If it begins having negative economic effects, eventually hiring managers will work out that they need to adjust their hiring interviews.  Once reading documentation becomes mandatory for getting a job, people will learn to do it real fast.  OTOH, if this does not happen, then probably the problem isn't that catastrophic to begin with.

Comment: @Kevin Eventually may be too late! I can say with confidence that at least some niche markets are already showing signs of time-related brain drain that's causing genuine problems and I really believe it's only a matter of time before it becomes evident elsewhere. Heck, look through SO questions, it's already started!

Answer (score 11):

There are pretty good answers in this thread already, but I'd like to make a point others didn't explicitly mentioned.

Google may provide you with different results based on the language of your system (regardless if many or all keywords are in english) and allegedly based on your user profile.

Add this to knowing and picking up the right keywords in a field or topic. Doing so flows naturally to someone who closely knows the answer but is hard for someone who is lost.

And the result is: Maybe **you** can find the answer in 5 seconds in your computer. The asker may not get the answer you get even with the same query, and let alone formulate the precise query you can.

Comment: Google suggests alternate spellings, and even if you select the explicit "Search for *ur orignal txet*", it will happily insert random links *anyway*. So my guess is "More than a single page of hits – and that top 10 sure looks like a lot of reading. Nah, I'll tpyr ma qz into SO thne, typos and all. They'll correct it anyway."

Comment: @usr2564301 I used the word "spelling", which caused confusion. I changed it to "picking up". The reasoning is that *n* words may be synonyms for you, but in certain fields, a specific work is preferred and should be used for query. Incidentally, my poor choice of words and your interpretation almost exemplifies the concern I was thinking about.

Answer (score 4):

Let me tell you a tale of two errors and hopefully it illustrates what what Nicol is saying

## PHP's MySQL result error

[This is one of the top PHP tag duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-mysql-fetch-assoc-mysql-fetch-row-mysql-num-rows-etc) (you [don't have to take my word for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/2973202?sort=newest)). In 99% of all cases, you **can** Google this in 5 seconds because they all have the same cause: you forgot to check if your query was successful before you started pulling data sets out. Adding a basic error check, as well as outputting the error MySQL sent back, will easily set you on the right path. As the error message and cause are always the same, [Google can actually answer this](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqli+expects+parameter+1+to+be+mysqli_result+boolean+given&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and people mistakenly assume this is the case for all problems.

But then we come to...

## Java's Null Pointer Exception

[With 2M+ views and 8200+ links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), this might be the most duped question on SO. So, this should be just like the PHP error, right? A quick Google search for a NPE error and... [Yikes](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.lang.RuntimeException%3A+Unable+to+start+activity+ComponentInfo%7Bcom.journaldev.MapsInAction%2Fcom.journaldev.MapsInAction.MainActivity%7D%3A+java.lang.NullPointerException%3A+Attempt+to+invoke+virtual+method+%27com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker+com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions%29%27+on+a+null+object+reference&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Android results? Uhm... I'm a Java programmer! Give me Java results. Let's go ask on SO...

NPE is a term you might not have ever heard of and, more importantly, is not suggested by the ever-changing errors like `Unable to start activity on {some Java class here} on a null object reference`. Google runs off keywords and NPE is NOT a keyword Google inherently associates with these errors. Not helping things is the lack of the word `exception` (add that word in and [Google hits it square on](https://www.google.com/search?q=null+pointer+exception&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)). So, in this case, 5 seconds on Google might not give you anything remotely close to the answer that can help you. That's why we have dupehammers...

The important point is that Google is not a one-size-fits-all tool. As long as the problems are all the same and consistent in error message, Google does well. Throw a giant class tree in there and exclude an implied keyword, and there's no telling what you'll get.

Answer (score -2):

Just because you--who *know the answer*, can formulate a Google query that finds the answer you already know...does not mean the questioner (who basically by definition lacks that knowledge) could have formed the query as easily.

I'm more likely to get on people's cases when plugging in the exact title of their question comes up with the answer *on StackOverflow*.  But even then, you have to wonder: what if they started writing their question after a search, but revised the title at the last minute, due to an evolution of their understanding while writing the question?  It might not have occurred to them to search again, after being forced to articulate more precisely what they were asking about!

(I know I've certainly improved questions while writing them, and then neglected to turn around and start my search over from scratch, with all the new clarity.  But I've also abandoned questions due to figuring them out while writing them, or decided to turn it into a self-answered question.  Or just figured out the problem and modified it to be a [public service message with a question-like angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53154898/why-do-projects-use-the-i-include-switch-given-the-dangers).)

From where we stand, the "why do people do X" aspect of your question is probably "primarily opinion-based".  What's important is what makes the best outcome for the resource.  So whether the people asking redundant questions know it or not, if their question isn't addressed by a good link on StackOverflow, it might need a good answer here.  It's an editable and [purposefully archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19579/where-are-the-stack-exchange-data-dumps) site, which can improve with time.

As strange as it may seem, a lot of the Internet hasn't caught up with this basic idea--including your random phpBB or "Code Project" or even MSDN.  StackOverflow is not Google--link only answers are not considered answers--so to my mind, anything that meets the question criteria and not covered on StackOverflow proper is fair game for a new question here.  And having multiple phrasings of the same question that are pointed at duplicates is considered to be a good thing; a kind of organic search augmentation in its own right.

So added in with all the other factors of "y'know, Google is banned to a giant percentage of Earth's population", I think it's worth just doing the job here and answering questions like you would if a friend asked you.  *Pretend whoever is asking is your friend.*

Comment: And I would tell my friend (and I do, **very** often) 'hey X, here's what you can do when you have this issue. Google it using these terms.'

Comment: @Patrice If that's what you actually do while leaving the answer field entirely blank, I'm betting you don't have a lot of friends.

Comment: Wow, thx for the ad hominem there. No actually my friends are happy I treat them like adults and I help them find solutions to their own problems so they don't have to turn to me every time. You know, the whole 'teach a man to fish'.

Comment: @Patrice How swiftly you just jumped to offense underscores my point.  This is not a medium for things like "let me Google that for you" links--they were banned for a reason, and it's a good reason.  Saying it isn't much better.  Re-read what I wrote if you like, because that's what I have to say.

Answer (score -3):

People don't talk to Google the way they do to a person. They may have tried looking for a solution with Google, and then they gave up. *After* they gave up on Google, they went to StackOverflow and expressed their problem as a comprehensible question (hopefully). If they would take that question back to Google, they might find their answer in 5 seconds. But they've already given up on that avenue.

Answer (score -15):

This forum is not the only one that suffers from it.  I am a member of a fantastic Sous Vide cooking group.  Yet there are people on a daily basis who say "I just bought this meat.  Time and temperature" without obviously ever attempting to find it themselves.  And one guy that pissed me off got really defensive when I explained how offensive his question was.  (because he went a few steps beyond that simple question, demeaning all of us)

I believe it is just human nature.

Comment: - this is why I rarely give an answer any more.  It was a reasonable response.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: How was it "reasonable"? The question was "why do people do X?" Your response was "People do a lot of X elsewhere too". That doesn't explain *why* they do it, either here or there.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: Remember that downvotes on meta don't cost you rep.  I think people are mostly downvoting as an alternative to flagging "not an answer", not because they actually disagree with your claims.  Your edit helps a lot to explicitly make this an answer.  Anyway, interesting point that it's not just computers, but other technical subjects, where this happens.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: As exemplified by the fact that my answer has over 100 upvotes. Oh wait...

Comment: Calling Stack Overflow "a forum" surely attracted a lot of these downvotes.

Comment: @PeterCordes and SASS_Shooter: I wonder if it might have to do with the fact that googling for a solution, as straightforward as it might look like, involves actively surfing the web ([an outdated metaphor?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/408703/128913)). Posting a question is, in a way, a more passive thing to do: you just have to write what is in your mind and then wait for the notifications. Perhaps this also has something to do with the way people often uncritically believe all sorts of fake news when they could google a debunking in 5 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps read more about how [voting on meta is different](/q/365106) before you give up on this sub-site entirely. Even after edits, I'm thinking this would fit better as a comment than as an answer to the question at the top of this page.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter Re _"this is why I rarely give an answer any more"_, your point was fine, and would have been completely appropriate as a comment, but it really does not rise to the level of an answer. I suspect that may be the reason for down votes rather than the actual content.