# Answer a question... inside the question

Tags: discussion

In order to improve my question I always stated some approaches I've already tried to do right after the question description itself. Besides, I want to maintain my question - edit and add information.

It applies to the list of "possible" solutions as well. I.e. while reading answers/thinking about/discussing the problem in comments, new solutions appear and I tend to append it all into the list with corresponding information, drawbacks, etc. And if the question has not a single trivial answer, but rather multiple ways to try with its pros and cons, this list becomes large.

#### Q: Should I do this?

Here I see several problems:

1. By the time for some new reader of my question it may look like I have already answered my own question at the end of it. So the reader will just think - "all main possibilities already counted. I don't do plagiarism as well as don't want to waste my time devising some tricky-non-mentioned solution here". And will stop reading/participating.
2. At first I'm not accepting answers (only if my question is so simple). Because I see that the problem is not fully solved or there are some flaws in solution or simply want to involve more people into discussion. But when my list of solutions is large - I even *barely can* accept any. Because proposed answers contain different approaches (which might be quite good), but none of them is *full*. The full answer resides in the end of my question that I've collected...
3. But at the same time I'm even not sure that it's *complete* or in opposite - see that some small details still are not solved. But about these details nobody wants to think because of 1. And even if someone do and solve it - he would likely post an another clause 2. answer, i.e. without any other side cases.
4. The minority of the ones who answer tends to change (even just fix small typos; I'm not talking about edits that would make major improvements in their own answer). Because of: they don't track new details that appear in the question, or they don't track other answers/conversation in comments, or "there can be the *only one* correct answer - theirs", or they have already received my upvote (if the answer brings *any* useful information - this is the most likely case) and what for would they improve answer, or ... So am I - because, again, I've collected bunch of solutions - it would definitely be unfair to give all these answers some person only.
5. I can not even answer my own question in this state - because of "it would be definitely unfair ..." and even if I post it - it more likely would be copy-paste or the part of my question where I collected all this answers.
6. Even worse - I definitely cannot stop to do it (also I am asking right now - should I do so or not?). Because no one (very-very likely) besides me will collect **all** the information together (because 4 and because I'm a maintainer and asker - I'm most interested). Besides for newcomers it's much more convenient when all information about the question is collected in one place, not teared up in comments.

Comment: _Note:_ if here will be some answers - I won't add them to the question.)

Comment: You need to be careful that you don't change the context of the question in ways that would make any of the answers before your edit appear to answer something different than what you originally asked.

Comment: sometimes adding question with possible answers (to your question not what you have tried) change the original context of the question and not accepting the working answer which solves the originally asked issue should not be done

Comment: I'd say keep your question as clean as possible. So, it's a *question*. If you add more and more *answers* to it, it becomes very hard to read and understand in the future. Feel free to write a new *answer* to your own question, though - let's say, you had three already but neither one was *the* answer, yet an approach taken for each is what worked for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a person who mainly answers questions and also works in the review queues...

When I run into something like this I'm often not "happy". A list of what has already been tried, prior to asking, is important. Adding the information from answers, or "solutions" after-the-fact makes it hard to follow what the actual, original question is. And no marked answer is *definitely* a problem for me if the person asking the question indicates the problem is solved.

If an answer is incomplete, add a comment to give its author an opportunity to improve. That will also signal future readers as to the contribution's short-comings. But be sure what you're asking was *originally part of the question*. If you're running into additional problems that you're only seeing once you have the information in the answer then, correctly, you should be asking a *new* question.

As mentioned in a comment, if a combination of a number of contributed answers results in the final solution, you can post your own answer.

Which contribution to mark as "the" answer, especially when you post your own version, I'd say depends on weighing the amount of effort involved, as well as the quality of the individual contributions. For example:

- If your answer mostly contains the code from one other person, with
  small modifications to make it work for your situation, then that    other person's contribution should probably be marked as "the" answer. A more general approach *might* be more useful for future users than a very specific one.
- If another answer, on which your answer mainly bases, includes good explanatory text about solving the question and how the answer works, consider marking that as the Answer.
- If you decide to mark your own contribution as "the" answer, it would help to explain the reasoning: What you've taken from which other answers and why the combination is more useful in solving the problem.

Just some thoughts... :-)