# Can/Should I edit my question to an add answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers

When I found an answer to my question and it is more general and have couple of hints how to solve my problem should I edit the question and add a section where I describe the exact solution to my problem? Or is it better to just upvote the answer post and add my own answer based on that post.

I've seen it in a lot's of post and I found it useful in most cases.

Comment: No, don't edit an answer into the question, post a new answer instead. See [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in the help-center.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't answer the question in the question itself. It's better to add an actual answer, instead of editing it in.

Comment: I would edit that helpful answer and accepted ..

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387723/answer-a-question-inside-the-question/387792#387792

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self answers are allowed and encouraged as explained in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Always use the answer box to, well, answer the question. It doesn't matter that you have asked the question. Do make sure the answer is useful. So posting *I solved the issue* is **NOT** an answer.

Here on Meta we have a [self-answer](/questions/tagged/self-answer) with questions about (corner) cases and other things to know about self answering. The [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/self-answer/info) of that tag contains also some useful info this time.

Answer (score 5):

Never edit the question to include the answer, post a self answer instead. Questions that include an answer and that are not actually answered in the answer section can be closed as unclear what you're asking as you already have the answer. It creates more work for other people to fish and edit answers out of questions, so please do not do that.