# Posting my work as an answer or including it in the question if it is complete, but not necessarily the best answer?

Tags: discussion

The main point of my question is going to be:

**How to do X (time-)efficiently?**

There are many posts about X, but they are *not focusing on efficiency*.

I have a method to do X more efficiently than the already existing posts on how to do X. Should my post setup look like:

Q: How to do X (time-efficiently)? I have already tried: Y, is there a better method?

Or:

- Q: How to do X (time-efficiently)?
- A: Use method Y

..and wait if someone posts a better answer?

Comment: If you frame your post setup as "I'm looking for a solution faster/ more efficient than Y," then I (personally) don't see any issues here, since that detail would be integral to someone being able to answer the question to your liking. If you didn't include it, or included it as an answer, it's very possible to end up with answers that aren't faster than your *Y*, which appear to not be acceptable to you. In my understanding, you should always put enough detail in your questions to get exactly the answers you want to receive, no more, no less.

Comment: Do you need a solution to a problem or do you have one? If first, then one possibility is to add enough requirements into question to make Y solution invalid. If latter, than make sure to ask really good question. Without good question even very good answer simply doesn't make much sense. I've seen selfanswers on another SE site, where OP basically ask totally nonsense question just to make his "well though" answer the only one possible. Don't do that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all, if you have a different answer to an *existing question*, you shouldn't post a new question just to provide a new answer. Instead, you should post your answer to the original question.

Now, regarding the two options that you included in the post,  they're not applicable here but if you find yourself in a situation where you want to post a question that you have an answer to, **never add the answer into the question itself**. In that case, you can post the question and self-answer it (in a separate answer). See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

To answer your own question, you can either post the question first and then answer it in the same way you'd answer any other question or you can tick the CheckBox that says "Answer your own question" to submit both the question and the answer at the same time as shown below. The answer still goes to the answer box though.

[image: Answer your own question]

Comment: If the focus and goal of the new question is distinct from the old, in this case specifically searching for an efficient solution when previous question(s) have not, is a new question *still* unwarranted?

Comment: Well, I would say it depends. Normally, when someone posts a question, they're implicitly looking for an efficient solution and would probably pick the most efficient one unless there's a good reason not to. Note that I never said that posting a question _asking for_ a more efficient solution is unwarranted. If you _actually are_ looking for an answer, then it's fine to post a new question if you frame it right. It's only unwarranted (IMO) if you already have an answer, not looking for one.

Comment: That being said, I would say that if the new question discusses a different angle of the topic (e.g., "Why is method Y faster than X?"), then that's a different question indeed. But if you have a better answer to an existing question, why not answer _that_ question?

Comment: If the efficient solution is significantly more complicated (e.g. manually vectorized with SIMD for a specific ISA), or optimized for one area of the problem domain (e.g. large arrays with lots of duplicates), that can justify a separate question.  Or especially if it only works under limited conditions.  Make sure to link the other general-case question that includes simple answers.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like method Y is a viable and novel solution to do X, so I suggest posting it as an unaccepted answer and leaving a comment that you're looking for a more efficient solution.  Reasons:

- Helps other people having the same question -- they are more likely to read a question with an answer, and Y might be good enough for them.
- Helps other answerers notice what you've already done before providing their solution (especially if it's a long question). This includes answers that benchmark other answers, which are often helpful.
- Helps the site by providing a dupe target to other questions on how to do X.  "This question already has an answer here" -- would not be possible if you had not given Y as an answer, since Y doesn't exist elsewhere.

As a side benefit, you might get upvotes for having both a useful question and a useful answer.

On the other hand --
I would not post the work as an answer if it's not a viable solution.  For example, an inefficient algorithm that produces the desired output given a MVCE but is too expensive in practice for your use case.  An attempted solution could still be useful to include in the question to reproduce the desired results on the MVCE.