# Is it appropriate to question reviewers' decisions in comments elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I log in to find a comment on a question I'd asked [hectoring me for my review choice on a completely unrelated triage review](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50960339/2706826).

> Unrelated: in the edit queue, I came across a question that you voted
>   on in triage. You made the wrong choice there. Please: study the help
>   for triage really carefully, and avoid putting items into the edit
>   queue that don't belong there. Please understand that your votes have
>   consequences! This is the one I am talking about:
>   stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20889741

I find this behaviour bizarre. Surely whatever the vote given by a reviewer is their choice, and they can interpret things how they see fit without being criticised for it.

**Is this appropriate behaviour/use of comments?**

*For what it's worth, the question was asking for wide ranging help writing something, and rather than close, I'd downvoted and told them to edit it, which [I understand to be the most appropriate response to the long unresolved issue of what to do with code-writing questions and the lack of appropriate closure reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/2706826).*

Comment: Tangential note: voting to close that question as "too broad" would have been perfectly fine.

Comment: *" and told them to edit it"*. The Requires Edit button doesn't tell the author to edit their question. It means that the question should to be edited by other experienced SO members and thus put it in the Help & Improvement queue. If a question can only be edited by op, as in this case, Requires Edit is a bad choice.

Comment: What raises my eyebrow is that someone called Hsif out for his actions, yet ALL the reviewers said that there were no serious issues (one even said it looks ok!)

Comment: @Draco18s If you look at the comments on the referenced question, it appears that other reviewers were also called out for their votes, presumably by the same person.

Answer (score 15):

> Surely whatever the vote given by a reviewer is their choice, and they can interpret things how they see fit without being criticised for it.

Well, no, not at all, actually.

You're in /review to review *according to site rules, policies, and guidelines*. That means if you're in Triage and you see a post that needs to be closed until its author reworks it, you don't pick <kbd>Requires Editing</kbd> — you choose <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> and pick the appropriate flag reason from there. (In this specific case, flagging to close as Too Broad would have been reasonable, as most write-my-whole-program questions are Too Broad to be answered with any kind of thorough explanation.)

If you make mistakes in /review, you should expect that some of those mistakes will be criticized, and if you make too many mistakes these criticisms will get sharper, until (in the worst case) a ♦ mod cuts you off entirely. Reviewing needs to be done correctly.

Of course, there's certainly room for reasonable disagreement about the best way to handle a particular post, given a good knowledge of the site's rules. But ultimately, reviewers are expected to use their own judgement primarily to *carry out* the site's policies, not to impose their own completely different ones. Up- and down-votes are your own, as long as they're not cast fraudulently, and if you want to you can vote up every post with an ID that's divisible by 7 and vote down every post with an ID divisible by 9, and while folks may certainly suggest you vote more wisely, that's your call. (This is why up- and down-votes are private. Conversely, reviewing actions are not private at all.)

All that said, it's not generally a good idea to try to hash out reviewing behavior in post comments, unless the review involved posting a comment already. It's all too likely to cause confusion and irritation for the post author, and can easily cause unnecessary friction by airing dirty laundry, as well. (You can see both problems in this case.) Instead, a chat room should work, or for more serious cases of systemic bad judgement, simply flagging a ♦ mod to investigate and communicate with the erring user directly. (Using Meta to call a single user on the carpet is a bad idea as well, although sometimes it's the least worst option if the issue is really rather complicated and especially if it may span multiple users.)

Comment: What about posts with id's that are visible by both 9 and 7? Like: 63, 126, 189, 252, 315, 378, 441, 504, 567, 630, 693, 756, 819, 882, 945, 1008, 1071, 1134, 1197, 1260, 1323, 1386, 1449, 1512, 1575, 1638, 1701, 1764, 1827, 1890, 1953, 2016, 2079, 2142, 2205, 2268, 2331, 2394, 2457, 2520, 2583, 2646, 2709, 2772, 2835, 2898, 2961, 3024, 3087, 3150, 3213, 3276, 3339, 3402, 3465, 3528, 3591, 3654, 3717, 3780, 3843, 3906, 3969, 4032, 4095, 4158, 4221, 4284, 4347, 4410, 4473, 4536, 4599, 4662, 4725, 4788, 4851, 4914, 4977, 5040, 5103, 5166, 5229, 5292, 5355, 5418, 5481, 5544, 5607, 5670, 5733, etc

Comment: @TinyGiant: Presumably the hypothetical bad voter would side-vote, close-vote, favorite, share, or bookmark them. Also, the point was for it to be ridiculous hyperbole.

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Or grab a sock puppet and cast one up and one down.

Comment: @TinyGiant: you should say "**di**visible", not "visible"

Comment: @Michael that would be divisive though. I thought we were trying to be inclusive. (I tried, that's the best I could come up with)

Answer (score 6):

Doesn't looks like appropriate use of comments to me. I'd flag them as no longer needed, as they are off-topic on the main site.

The root cause appears to be that GhostCat looked at the Help & Improvement review queue. I think that was an honest mistake on their part, and hope it won't be repeated.

Comment: +1 for accurate and sympathetic root cause analysis.

Comment: I personally wouldn't object to users doing this in isolated cases so long as they don't harass the reviewers about it, and if they continue their pattern of poor reviews then that's when a flag would be more warranted. These comments *are* still subject to deletion as no longer needed when enough time has passed.