# Failed audit. Why wasn't a minimal, complete, and verifiable (MCV) example needed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits

I've just failed this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26156837) in Triage having flagged it as "Needs for details", but the correct answer was "Looks OK" instead.

I'm not disputing it, just trying to understand.

I thought that an acceptable question must meet the [SO questions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular to show some effort in trying to solve the problem (I've found a lot of comments around complaining about people asking questions like "please provide the code to do this or that")

Sincerely, I believed this was the case, or at least it should have been closed and moved to math.stackexchange.com (since it seems a theoretical and generic question about time complexity), but I didn't find this particular site in the options.

Could anyone clarify what should be the correct decision drivers in cases like this one? When is no effort in trying to solve the issue ok?

Comment: That's what happens when people don't downvote. It won't appear in audits again, now that it's been downvoted and closed.

Comment: "_I thought that an acceptable question must meet the SO questions guidelines and in particular to show some effort in trying to solve the problem_". [No](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/479156).

Comment: The linked question answers that: questions for audits are automatically selected based on their overall reception.