# Add new closing option "Shows little or no effort"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Everyday, more and more questions are posted that are simply variances of "do my job for me while I go have a beer". These questions show little or no effort on the OPs' part, not even to the extent of a simple Google search. Some of them get closed or downvoted, others are answered by responders merely looking to score some points. In the end, this takes time and attention away from the questions that have been posted after the OP has exhausted all options.

Can we add a closing option "Shows little or no effort"? Optionally, if multiple questions from the same account have been closed with "Shows little or no effort" with a certain period (like a month), ban them temporarily.

**Why shouldn't this question be closed as duplicate** to [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/839733)

1. That post was from 6 years ago, and the number of zero-effort questions has exploded since then. Decisions change with time. Women weren't allowed to vote at one time, and that was normal; it's not anymore.
2. None of the reasons listed there are logical, only the poster's personal opinion in 2014. "*the newcomers don't even realize something is bad about their question*" is the lamest excuse there can ever be. Do you get a pass for committing a crime the first time for being a newcomer to the crime world?

Comment: There are some questions that show no effort that are still useful references for others to look up later. Granted, these are far outweighed by the hordes of assignment dumps that will *not* be useful to anyone in the future, but lack of effort alone isn't a good enough reason to close IMO.

Comment: Lack of effort from the OP is not a close reason at all. There may be other reasons to close a post, of course. But if the OP posts an on-topic question without putting in any effort, and goes off for a beer, that's perfectly fine. You can down-vote the question if you don't like the OP's lack of effort.

Comment: @cigien You missed the point I already addressed in my post. Having to come across these questions and taking the time to downvote them is a waste. These questions shouldn’t exist.

Comment: So you're saying that if a question "shows little or no effort" it's automatically not fit, or valuable for SO?

Comment: @cigien _So you're saying that if a question "shows little or no effort" it's automatically not fit_. Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. How are such question remotely helpful to anyone? Are people whose paychecks or degrees depend entirely on SO and not on their meri allowed to lean on others forever?

Comment: There is a strong correlation between no-effort questions and utterly useless questions, but it's not 1:1. Some are useful.

Comment: @AndrewT. That post was from 6 years ago, and the number of zero-effort questions have exploded since then. Also, none of the reasons listed there are logical, it's just what the poster came up with. _because the newcomers don't even realize something is bad about their question._ is the lamest excuse there can ever be. Do you get a pass for committing a crime the first time for being a newcomer to the crime world?

Comment: @CertainPerformance There's no good measure for usefulness, but lack of effort can be clearly established.

Comment: Number of upvotes is a pretty good indicator of how many users found it useful. There are many no-effort questions with a high positive score (mostly old questions, but some new questions too).

Comment: Personally I am a big believer in trial by fire. Though effort is subject, terrible low qualitive uncommunicative attempts at a free lunch for the most minimal amount of work, stand out. Such questions are likely not going to be fixed to a standard that can be answered. The ops general don't care one way or another, its just school work anyway. If i was up to me, we would have a little button that could give electric shocks to question askers. *not serious*

Comment: Up or down votes are mostly subjective.

Comment: "*There's no good measure for usefulness, but lack of effort can be clearly established.*" That sounds like you want to make the curators' lives easier, at the expense of potentially closing some useful questions. I'm not sure I like those priorities.

Comment: @cigien if you take this too far the other way, you lose the answering talent. There is no value in it. There needs to be a balance

Comment: @cigien I understand SO wants to project a "welcoming environment for homies", but not everyone deserves a welcome.

Comment: I'm not remotely concerned with being welcoming to the OP. In fact, I don't care about the OP at all, in any way. My only concern is with the quality of the question, and how likely it is to generate answers that are useful to programmers. I want close reasons to reflect that. And that's a big problem with the "lacks effort" close reason: it focuses on the OP instead of the post.

Comment: The post isn't a separate entity from the OP. The personality of OP is squarely reflected in the post.

Comment: That is true. And you're proposing that we account for the OP's personality even more, by enshrining an aspect of it in a close reason? That seems to be the wrong direction to head.

Comment: @The General: It would be more efficient to raise the barrier to entry just a tiny, tiny little bit. If people are willing to spend [6-8 months of their lives trying to get into FAANG companues ](https://daedtech.com/deploying-guerrilla-tactics-combat-stupid-tech-interviews/), surely we could demand a little bit more.

Comment: @PeterMortensen agreed. Though in all reality, SO is a commercial entity, there is not much we can do, and very few suggestions get even considered these days. Downvote and move on.

Comment: Another, huge issue is that many users have no idea what effort to apply.  Profs/TA issue homework without mentioning debugging/logging at all:((

Comment: If this reason gets added are you going use that reason in your close votes instead of your downvotes?

Comment: This is approaching the problem from a less than efficient solution. Rather than eliminating poor questions we should be eliminating the askers. This will ensure their future compliance.