Help me improve my question
I asked this question yesterday
Create two barplots for categorical variables having different numbers of classes
It didn't get much attention, except for a downvote. Can you help me improve it? Should I split in two questions, one for each barplot? It seems a bit wasteful to me, since the two plots are very similar, thus I'd end up asking two very similar questions. But if this is the expected behavior on SO, I'll do it.

You could tag the question with whatever software you are using to create the charts (matplotlib?)

And explain what it is that is causing difficulty - do you know how to create a barchart at all (I imagine this has been asked before)?  Is there something specific about your problem not covered by introductions / tutorials? Show some code that illustrates the issue.

a picture of what you want could enhance the textual description. that's all I can think of as a non-SME who gave a brief skim

I appreciate the attitude of aiming for feedback for improvement. Most of the posts I see here on meta are just arguing why their posts do not deserve the downvotes and being reluctant to constructive critics.

Firstly, you explicitly ask two separate questions about two different plots. That's not really allowed, you'd best focus on one plot, then see if you can apply the principles learned in the answer and make the second one yourself.
Secondly, your question does not demonstrate any research effort. You'd do better to read about creating bar plots, pick a plotting library, make an attempt, and ask when you get stuck. That makes the downvote tooltip part "does not show any research effort" apply.
Thirdly, this is a very simple and localized problem. It is hard to see how an answer would be of value to future readers; they'd likely get sufficient information in the docs of their plotting library, or in a plot gallery that includes code. That makes the downvote tooltip part "not useful" apply.
As for how to improve this question: start by narrowly defining the question (so 1 plot), scrap all the parts about categories sometimes being long and sometimes being a number or explain how that is relevant, then make a genuine attempt, doing sufficient research each time you get stuck when making that attempt.
The odds of you solving the problem while making that genuine attempt are probably large.

implementation effort is not part of "research", nor is it required. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/11107541

@starball I don't say it does. Implementation effort forces you to do research, though, and helps in both reporting research effort, trivial vs nontrivial stuff (e.g. the long names), and narrow down the question (e.g. which plotting library, since approaches in different plotting libraries are mostly unrelated). That makes it an easy way to improve the question. Asking a well-defined and well researched question without implementation effort is hard.

@starball Research Effort is not just limited to closing as a duplicate.

Implementation effort could be a set of UML diagrams of course, but... who does that nowadays. most of us lesser mortals need something tangible before we can see the how and why behind a problem which can lead to a Stack Overflow compatible question, be it a design or an actual attempt to implement code. You need to be pretty masterful to see it all inside your head and be able to distil a valid question from that.
