Is it okay to ask questions about specific APIs with explanation?
My question that I'm trying to find an answer to is, in a broad sense, How to use Google Drive/Form's authentication process. I would provide more details such as what I'm trying to do, what I have so far, and where I'm stuck after reading the docs and asking another community (outside of Stack Exchange) about how to do a certain task. Are these questions allowed? If not, is there another Stack Exchange that is more appropriate for these questions, or is it that these questions should not be asked in any of them?

If your question is programmatical in nature, then yes, it's on-topic here. How to use an API, from a program you're writing, would be on topic, but you'd certainly need to show what you've done and where you got stuck; how to use APIs (in general) is a "solved" problem, and they'll be plenty of duplicates for different languages.

I second what @ThomA says above, although I'd add that if the question is programmatical in nature, then it may be on topic, providing that it fits the other criteria for being on-topic, including and especially that it is focused enough. This is often achieved by doing extensive research prior to asking, showing the pertinent findings from that research in the question and perhaps by attempting a solution prior and showing that attempt in the question (although an attempt is not always necessary).

I'm kind of sketchy on what "Google Drive/Form's authentication process" is though. Wouldn't that actually be the Google OpenID flow and not something really specific to the services?

@Gimby The OP should ask about [tag:google-oauth] and perhaps about [tag:google-cloud-platform]

It is not my understanding that showing what one tried and where one got stuck is "certainly needed" for a "how do I X" question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/11107541

To summarize the comments and the SO-help-center, ask yourself:

Is my question programmatical in nature?

Is my question specific?

Will my question lead to an objective answer?


If you can answer all these with yes, then it fits here.
