# Question asking for you to write code

Tags: support, flags

How should I flag a question that is just asking you to write code?
I mean a question in what the OP didn't write any code yet and just drops the problem in the hope that people will just answer the question with the code he needs.

Example: [Transfer from sql server to mysql using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997542/transfer-from-sql-server-to-mysql-using-php)
In this example the OP just wants people from SO to write the whole statement for him without him trying something to solve the problem himself before.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That particular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997542/transfer-from-sql-server-to-mysql-using-php) could be flagged/closed as `Too Broad` because there could potentially be several different ways that this could be solved.

Determining the correct flag or close reason will always vary from question to question but in general if the user fails to include any code and it is a *gimme da codez* question, then I would think these fall into a `Too Broad` category and should be flagged/closed as such.

Comment: I completely agree, though I always like to add that commenting and/or downvoting in these situations is completely acceptable also. I know that wasn't the question but I think commenting is understated when taking other actions, especially with new users.

Comment: @codeMagic I agree with you, if you can **constructively** tell the OP how to fix the question, then commenting is helpful.

Comment: Both thank you for your reply. @codeMagic commenting was indeed not part of the question but I think that mistake is mine, I should have asked what steps to take when something like that happend instead of what flag should I raise. I now understand what to do, thank you both.

Comment: Hey @bluefeet , sometimes people just add a question with a image and ask the code for how to do it. I simply flag as "Questions asking to recommend step-by-step, tutorial, etc". What should I tag them? Or couldn't be there an option: "Questions asking us to write code are considered bad behaviour since that's not the point of Stack Overflow"  or something more elaborated.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Based on your description, that sounds like a textbook - too broad close reason.  I'd recommend reading [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason) about users asking others to do their work.

Comment: `Too Broad` is now called `Needs more focus` (under `needs improvement`).