# Dealing with a question that is asking for code

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I've come across [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324447/linq-iqueryable-query-to-get-balance-at-run-time-with-take-and-skip-functionalit), which seems to just be asking for someone to write a C# equivalent of some SQL for them.

I wanted to vote to close, but couldn't find anything in the close reasons that felt appropriate.  So I decided to check meta, to see if there was a documented precedent, and found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277139/question-asking-for-you-to-write-code).

The answer suggests using "too broad" in the OP's specific scenario, but that doesn't feel applicable, as this question isn't broad.  The answer also correctly states that all questions will be different, and warrant their own reasons.

- Are these kinds of question allowed on Stack Overflow? (It was my belief that they weren't)
- If they aren't allowed, why isn't there an appropriate flag for them? (I'm sure there used to be a "minimum effort" flag, or a "give me teh codez" flag)
- Do we need a new flag reason with an easy catch all for these?
- Is there another mechanism other than close that we should be using (Shog9 alludes to something [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308842/39277), but fails to elaborate)

I understand that close reasons need to be terse, but it seems that we've got a hole that a common class of question isn't addressed by.

In the end, I decided to close with "other" as a reason, although I feel there should be a better option.

Comment: They are allowed, so there's no close reason appropriate for them. I find it terribly frustrating, but whatever, that's the way it goes...

Comment: "Downvote and move on" is standard recommendation for no effort questions... Since current guidance on "effort" are not clear I'd shorten it to "Move on"... ("move on" is really just trolling - you are essentially asking people who don't know rules to dump some random suggestions as answers... not necessarily without entertaining value :) )

Comment: I'm perplexed as to why 2 people have downvoted my question.  On meta, down voting is used to express disagreement with the post, but my post doesn't posit anything.  It's merely asking about policy, there's nothing in it to disagree with.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, thanks!  Do you have any citations to back this up?  I've been searching, but cannot find anything.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to write an answer, as your comment does attempt to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

> Please edit the question to limit it to a **specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer**. [...]

Too broad should be fine depending on your interpretation of it.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") **must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.**

Alternatively, `Off-topic -> Questions seeking debugging [...]` is another viable contender, again, depending on your interpretation.

If all else fails, an "other" flag can be used as you have done so already.