# Which flag should I use to flag questions that give a task?

Tags: support, flags, bad-questions

I oftenly face questions that ask to perform a specific task, instead of answering a more general question about their problem, for example:

> I need to animate a textblock, start from left side of screen and stop
>   for 2 second in center of screen, then continue.
>
> All this should be done programmatically and with **one storyboard.**

or

> I need *(blah blah blah...)*.

What type of flag will be best to use to mark these posts?

Comment: Use "Too broad" which says *Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: @PaulCrovella: Lack of a question-mark does not neccessarily mean it's not a valid SO question. Though that makes it very likely.

Comment: see also: [Should we add a “Do my work for me” close reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)