# What happened to the "Do it for me" close reason?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, close-reasons

A while ago, I remember there being a "Do it for me" close reason, which I would guess was due to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630).

I was going through the Close Vote queue on Stack Overflow, and I noticed a lot of questions that were asking things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7345482):

> How would you develop an optimal Algorithm to convert an Incidence Matrix to Adjacency List ?

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7345408):

> I am take web programming class and really confused about this part of the introduction my teacher gave about asp.net. It would be a huge favor if someone could explain in simple English what the following lines mean:
>
> The code-behind class files for all Web Forms pages in a project are compiled into the project dynamic-link library (.dll) file. The .aspx page file is also compiled, but somewhat differently. The first time a user browses to the.aspx page, ASP.NET automatically generates a .NET class file that represents the page, and compiles it to a second .dll file. The generated class for the .aspx page inherits from the code-behind class that was compiled into the project .dll file

It seems like whenever reviewers see a "Do it for me" question, they choose to close it as "too broad", or "unclear what you're asking", even if those reasons do not fit the question.

Why was the "Do it for me" close reason removed? Did people misuse it?

**EDIT**: This question isn't about an alternative, although one would be nice. The question is *WHY* it was removed? Was it abused? What causes the removal of close vote reasons like this, which seem to be helpful?

**EDIT 2**: It appears that I have schizophrenia - there was never a "do it for me" close reason

Comment: I'm guessing that it went to the same place as 'minimal understanding'.

Comment: Related on Meta.SE: [What happened to the "you're just lazy" close vote reason?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216491)

Comment: Unless you were the subject of an obscure A-B close reason test, you're misremembering. The close reason hasn't been removed, because it was never introduced. Do you remember the exact text of the close reason you're thinking of?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I remember it was a 1-line message with a some symbol like this: <(((((

Comment: @Jojodmo "Do X for me" is/was **never** a close reason.  There was a "minimal understanding" close reason that was removed because it was over used and abused.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I specifically remember a close reason that contained "Do it for me" in the message, and it was in the off-topic section. It was removed about 2 months ago, and was added about 4 months ago. I'm pretty sure the title of it was: **This is a do it for me question <((((()**. I completely remember it... Either that or I may be getting schizophrenia... Is there any way to view the removed close reasons on data.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You saw someone write that close reason in, then. The last option in "off topic" is a custom reason. Once someone makes an entry for a particular question, the reason is saved for other voters to select it directly _on that question_. I don't believe these reasons go into the public data dump.

Comment: @JoshCaswell That may be it, I saw a lot of posts with that reason as an option though. Anyways, back on-topic...

Comment: Apparently you keep running into questions that the same person has voted to close, then. This has never been an official close reason. Had it been, it would have included a line or two of descriptive text, and omitted the fish bones or whatever it is.

Answer (score 4):

"Do it for me" falls under a few different close reasons.

- Too Broad: If there are to many possible ways to do something, the question is to broad. "How do you develop an optimal algorithm..." sounds very broad to me.
- Primarily opinion based: If the question is going to generate answers that are more focused on the opinion of the answers rather than facts, then it's not a good question either. "How do you develop an optimal algorithm..." sounds like multiple people with experience in the area could easily argue about what is and is not optimal.
- Off Topic->Why isn't this code working: If the user provides some code and is asking for debugging help without any further information, the question is off topic. Since the entire question is "How do I develop an optimal algorithm...", this close reason doesn't apply. The user isn't even to the point of asking about code yet.

---

The second question you provide would fall under either "Unclear"/"Too Broad" or the "Why isn't this code working". The user is asking about compiled code, but provides none for us to look at. They also ask for a detailed explanation of how a technology works - too broad.

Personally, I'd choose "unclear" over "Why isn't this code working", because the user hasn't provided code. I tend to utilize the second when the user provide a huge snippet of code and says something like "Why isn't this working?" or "I get an error" and provides no further information.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" is my fav.  "I need to do X" "That's great, but it's unclear what your problem is. Go do X and come back if you have any problems with specific implementation details."