# Which questions are ok to ask without code?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

So imagine someone created a language called it "X" and disappeared away, then i found it, started working with it, then an idea came to my mind

> How can i do **y** in **X Language**?

As you can see i didn't provided any code, because there are no examples for it. Does it okay or should i ask it like

> How can i do **y** in **X Language**, we usually do like this in **Python**

```
Some code here.
```

They both looks ok, but now take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529270/how-to-validate-whether-the-given-email-address-belongs-to-a-corporate-personal?noredirect=1#comment112340035_63529270)

[image]

Then the question gets flagged because someone with high reputation thinks the problem is **arbitrary**

[image]

**Then the user posts a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63530314/how-to-validate-whether-the-given-email-address-belongs-to-a-corporate-personal) including the more details(because that's what flag says), it also gets closed because it's opinion based?** These are some comments:

> It needs to be about programming. Right now your question is not about programming,

> I deleted the language tag because there is nothing Python-specific in your posting. You have posted no code, as you haven't defined your problem requirements. "Figure out what I want and give me a coded solution" is far outside the bounds of Stack Overflow's stated purpose.

Summary of this comment:

The OP added Python when he creating the post, but some other user comes and deletes the tag, then flags it, says this. But the OP, does not asking for a coded solution or any code, just asking for how other dev's usually handles this, also there are some users waiting for the post reopen,

[image]

but OP spended last three hours to explain **this is maybe you won't need but i need this but it doesn't makes this arbitrary**,still no progress, This is really exhausting, everyone says it's "arbitrary" or "my friend is self-employed he uses gmail is it considered as corporate mail?" etc. But no one shows me a way or redirects me to any url with "this could be useful" eg ,that's the funny part, no one knows how to do it,but they keep closing this with just their **opinions**, That doesn't changes the fact that i still need an answer even the question is **arbitrary** for them, how can i reformat the question to get an answer? Am i asking the question in a wrong way or their approach is high-handed?

Comment: Related: [Is there really a universal code requirement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291399/1595451)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1425/ is an explanation of why your questions are getting closed. The fact you can't even reasonably define what you want to achieve should hinted to you that it is way too broad for SO to ask how to "approve" email to be belonging to real user...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's not about approving the mail, already got that part, i wanted to check a mail whether belongs to personal/corporate mail.

Comment: You'll need to create and keep, or find a list of all public providers, that is the _only_ solution. Personal/corporate addresses could be _anything_. You say that that doesn't handle "all cases", but you don't explain how not, what cases doesn't it work for?

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci the fact you have a problem and did some research on it *does not* make a problem well understood and solvable in scope that *is defined in SO*. I.e. there are years of research on "traveling salesmen" problem but it does not mean asking question on SO how to solve it and showing all those years of research will make it answerable on SO. Same for "how to identify that email belongs to X" problems - large teams in multiple companies devote insane amount of time to solving that, even if you show half of such research it will not become narrow enough for SO.

Comment: You are right @AlexeiLevenkov i agree that, the only part that i'm sad about, it's getting closed because someone thinks it's arbitrary, but also as i posted in the question, someone waiting for the question to reopen to provide an answer but he cant because some high-handed guys thinks the question is arbitrary for them.

Comment: Disregard the word *arbitrary* and there is still nothing there that makes the question on topic based on SO guidelines. SO isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: If you read the question, you can see that i mentioned an answer for that @charlietfl I'm not asking for an COMPLETE CODE, just asking for a common approach.

Comment: I understand that you need on answer on researching this but you will need to find another forum to do it. Many many "how to" questions get closed here every day for being off topic.

Comment: @charlietfl Since i want to implement the approach to my backend with Python, can you explain why it's off-topic?

Comment: @Nick there is a lot of temporary mail providers, the point is i cannot blacklist all of them with adding each by each, see a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976706/how-to-block-disposable-email-addresses-in-your-websites-registration-form) example like this

Comment: Yes, there are a lot, and there's always new ones, and there's also no way to identify the spam ones from new legitimate ones, which is why a blacklist is the only real option. And yes that involves keeping the blacklist up to date. So.... Good luck

Comment: Thanks @Nick you are the only one to provide an answer over +30 comments

Comment: "Then the user posts a new question including the more details(because that's what flag says)" - **It actually says to edit the original question.**  Why are you talking in the third person?  The question that was closed was your own question, and then you submitted a new question (you attempted to resolve the problems) instead of editing the first question.

Comment: @SecurityHound Why is it saying _Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one._ , also the first question had 2 delete votes when i posted the second one then i just commented the new question to reach out the guy who wants to answer the question.

Comment: Questions that are closed should be edited to be within scope instead of resubmitted and creating two questions (admittedly one of those questions will be deleted).  However, the message in your screenshot, indicates the question should be edited.  Just because a user can answer a question, doesn’t mean they should answer that question, if the question has been closed as being out of scope.  If that user wanted to answer the question, they could flag the question, and the community would vote to reopen it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is not that you're asking a question about an obscure programming language, or that people don't like what you're trying to build. Both are not valid close reasons.

The point is that you're basically asking *"How do I detect domains where it is trivial to create a new, free email address?"* - and that's way too broad. Also, it has been asked dozens of times, there are online services you can pay to detect this, some lists of well known free domains circulate the web which you could download and use as a blocklist, and so on.

So: your questions were not down- and closevoted because the lack of code, but because the lack of research.

Comment: Every question has an answer on web, also afaik it's ok to ask [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) that is on-topic and not duplicate, i know that i can use some API to detect dispose mail services, the main point about this, like you pointed in the questions, they are just closing it because they don't like what i'm building

Comment: _So: your questions were not down- and closevoted because the lack of code, but because the lack of research._ so again what is the point of stackoverflow then when there is no answer about this this and i'm just expecting a common approach like "we usually use an api service, because it's hard to keep blacklists updated... etc"

Answer (score -1):

The questions that are okay to ask without code are questions that ***include detail of their problem***.

Here are the points the question needs to address:

- Include enough detail (the more the better!)
- Make the question on-topic for StackOverflow
- Have the question be ***very*** specific
- Lastly, it proves that the OP gave an attempt, and that they did research

As long as the question passes these points, it doesn't matter if it has any code.

As a moderator once said in a chatroom:

> I'm starting to become concerned that this room is somehow promoting the idea that all questions need to have an MCVE and/or that debugging questions are the only questions that are on-topic for Stack Overflow. That is not only wrong, it's horribly wrong, dangerously wrong. So I step in and correct this misconception as often as I can.

So just address all the points, read up as much as you can about asking a question (see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for starters if you haven't already).

Comment: As i mentioned in the question i did my research and couldn't find anything how you can include detail of when there is no other examples?

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci Then link the sites which you went to research to, and explain why it didn't help.

Comment: How to link a website when there is no website talks about this topic.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci Then put that in your question. I wouldn't close it if that were the case. Just make sure your question passes all the other points. Make sure it is on topic, for instance.

Comment: If you don't someone other would close that, because in these days, they immediately flag the questions that doesn't have code samples, but i usually look throught [Jon Skeet's writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) when asking a question, but in this case, it's independent from the python version, or libraries will use or really doesn't dependant to anything else than Python.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci Yes, I know. That's why I put the quote from the moderator. It's a big misconception because there are many people who have the same type of question as you get downvoted and their questions closed. So what I do is put a comment telling people not to close, or I request other people to reopen the question.

Comment: Exactly, the moderators quote is on point,  The sad part about commenting the both questions get closed before i drop a single comment.

Comment: You've basically included "Make the question on-topic for StackOverflow" as an item in your list of how to make it on-topic?!?