# Flood of zero effort questions

Tags: discussion

When I search new questions, most of the unanswered ones are not even questions at all. They fit into one of two basic patterns:

1. "Debug this for me"

What's annoying with these is that the user usually did not fail at debugging and now needs help. No, the user didn't even try debugging. But at least these questions are still marginally better than my favourite:

2. "Do my assignment for me"

Because of the reputation system, a new user might be inclined to answer these terrible non-questions in order to earn reputation and unlock privileges.

Why does StackOverflow encourage such behaviour, rather than discouraging it?

Comment: Just make sure you get 125 rep so you can downvote those questions. And you flag every single post that fall in those categories I assume?

Comment: *"Why is it that StackOverflow encourages such behaviour"* - **does** SO encourage such behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps it is that SO is doing such a good job discouraging low-effort posts that you don't even *see* the huge swathes that get removed because they're already gone. You only see the ones that haven't been handled yet. And there is an **awful lot** of these flooding in every minute of the day.

Comment: Also, don't conflate "enable" with "encourage". The ability to ask questions is given to anyone who signs up with an account, but it doesn't actively tell them to go forth and post crap.

Comment: I wish there was a flag category for this type of question that is "Write the code for me that does this" flag. I flag them and usually put them under "too broad"  But they are so common and so specific that it seems they could warrant their own category.

Comment: @ValAsensio - We do have a "Not an Answer" flag. It does seem like it would be useful to have a "Not a Question" flag as well. Perhaps they're worried people will abuse it by doing things like flagging anything without a question mark even though the problem statement is clear.

Comment: You're in for a shock when you gain >10K. Then you actually get to *see* a large part of the low quality that was deleted – and, like Superman with his X-ray vision, at times you'll wish you could turn it off.

Comment: You missed out 'Please explain this code to me', AKA 'I copied it from another student but I cannot make it work and my prof will ask me how it is supposed to work.  I will be unable to answer and get a fail grade'.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: "does SO encourage such behaviour?" Yes it does. If it were not for the way privileges are granted through reputation, virtually no one would answer any of these questions. Then they would also be much less common. But as it is now, a newbie might answer one of these in hopes to get +20 reputation in order to get the right to write comments. This then spawns 5 new stupid questions as the guy who got the answer tells his classmates how well posting the assignment at SO worked.

Comment: @michael_0815 but without that system, would anyone answer the *other* questions? I agree that low quality questions are a problem, but do you have any concrete suggestions for changes? SO is in the privileged position of having problems *caused by its success*!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: concrete suggestion: Most importantly make "post a comment" available from the beginning. Not being able to write comments is just stupid. That change alone would sweep away a lot of the pressure currently encouraging newbies to write "answers" no matter how shitty the question.

Comment: @michael_0815 that limit is there to prevent spam, otherwise there would be a whole lot more crap comments to moderate. 15 points isn't that hard to get.

Comment: @michael_0815 *50 points

Comment: Why is this question closed as "no longer reproducible"? Has the "flood of zero effort questions" somehow gone away?

Comment: @user000001  That is strange indeed, but maybe there were other close reasons voted. Only the majority one is displayed AFAIK. Your question is in the reopen queue as I write this. Stiil, it should be closed as a duplicate, there are [many questions here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+effort) about this issue, e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason

Answer (score 35):

It is all your fault. And mine as well. We are not doing enough to keep the rubbish out.

When you reached the [reputation of 15](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) you earned the privilege to flag posts for moderation attention.

Looking at your profile I see that you have 0 helpful flags. That is a problem, please do better.

[image: 0 helpful flags]

If you gain more reputation you get the privilege to [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) which helps to signal to the OP's that there is something wrong with their posts.

I'm not sure why you talk about Stack Overflow as if you're not part of it. The site is mainly driven by community moderation, that includes you and me. To battle the incoming flood of low quality, zero-effort questions we all need to moderate that stream.

My point is that the close vote queue would be zero, the Help and Improvement queue would be a nice place to help out, questions that don't meet our current standards would be gone much sooner if everybody that has some form of moderation privilege would use them to their full extent every day.

Personally I can do much better in down voting and flagging. I'm not a great editor either. But I do use all my close votes almost every day.

The flood is a problem but it is not someone's problem, it is our problem, your problem and my problem. I'll do my part ...

Comment: While you have a valid point about me not flagging stuff, I also fell that the fact that there is not even an appropriate reason to flag a "do my assignment for me" question reinforces my notion that the system does not discourage these questions. "Too broad" is clearly not meant for that and more often than not plain wrong as the assignment can very well be rather specific.

Comment: Don't take my post to personal. The exact flag reason is not so important. For low quality too broad or unclear would both fly. Having more reasons would only increase the flag-paralysis...

Comment: @rene You have some good points in your answer, but a main problem is, that the flood of VLQ is getting bigger and bigger, but we have still the same small tools to handle them.

Comment: @Rizier123 I know but I'm not sure if or how the (small) tools contribute to the problem. Maybe we need less tools, less flags, and less queues. On the other hand I personally feel I can handle more load/ willing to  accept more responsibility / want to be able to give more focus to my moderation activities. If a change in tooling brings more eyes/hands in the moderation process I'm in favor. So far I only managed to make an appeal to people in the hope to make them realize we need all hands on deck...

Comment: @rene I appreciate your response here. So you are advising to flag low quality posts for moderator intervention? What do you suggest giving as the reason?

Comment: @helgatheviking you have to provide context, here is an example of a custom reason I used on a specific answer: *This answer really isn't an answer. It copies the proposed solution and states "it didn't work for me" so it is more a bug report. This OP should have down voted the other answers but probably couldn't at the time posted. Please remove this bug report, no value will be lost*. So if you expect that the VLQ/NAA  flag needs context to be judged correctly, use a custom flag, provide the context needed and propose an action. So I might suggest converting to a comment for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rene. Specifically I am asking about a custom reason  for flagging low quality questions as there is no existing flag for that.

Comment: @helgatheviking maybe share an example of a low quality question that you would like to flag? Because if a question is not all gibberish no flags should be used, a down vote or close vote would do.

Comment: @rene, well they are not gibberish, so they don't merit flags for that.  But they fall into the category of this question's original premise...zero effort or "do my work for me".  I do down vote and close vote those. I just re-read the "too broad" close description, and it does include questions whose answers "would be too long for this format", which seems like the best choice for questions expecting free work. Even though, if the question showed any effort, it might be exactly the type of complex and interesting question I would like to help with.