# Lack of interesting questions / flood of "do it for me" questions

Tags: discussion

## I have the increasing feeling that stackoverflow becomes uninteresting.

**There is a lack of really good questions** - I mean questions where you have the feeling that the one asking has good fundamentals, and he has an idea of what he is doing. Answering to such questions is a kind of dialogue and exchange, where both parties gain.

**Instead, there is now a flood of really poor questions** - and it seems to be of two categories:

a) students who simply post their homework; who have no idea or interest at all and just say "Please solve it for me". - Some even say "Now" instead of "Please".

b) people with no or very little understanding of computer science, who got some work to do, but who have no idea of what is going on at all. E.g. just randomly running a SQL command they get from somewhere and wondering why it does not work.

It's becoming frustrating.

I post this just for discussion.

Comment: it's not the first time it's been discussed and it won't be the last.

Comment: Also of [Flood of zero effort questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296952/2564301) – see [rene's *very* good answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296956/2564301) on that.

Comment: This has been going on for six years, if there's going to be more discussion on it you need to bring something new to the table

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Flood of poor questions about flood of poor questions. Sounds about right.

Comment: My advice is to stay away from the [newest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) tab until you have vote-to-close privileges. The [active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active) and [interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) tabs are much better for finding questions to answer.