# What is the correct close reason for extremely specific questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

You'll all be familiar with questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650136/bridg-project-with-pthread-mutex-c). It happens to be a homework question (which is not in itself problematic). The reason I object to this question is it's fantastically specific. The questioner wants a specific answer to his very specific homework problem. He is not asking what would be a much better question about how to use mutexes to mediate a limited number of resources.

As such, this question (or its answers if it gets any) is going to be of no help to anyone else. No search term is going to find it. It adds nothing to the SO community.

But let's look at possible close reasons:

> **duplicate of...**
>
> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

Unless someone has asked this exact homework question before, this is not a duplicate.

> **off-topic because...**
>
> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

It isn't off-topic; it is about programming.

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

It's very clear what he's asking. He wants his homework done. To the extent it is unclear, let's pretend he made it very clear - the question should still not (in my view) survive.

> **too broad**
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

This is how many such questions seem to be closed. But the question itself is not too broad. Rather its problem is that it is too specific - too specific to be useful to anyone else. Moreover, knowing whether an answer would be too long requires actually understanding piles of code. Perhaps the answer is very simple (e.g. *'`if (i=0) ...` should be `if (i==0)`'*) - in which case there is only one answer, and it is very short.

Indeed using this close reason is only going to encourage even more specific questions. Perhaps the guy will specify the indentation style needed in the answer!

A much broader question (e.g. 'what are the advantages of using UNIX pipes over socketpair()') would be far more useful - I recognise that particular one might be a dupe.

> **primarily opinion-based**
>
> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

I don't see anything opinion-based in the answer here. There might be more than one way to skin a cat in terms of answering it, but one can't know that without analysing the reams of code.

And again, a far more opinion based question (e.g. 'what are the advantages of using UNIX pipes over socketpair()') would be far more useful.

(Personally I think 'too broad' and 'primarily-opinion based' are close cousins, but that's another issue)

My view is that there is no satisfactory close reason for too specific questions such as this. As in general they are asked by less than experienced question askers, we can normally find some other close reason to use, but that's missing the point. We want people to know they shouldn't ask them in the first place, and if they do, precisely why their question got closed.

I thus propose another close reason:

> **too specific**
>
> This question is so specific that it is only ever likely to be useful to you. Stack Overflow is a community-based site and we want to ensure questions that are asked are likely to be relevant to other visitors. Your question is so narrowly focused that this is unlikely to be the case. If it contains a large amount of code that any answerer would need to debug, please reduce it to a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (noting the word 'minimal').

Comment: You are not going to find a "this question doesn't belong here" close reason in that list.  It used to exist but, although SO users are trusted to answer questions, they were not trusted to not answer questions.  Most everybody reaches for "Too broad".  With enough imagination you can find a way to make it apply.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not asking for "this question doesn't belong here" as a close reason, because that doesn't explain *why* the question doesn't belong here. I'm asking for a close reason that explains the problem. I agree that people do in practice use 'too broad', but surely that only encourages even more specific questions!

Comment: I'm with Hans, would choose _too broad_.

Comment: The antonym of "too broad" is "too localized".   The reason that was removed.  You can only use the tools at your disposal, we can't add any.  If it really bytes then use the custom off-topic close reason.

Comment: "Too broad"/"too specific", you don't get any wriggle room on StackOverflow. Being too relax in content moderation compromises the quality, granted, but to be too stringent cripples the flow of things.

Comment: Related (but different): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't happy with the close reasons that are on here, you can always close the question with a custom off-topic close message, as there always will be questions that don't perfectly fit into any of the given close reasons. If you encounter a lot of those questions or simply think that there should be more close reasons available, you should check out the close reason editor available on stack-apps:
https://stackapps.com/questions/4483/close-reason-editor-customize-your-off-topic-close-reasons.

This will give you a customizable list of close reasons and you can save your own messages, that will be available for your convenience:

[image]

You can save yours here:

[image]

The new close reason will then be available just as the original ones are in your close a question popup.

As a sidenote, there's also an userscript available that lets you close questions with just a push of a button, but I forgot the name; you'll find it on stack apps:

[image]

Comment: This would be a useful stopgap, and I tried it, but even when installed it appears to do nothing on Chrome (OS-X). A custom close reason is, however, not an equivalent solution to a different default close reason, in that as has been pointed out, many people will only use the default reasons (particularly 'too broad' which is the opposite of the problem).

Comment: Keeping in mind that some of the SO net-cops will complain that only the stock close reasons are valid, and thus by definition if you enter a custom reason, that's not a valid close reason. Not to dissuade folks from using custom reasons, just be aware that doing so will attract a particular kind of person to respond.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely certain that *is* a bad question. Although it has plenty of very specific requirement, it really just boils down to how to use certain thread primitives to achieve an end.

In fact, I'm pretty certain I could answer it in such a way that it would teach how to use said primitives in a general sense without having to deal with anything like 'only three cars allowed on bridge at a time'.

The other alternative would be to edit the question itself to make it more general and therefore more useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the lack of a "too specific/localized" close reason has not been a problem. I will admit that when I first started using Stack Overflow, I had the same prejudice against overly-specific questions that you seem to have. I resented the attitude of the questioners, who seemed to think they have the right to push their work off onto others. But over time, I came to realize that each question can be judged on its own merits, and that Stack Overflow already does a good job of categorizing possible reasons for closing a question.

If a question seems to me to be overly-specific, but I'm unable to match up one of the existing close reasons to the post, more often than not it was just my prejudice speaking and the question didn't really need closing after all. In many cases, someone else who approached the question more openly managed to find the nugget of good in the question and wrote a good answer. Seeing someone else succeed where I had failed has been a powerful motivator and aid in introspection. :)

It is true that many people post questions that are *presented* in an overly specific way. They go on and on about how they are writing a call center load-balancing/scheduling system, or a license plate reader, or whatever. These are details that we clearly don't need, and which only interfere with the ability of the question to be useful to others, by obfuscating underlying software engineering problems.

But inasmuch as these questions fail to suit the Stack Overflow model, we already have close reasons for dealing with them.

Consider…there are two possibilities with questions that *seem* too specific:

1. The question as stated is comprehensible and answerable in a reasonably concise way. Then, in spite of the overly specific context, it's actually not a bad question. It *might* need some editing to improve it; maybe take out extraneous narrative, add clarification(s) of the underlying issue, etc. But if there's a way to write a good answer for the question, the question itself can't be all that bad.
   Indeed, many such questions are actually duplicates of another question that has been already answered. The author of the new question may have difficulty generalizing from the answer(s) of the marked duplicate, but that's a separate problem.
2. The question as stated is literally too specific to answer. The main mechanism by which this would happen is if it's so specific, the author of the question would have to post their entire program verbatim just to include a reproducible scenario. Note that in this case, there are two sub-possibilities:

   1. They *did* post their entire program verbatim, rather than distill the problem into the *minimal* code required to reproduce the problem.
   2. They did not post a *complete* code example, but rather some subset of their program that they guessed has something to do with the problem.

Note that in that second top-level possibility, both of the sub-possibilities involve an off-topic question. That is, it failed to provide a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If in spite of having what seems to be an overly-specific question, they were able to provide a code example that was both minimal and complete, then that would suggest that the OP has successfully found the underlying issue that they are really asking about and correctly presented their question in a directed way. Indeed, it's so rare that anyone actually creates a truly *minimal* and *complete* code example that I'm always surprised when someone does; if they did so in the context of a question that otherwise seemed overly-specific, I would readily ignore the specificity of the narrative and focus on the code example. Such users are to be encouraged; at most, edit the narrative to remove the irrelevancies. Doing so will help the author improve their own question-asking skills.

There are lots of ways to fail to write correct, working code. It seems to me that the charter of Stack Overflow, the idea that it should develop a repository of all programming questions and their answers, is compatible with code examples that are presented relative to a specific domain. It took me awhile in my career, but one thing I eventually figured out is that for the most part, it doesn't matter what the program you're writing is, the bulk of the problems being solved are the same for that program as for any other program.

Just because someone is writing a program that involves simulating traffic flow, and they have presented their question in that manner, that does not *necessarily* mean that the question is not useful to others. For one, maybe some other person trying to simulate traffic flow will need help with the same issue. For another (and more likely), it may be that the specific problem the person is dealing with has nothing to do with the fact that it's a traffic flow simulation, and in that case an answer can be written more generally, making the question and answer both useful to people besides the traffic flow simulator programmers.

In either case, there's no need at all to close the question.