# Close reason for work requests

Tags: discussion, custom-close-reasons

Fairly often, I see questions like "I have this programming task to do: <problem statement>." Full stop.

If the "task" is simple enough, they may even get a few (or even several) solutions before the question is closed.

Sure, these are routinely closed as "too broad/primarily opinion-based".

But I feel those reasons don't quite bring the message home that it's not the *scope* or the *problem nature* that is incorrect, it's the *nature of the request* that is.

A few more specific things to consider:

- Is the problem large enough to warrant a separate close reason?
- Is the reason going to do noticeable good vs potential harm?

Comment: The people that ask questions like that don't *care* what the close reason is.  They're getting their answers anyway, so that it's harming the site is irrelevant to them.

Comment: @Servy please refrain from sweeping generalizations unless you can back them.

Comment: "unclear" already covers the example you provided. they didn't specify what the problem is, they instead dumped a task description. I think there's an off topic reason that matches it too.

Comment: I agree with the duplicate status. I didn't find that question despite searching around.

Comment: A sweeping generalization seems fine to me.  Occam believes it, so why shouldn't I?

Comment: @MartinJames ever heard of the scientific method? It exists to prevent one from coming to false conclusions btw.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev how about evidence: I yet to see complain on META about "I just asked to do my homework for me and you $#$# closed the question"... So one can draw reasonable conclusion that people asking this type of "questions" don't really care that much.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, I've just seen a post from a user holding such views: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274689/648265.

Comment: The OP of that answer is against having a close reason for those types of questions. They weren't swearing and complaining about one of *their* questions getting closed for being a work request. The person who wrote that answer tends to write questions that are well received by the community.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but even if I didn't, this only shows that none try to ask these specific questions on Meta. Which can be for a plethora of other reasons & combinations (don't have rep, are able to search, don't use such pointless formulations). It doesn't tell what anyone (even less so, the target audience) thinks about the close reasons' relevance.

Comment: Thye did not care enough to read the rules, or just ignored them.  They did not care enough to bother taking the tour, or just ignored it.  They could not be bothered to do any work, or were incapable of it.  I would put the chances of such a poster caring about close-reasons or, indeed, anythng except getting their answer, as 'vanishingly small'.  Smaller than the chances of Mourinho still managing Chelsea next season.

Comment: I don't care abut the close-reason either.  'Too broad' or 'unclear'?  For these works-request/demand questons, I pick the one nearest my mouse cursor.  I cannot justify spending any further effort deciding on the best choice to close an insulting 'question' from a selfish deadbeat.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said ' Smaller than the chances of Mourinho still managing Chelsea tomorrow'.

Comment: @MartinJames I couldn't care less about Mourinho. I did upvote your observations I acknowledged as useful though.

Comment: Besides, since this is a duplicate and thus has no perspectives on its own - is there a way to move the useful comments to the main question?