# Review a Question where the user has not put forward any attempt

Tags: discussion

Into which category do I put a question where the user has not shown any attempt to solve the task. `Requires Editing` or `Unsalvageable`. If `Unsalvageable` again into which category does it fall? Shouldn't be there a category no attempt from user? It was so much straight forward.

Comment: It's either "Too Broad" or "No Code" basically...whichever is closest.

Comment: But there isnt any category no code.. Did i miss looking into something?

Comment: It's under "Off-topic because..." as I recall.

Comment: But off topic has a definition that the question is not about programming. And again in the sub category there is nothing mentioning no code

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") etc"....don't you see that one?

Comment: But the in the case i mentioned there isnt any code in the question. Then how do i tag it saying the user is asking why isnt the code working?

Comment: Same thing....just because there isn't any code doesn't mean there shouldn't be...it's basically the same in my opinion. But just use "Too Broad" if you're uncomfortable with another option....or just downvote and move on.

Comment: OK. Lets say that is the quickest fix. :)

Comment: see also [Should we add a “Do my work for me” close reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)