# Can "do my work" type questions be closed as "why isn't this code working"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923007/how-can-i-extract-the-numbers-from-a-string) (now deleted):

> #### How can I extract the Numbers from a string?
>
> My text input is `d3m12h21`. I want to separate the numbers 3, 12, 21 and store it into three separate variables.
>
> [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)

which looks like a typical "do my work please" question. It has been closed using "why isn't this code working" as a reason. But actually the OP didn't provide any code before (neither incomplete or failed code). Does the reason really make sense here?

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this case. Using any close reason (too broad, unclear) is just OK.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ using the proper close reasons _does_ matter, in every case. Otherwise we'll have people (Reddit) pointing at us, and the OP coming to meta to complain.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, the close reason implies that OP has some source code and denies to show for whatever reason. Primary goal is to close and delete such crap questions (in that sense it _doesn't matter_) as quickly as possible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ even if the question is crap, we shouldn't go and select random close reasons, if only to prevent disputing or mockery of the close reason.

Comment: @CodeCaster _Too broad_ isn't a _"random reason"_, neither missing [MCVE] is so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Too Broad" does not apply (it is answerable with a oneliner) and "Missing MCVE" neither because the OP has no code to show.

Comment: @CodeCaster At least for the latter, I have to disagree. We should force them to do so.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and then we're back to the former comment: you're trying to apply a random close reason (_"Questions seeking debugging help"_) to a question that is not seeking debugging help, but looking for code to begin with. It should be closed, but not as "Too Broad" and neither as "Missing MCVE", because **there is no code to show**.

Comment: Closing *bad* questions with inappropriate close reasons and saying it is for the greater good reminds me of how my country is ruled.

Comment: This makes we wish we still had lack of research as a close reason.  Had the OP googled what they wanted to do they should have found one of the many, many, many dupes.

Comment: I can't recall a time when "lack of research" was *ever* a close reason, @Nathan. At least, not on Stack Overflow. It was and I believe still is on certain other SE sites.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe I am confusing it with of lacks minimal understanding.

Comment: I like to use the "request for off-site resources" reason.

Comment: *Using any close reason...is just OK.* @πάνταῥεῖ The close reason should match the actual problem with the post. It does not make sense for us to tell folks who are question banned to go back and look at the guidance given to fix their questions if the guidance given is wrong.

Comment: @TabAlleman - For questions like this? Why?

Comment: @BSMP, it's a bit of a stream of consciousness, but I see these questions as a request for pre-written code, so whether you've got it in a project you've written or you've seen it on the internet somewhere and have a link, you're being asked for a "resource" that is currently "off-site".  I got the idea because a few of these questions were phrased with a request for any link or tutorial, but the basis of the question was still "give me teh codez"

Comment: @TabAlleman That's often what I pick when they've clearly not done anything and are just asking for teh coedz. However, given the volume of these questions that come through, I would _infinitely_ prefer that we had a proper reason like `shows no evidence of basic research or independent effort to solve the question being asked` - and frankly continue to be **shocked/perplexed** that we don't. So we're reduced to trying to find some other flag that is _least unlike_ what we're trying to say.

Comment: @TabAlleman ...especially since 'lack of research' is shown on the tooltip for downvoting. Surely if we can downvote for moderate lack of research, it's not unreasonable to expect an ability to flag for closure when the question shows a _total_ lack? Otherwise we just end up with questions that get downvoted indefinitely but never get locked as they deserve, all because there isn't a defined reason for locking on which enough people can agree/randomly select.

Comment: *I got the idea because a few of these questions were phrased with a request for any link or tutorial* Yes, those are requests for off site resources but the question in this post is just asking how to do something. The OP clearly expects the answer to be written in the post, not for a bunch of links to other web sites. The "request for off-site resources" is blatantly wrong for this.

Comment: see also [Should we add a “Do my work for me” close reason?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason)

Comment: But if the question should be flagged for closure, and it doesn't specifically fall into any of the categories, then shouldn't the practice be to pick the closest reason?  We should add "Requesting Code/No Effort Shown" to reasons to close.

Comment: *if the question should be flagged for closure, and it doesn't specifically fall into any of the categories* @SusannahPotts - If none of the existing close reasons apply then the question shouldn't be flagged for closure. Not all bad questions are close-worthy.

Comment: It shouldn't be closed, because it's ontopic. It should however be downvoted because it's not useful and doesn't show research. That way it will be auto deleted and lead to potential question bans.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

However much one might dislike "do my work" questions, they aren't a problem per se according to the current site guidelines.

They generally lack research, so they warrant a downvote - but that's about it.

There's no close reason that might apply specifically to "give me teh codez" questions, especially when the question is clear, specific and answerable with a few lines of code and/or text.

In this particular case, there's about ten thousand possible duplicates though, so that close reason still applies if you can find a duplicate.

Though let's look at the question again:

> My text input is d3m12h21. I want to separate the numbers 3, 12, 21

Wait. That's in fact closeable as *"unclear what you're asking"*. The *pattern* of the string is unclear. Do they want to extract the numbers after the letters `d`, `m` and `h` respectively? Or do they want to extract all numbers from any string, separated by any non-numeric characters? Are there always three numbers? What are their valid ranges?

So either "unclear" or "duplicate" will suffice.

See also [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions).

Comment: "See also" that other question - and upvote it in your droves, _please_. The answer to that question is a deafening _yes_.

Answer (score 8):

The close reason fits just fine if you keep reading beyond "why isn't this code working". It states [annotation and formatting my own]

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>   include
>
> - the desired behavior **(check...ish)**
> - a specific problem or error **(nope)**
> - and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **(nope)**
>
> in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement
>   are not useful to other readers.

That's 1 out of 3, if we're generous, and that isn't good enough.

The assumption we make for any question asked is that you have tried something. That doesn't change if you're not showing it. So while "why isn't this code working" may not  seem to apply, it does, because we assume you have tried something. And if you really haven't, don't complain about the close reason, but go do some work instead.

That said, for a question of this quality multiple close reasons will usually apply, and to argue about a specific one is somewhat of a moot point.

Comment: But this question is not part of the group _"Questions seeking debugging help"_.

Comment: Surely there is a problem the OP is facing @CodeCaster. He's just not telling us.

Comment: If the problem is that they have no idea where to begin, then there's no relevant code to show or debug. As far as I know, that's still a valid question, but feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: For as far as I know that is not a valid question. For one it falls short of the requirement for homework help "*Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*" as can be found [in the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It is a valid question to have. It is not a valid question to ask here. If the requirement for questions on our site is "demonstrate what you've tried", I'd say it's fair game to assume you've tried something but just aren't showing us. If the response then is "but I don't have any code" ... well, there's your problem.

Comment: And keep in mind that close reason headers can only express so much. That's why the body is too important to skip.

Comment: I think you're then using that close reason as a loophole to close zero-effort question where better close reasons exist, as demonstrated in my answer. Let's not devaluate close reasons like this. It's not a _question asking debugging help_, it's a _question asking for code_. Those are fine, just not in the way expressed in this particular case.

Comment: I don't see how, what is essentially a checklist explicitly telling you what you should have shown us, is a loophole. But I won't argue against other close reasons also being a fit here.

Comment: I really don't see how you think the close reason for _"my code isn't working but I won't show (the relevant parts of) it and/or not properly tell you how it isn't working"_ applies to _"I have no code to show because I don't know where to start, how do I do X?"_, but fine. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: That we can do. ;)

Comment: */me shakes angry old man fist at @CodeCaster anyway*

Answer (score -2):

I would say "Too Broad" could be the primary close reason for "Do my work" type questions.

I don't have sufficient reputation to view the question linked, but I can guess at its content.

Without knowing more details, the asker could want a regex, they could iterate the string char by char and spit out the digits, they could replace any non-numeric with whitespace, they could split on non-numerics and discard empty partitions.  And anyone of a hundred other solutions I can't be bothered to list.

There are more options than could reasonably be covered in a single answer, which is the purpose of the "Too broad" close reason.

Comment: Just a FYI [CodeCaster's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332464/4342498) quotes the question.

Comment: Similarly, it's unclear exactly what the OP needs to know in order to write the code themself. If they can't tell us what went wrong when they tried to solve this problem it's hard for us to set them straight. Sure, we _could_ just write the code for them, but I prefer to impart some actual understanding to people who actually want to learn how to program...