# Why is there no flag for 'plz send teh codez' questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, low-quality-posts

I keep running across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387342/how-to-find-an-optimum-location-point-on-a-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40388369/messaging-service-in-c-for-unix) that are obviously 'plz send teh codez' questions. Why is there no flag for this? What flag should I use for this type of question?

Comment: because it would be abused to the extreme.

Comment: @KevinB probably so, but the second part is still relevant

Comment: "flag" is the wrong term here i think, but that's not you're fault, all you see is the option to flag. What your'e looking for is a close reason for these types of questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can flag to close them as

> **too broad**
>
> There are either *too many possible answers*, or good answers would be *too long* for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

(emphasis mine)

I'm fine with very narrow 'how do I do X' kind of 'gimme teh codez' questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880526/set-uilabel-line-spacing/) (barring duplicates). Asking for complete algorithm or service implementations is *way* too much.

It's interesting to see that these questions are related to the only [off-topic reason](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which doesn't have its own off-topic *close* reason:

> 3. Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: Isn't the second clause of the close reason ("too long") more relevant than the first one ("too many") in this case? A good question might allow for several different answers that are equivalent for the OP's purposes, but if, as you say, a question asks for e.g. a full service implementation it is clearly out of bounds.

Comment: @duplode Yeah, it is at least equally important.

Answer (score 7):

The correct response is to down-vote.

This gives a clear signal that the question is a poor one and requires fixing.

If you want to vote (or flag) to close then this is probably the most appropriate reason:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. [See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I'll admit that the first half doesn't really apply, but it's the second half of this reason that's important here - telling the OP that the question must contain a problem statement and a minimal, complete example of what's failing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning downvoting, but the close reason is plain wrong. Those kind of people are clearly not *seeking debugging help*. They just want us to write their code for them.

Comment: Certainly better than closing a very specific question as too broad.

Comment: I've been using "why isn't this code working" and "unclear what you're asking" but they aren't right, as @Glorfindel stated.

Comment: @KevinB Such questions sometimes are too broad, in the sense of "good answers would be too long for this format" (e.g. when "teh codez" means a 500 LOC solution for someone's homework).

Comment: Asking for how to implement something isn't really the same as asking why an implementation isn't working, is it?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara this was discussed in [Can “do my work” type questions be closed as “why isn't this code working”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332455/839601)