# The limit of Stack Overflow is not coding service

Tags: discussion

What is the limit of "Not a coding service"? Is there a line which is and which is not?

I have read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason). While in there it is quite clear which is and which isn't, but when I review a question, sometimes there is a  question where the OP has included the code he tried, but still marked as "you don't try enough" or "not coding service". Most of the time I skip the question, but after I  a while I kept seeing that I doubt there is a line after all, so is there a line for this?

Comment: I don't want to get into this whole topic but I will say this: In any community with 6.9 million users (2.4 million active, 1.1 million in the past week or so -- and furthermore only [20,000 of those users](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/650086) have been seen here on meta in the past week thus most probably aren't even aware of some of the discussions we have here), *any* policy-related lines will necessarily be quite fuzzy. You can expect quite a bit of variance among reactions to questions. You should do what *you* think is right.

Comment: The problem is what I think is right is not true for other people. Without  a line what is right and what is wrong, can we measure it with our feeling as it is relative ? the way I see it Stack Overflow has become something like a government where some are "cops" to enforce bias rule and other "victim" thinking he is right, whether he was read the rule or not.

Comment: Unfortunately the only responses I can think of are far more philosophical than I want to deal with here. The community evolves organically and constantly, it is the collective sum of its member's values, which may change over time. Also consider the fact that "heading to MSO to see what other people there think and following those examples" is a value in itself, more meta than simply how you react to a question. I skipped a lot of reasoning there, so, maybe that means something to you, or maybe it doesn't. I dunno.

Comment: @whale_steward, "the problem is what I think is right is not true for other people" - this is what voting and closure mechanisms are for: 5 people (non-mods and not Thors) should VTC for a question to be closed.

Comment: @whale_steward "The problem is what I think is right is not true for other people." -- My previous comment in different words: You have four options: 1) Change your ways, 2) try to change other people's ways, 3) keep doing your own thing, or 4) leave. Every one of those choices is equally valid, the big picture end result will be as it should be.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah it maybe a good way to set what is right. I need to work some data to get the big picture of this.

Comment: @JasonC maybe you are right, as right now I hope there is a line so I know what I am doing is right or wrong, but as you said, at this point I choose option 4 (skip the question) as I don't know which one is true. thanks.

Comment: @whale_steward The help center article, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, is a fairly decent representation of current community values. Comparing a question to some of the guidelines there can often give a hint of why a question got the reception that it did. If you're searching for a set of values to establish as your own, that could be a good starting point. That article can be supplemented with all the various discussions on meta about its finer points, combined with your own personal values. And again, remember: There will be fuzziness! Not everybody here is identical. :)