# I asked a question on how to get started on a specific development effort, but it was closed immediately

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I've posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69885766/geo-plotting-with-c-sharp), but almost immediately it was closed as "This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers."

What if I'm very new to the subject and really looking for some help?

I mean, of course I googled on the subject, and did it a lot. But I didn't find any useful info. Then what, if I can't ask for some help, what do I do? Just forget about it?

Comment: Have you taken the [tour] already?

Comment: *"What if I'm very new to the subject and really looking for some help?"* You're on the wrong website then. With respect, [main] isn't for people who are "new", we expect the users here to have some knowledge of the technologies they are using and have performed research before they even thought about asking the question. [Main] isn't a "free help" website; it's a Q&A repository.

Comment: We both know the answer to that is (currently) "no", @Dharman . ;)

Comment: Related: [How should we be advising users asking too broad or unclear how-to questions while not implying that such questions require code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370152) and [What is an indicator that a question is "too broad" or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268305)

Answer (score 27):

There's an explicit and very clear difference between [trying to build a forum](https://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) and needing help with one specific part of that effort.

Your question is asking for a whole way to do geoplotting with C#.  You've only described two things:

- What your intentions are, and
- What language you're going to execute those intentions.

You're asking us to help you fill in the rest - and there's an nondeterministic amount of "the rest" that's not here.

- What kind of map/projection are you using?
- Where are you getting the data from, and do you have a license to use it?
- How is the information accessed?

Basically...you want us to help you build that forum.

That's not gonna fly here.

If you have more specific, pointed questions about an aspect of this effort that you're struggling with, *then* we *might* be able to help you.  Simply saying "I don't know where to start" makes two of us, since we wouldn't either.

Stack Overflow as a Q&A platform works best with narrow-scope and focused questions.  Yours is just too wide open.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow expects everyone to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before making any contributions to the site. If you don't do that then the only person you can blame is yourself. Before posting here you must familiarize yourself with the rules and expectations. You wouldn't barge into a Chinese restaurant and demand Spaghetti Bolognese.

Your current submission has been reviewed by 3 people who found it too broad and likely to lead to opinionated recommendations of various map plotting technologies. According to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) such questions are off-topic.

What you can do now is to narrow down the question. Pick a technology, try something and ask about a specific problem. The question needs to be more focused to be successful in our format. Only then it might be helpful to future readers.

Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a personal help desk. We do not offer one-on-one guidance. According to the tour, which you were expected to complete, the goal is:

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.

Your question needs to have answers that can be validated and aren't primarily opinion based. Only such questions are suitable for the Q&A format. The question you asked might be suitable for a normal forum, which Stack Overflow is not.

Answer (score 6):

I was one of the close voters on the question, so I can comment as to why I voted to close.

In particular, focusing on the first sentence:

> What is the best way (and not very complex preferably) to visualize data on a world map using C#?

The "best way" is very subjective. Also, I'm not sure if this was your intent or not, but the "not very complex" phrase makes it sound like you're not willing to put forth the effort to learn about the technology, you just want someone to hand you a ready-made solution that requires little effort or understanding on your part. Again, I'm not sure if that was the actual intent, but it at least sounded like that from the way that the question was phrased. Stack Overflow really isn't supposed to be a substitute for your own learning.

Also, given the constraints of the question, an answer would almost certainly have to be some library (because doing this without a library *would* be complex), which is off-topic for Stack Overflow because we've found from experience that this type of question doesn't work very well on the site. (They used to be allowed, but they attracted a lot of spam, opinionated answers, and answers that were little more than links).

Also:

> I mean, of course I googled on the subject, and did it a lot. But I didn't find any useful info.

You should indicate what research you did in the question and why what you found didn't help you; otherwise, reviewers will likely get confused and assumed that you didn't do any, and answerers might get confused and answer with stuff you already knew.

Comment: Good point. For some reason you ignore the fact, that I'm new to the subject, and "not very complex" solution is needed for I just might not understand difficult solution at all at my current level. Besides that, I don't need really difficult and complex technology to display a single map having marks on it, that's just it, no looking for an easy way. Then, what if I truly did some research, and found no answer to my question, why can't I just ask a living person for help, for her opinion? Is it THAT BAD to have some amount of feedback about different technologies I could use?