# What link should I give when people ask to write their software for them?

Tags: support, questions, close-reasons, question-quality, needs-more-focus

In handling first time posts, sometimes I encounter a 'write my software for me' non-question. Is there a link to SO official guidelines that I can give in such cases? Also, when I flag it, what is the correct category?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761?

Comment: A downvote, and silence.

Comment: I wish that the correct answer was "ASCII art of a raised middle finger".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You do not need to give a link. Any link you give would just be generic boilerplate, repeating what the asker should have already read when they joined the site and attempted to ask a question. If they didn't read or care about it then, they're unlikely to care about it when you post it. Worse, it risks you becoming the target of backlash. And if nothing else, it just clutters up the comments, making more work for others in the future.

All you need to do is **flag such questions as "should be closed"**. For "write my software for me" non-questions, the most common closure reason is **"needs more focus"** (what used to be called "too broad").

If or when the question ultimately gets closed, a banner will be displayed, explaining the reason for the closure and containing the link(s) you would have otherwise shared.

You are, of course, welcome to leave a comment if you can provide something *specific* and *unique* to that particular question. For example, if you want to give targeted advice on how to improve the question so that it can be answered. You should do this *in addition to* flagging for closure.

Comment: ah, great. I was worried new users would have no feedback, but since they get the link upon closure that saves us a lot of work.

Comment: Yup. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808593/how-to-solve-this-equation) an arbitrary example of a question closed as "needs more focus". Note that you do not yet have [privileges to cast close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions). However, you can *flag* questions to recommend closure, putting them into a close vote review queue that users with close vote privileges can and do monitor.

Comment: Wouldn't this specific subset of "Too broad" questions deserve a specific flag reason? I'm usually against harsh closures, especially for people that are honestly trying to do their best, but in this case probably a specific "SO is not a _free coding service_" message would be useful.

Comment: @Roberto No, because many questions that request code are perfectly on-topic for Stack Overflow, so that alone should not be a close reason. These questions should only be closed if they are actually too broad for our Q&A format. I have no idea what a "harsh closure" is. Closure is never harsh. By definition, it's a quality control mechanism indicating that the question, in its current form, is not a good fit for our Q&A format. The point is to get the asker to edit the question to comply with our guidelines.

Comment: @CodyGray I understand ([even if..](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274630/11336762) :) ). For me a _harsh closure_ is a closure occurring in the first 10 minutes after a question of asked. My (little) experience says that if the user is responsive comments are able to make him improve their question and make it answerable, and also says that after the closure it will probably remain closed. And because of the early downvotes, probably unrecoverable since downvoters will never come back to appreciate the changes, the OP will more likely delete question and ask the same question a week later.

Comment: @Roberto Closure is maximally useful if it is done *as early as possible*. You should never be waiting to vote to close. Vote to close immediately, then discuss with the asker how the question can be improved. Once it's improved, it can be re-opened. If you don't close *early*, then the question will attract answers in the meantime, and your edits will invalidate those answers. Closure is like a purgatory for questions. The nicest possible thing you can do is close early. If you miss that opportunity, the question inevitably ends up being deleted altogether.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni It's so interesting that people want two things to happen at the same time - get quick answer by making question seen by as many people as possible and get as little feedback as possible demanding that no questions can be looked at/evaluated for quality by anyone for an hour or more...

Comment: @RobertoCaboni If the asker isn't willing to put in the effort to make their question on-topic when they post it, it's highly unlikely they're going to bother to edit it into good shape. Such users are essentially engaging in phishing: if nobody answers or their question gets closed they haven't put much time into it so don't lose much, if someone is foolish enough to answer honestly then the asker has essentially gained the time that person spent answering.

Comment: @IanKemp ok, guys, but that's not the real topic of the answer. What do you think about a specific "Do my job for me" flag?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni every flag raised has to be actioned by a human moderator, of which there are never enough. In other words, flagging should be a **last resort** when the other means provided by the system to handle a bad post are available. In this case, you have the ability to downvote and vote to close the bad question, and those are the mechanisms you should use.