# Is it okay to use the word "assignment" when asking a question?

Tags: discussion

I was answering a question where in the comments, the asker is repeatedly using the word "assignment" to refer to his question.

*Meaning that he is the **assigner**, we are the **assignees**, and the question is the **assignment***.

I am wondering if that's right; is it an assignment?

On the one hand I can say "yes it is", as people who are answering are seeking success, challenge, and maybe reputation.
But on the other hand I can say "no it is not"; it is just a question, an inquiry to help -- he is not a team leader assigning tasks.

I don't know how I should see it. What is proper here?

Comment: Why does that change anything? If the commenter seem to treat users as lackey... yes it's a problem. If it's just a word they use, meh...

Comment: When saying *the assignment is to use a 'specific technology' *, or *i'm not yet ok with the assignment*, i can't confirm he's treating users as lackey, but he may be...

Comment: see [Appropriate Response for 'Do My Job' Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260647/appropriate-response-for-do-my-job-questions)

Comment: Thanks @gnat, my intention in my question is not to `close` or vote for closing or downvoting, as the OP asked a somehow well received question -after editing and enhancing his need not his vocabulary-, but in his `comments`, i got a real feeling that he seem to giving us a assignment. So my question intention is to know from your experiences whether i can point out for him that this is not a assignment, or if he's really right -> in the end in some aspect it is an assignment!

Comment: Your premise is wrong. The word assignment does not mean it's *your* assignment, is merely *an* assignment. There is nothing wrong with assignments.

Comment: As user000001 pointed out in comment it very well could be translation issue. I.e. "doubt" is frequently used to refer to a problem even if most common use "I have a doubt about methods" is very hard to read in a way OP intended too... I bet "assignment" when translated back and forth to some language will end up "a problem"... (Maybe we need SO specific dictionary for such cases).

Comment: thanks @Félix Gagnon-Grenier for your point of view

Comment: thanks @Alexei Levenkov, yes that's right, we may need an SO dictionary specific to take these cases more seriously and judge so that OPs and contributors know exactly and clearly what they can say and what not in a  misunderstanding case.

Answer (score 8):

...So the OP was asking about a homework question, and you took personal offense to it in such a way that you felt like the OP was giving *you* an assignment?  This is a unique interpretation if I've ever seen one.

In general, I'd imagine that the OP was referring to their assignment - as in a *homework* assignment - and was using that as a familiar way to refer to their question as stated.

If the question was explicitly asking or telling you to do the work, then that's not an acceptable question here anyway - it's too broad - and should be flagged for closure as such.  There's no value in engaging with someone who believes that we are here to just do their bidding; there's a bit of give and take here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's not a homework assignment! it's a practice on a new library where a help is needed on a task. Anyways, what made me reach that point of thinking more, is his awareness of the reward given in case of providing the good answer he needs, and using that, to ask for more adaptation on older answers to get the right one he's convinced with. So there is a context of bad signs that shows how some people interact on stackoverflow, where it is not clear -in my case- if i should stop engaging, or take it easy and positive as must as possible

Comment: It could also be a language issue

Comment: when you say 'it could be a language issue' you mean that in case it was not, OP is not allowed to treat contributors as assignees and the question they ask as an assignment ? thanks. that's what i need to know